# Hiatus for Fortnightly Challenges

Tags: discussion, weekly-challenges

It's currently not looking good for the [fortnightly challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3578/8478). Of the last four challenges only one was actually posted. And the current one doesn't seem to be quite on track either.

It seems that the back-to-back fortnightly challenges are causing some fatigue, especially since it's usually the same core of users developing them.

I propose we pause the challenges for a while, collect more themes in the linked post, and get back to it in a few months, so we can come up with some nice ideas everyone is sufficiently stoked about to actually pull it off.

If you have a better idea for reviving the challenges, please leave an answer here. (And if you object to having a hiatus, please do as well!)

Comment: I really liked the idea of weekly challenges (I wanted to participate but couldn't find any time...) and I would also love to help designing these challenges but a weekly, or even fortnightly cycle is just too short for me to participate. I propose moving from fortnightly challenges to monthly challenges, since these give us more time to pick a topic, design a question and let it be answered.