# Should we hold an annual contest?

Tags: discussion

I recently had the idea of making an annual contest in PPCG, like the Google Code Jam.

But I went through this question. "Should we really hold an annual contest? If we should, how?"

Could you tell me if we should make one or not, and if yes, with some possible ways to do it?

Comment: In a way the [Best of PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11186/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2016) is already a annual contest.

Comment: We hold contests on a daily basis. I have a hard time thinking of what would set one apart to classify as annual.

Answer (score 1):

## My basic idea

1. Get participants for a set period of time.
2. Have 5 rounds, each with 3 problems. ([participants count]/5) people with the most sum of bytes (or score depending on the problem) will be eliminated.
3. Give a set amount of bounty to the first, second and third winners.

### Some more ideas

- Set a language each round to make the game fair.

Comment: Are we specifying which languages people should use? Otherwise you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @DLosc That should make a fair game.

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for a contest, but labelling it "annual" requires then planning many more. It might work better to just make one contest at a time rather than committing to make one the same time every year. For comparison, [fortnightly challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4960/hiatus-for-fortnightly-challenges) faded away due to not being able to keep up the momentum.

Comment: It might be better to have "collaborative challenges" if you want a group effort, rather than specifying a time period.

Comment: Competing in the same language doesn't really work with the StackExchange model of publicly visible answers.