# Is Language of the Month dead?

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

The [Languge of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14737/71434) series(?) started in March of this year, for the purpose of "to get more exposure for less-frequently used languages". Until August it seemed to be doing fine enough, though I don't have any particular way to quantify that.

However, in September I can clearly quantify that it did not do fine. As mentioned in a [comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/nominations-for-language-of-the-month#comment59438_14737) by user JayCe:

> It’s time to announce Cubically as LotM isn’t it?

Cublically was the "winner" for Language of the Month for September, but no Meta post was made to consolidate information or posts about or using the language, the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62883/cubically) remained frozen, and it seems that [no answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2018-09-01..2018-09-31+%22%23+cubically%22+is%3Aa) using the language were posted in September (though that search doesn't have 100% reliability by my understanding).

Based on the past threads, it's not yet time to be worried about this month's language, which should be R I guess; some of the previous Meta posts were made on the 3rd of their respective months rather than strictly the 1st. However... much like last month, if such a post *doesn't* get made I'm not sure what can and/or should be done about it. Have the Languages of the Months run their course, and not enough people are really interested? Was there significant discussion on this somewhere (chat perhaps?) that just never resulted in a new Meta post or a change to the Nominations post? Is this just a case of "everybody thought it was someone else's responsibility", and if so can or should that be improved?

Comment: I think it's a combination of *everybody thought it was someone else's responsibility* and interest waning, but that's just my impression.

Comment: Don't worry; if nobody's interested to post one, it can wait. If it dies, that is, turns out to be inactive for months, then the community is most probably not very interested in it anymore.