# Language of the month for November 2020: Forth

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout November 2020, our Language of the Month, nominated by user96495 and supported by me (Bubbler), will be:

> ## [Forth](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/)

#### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during November, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Forth, use it to solve challenges, and discuss it in the [Forth chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115720/forth). Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

#### Information about Forth

[Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) is one of the earliest stack-based practical programming languages (it's turning 50 this year), yet at least one modern implementation (namely [Gforth](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/)) is still being actively maintained.

- Forth's very simple syntax will let you get started quickly.
- Forth supports functions and structured programming. This has multiple implications:

  - We can use stack content I/O for functions.
  - We can write test cases for a submission more easily.
  - We can construct more complex programs without much hassle.
- Due to the low-level-ish way Forth treats its stack contents, we can use various built-in words to achieve something they're not designed to do. e.g. `s>d` can be used for a non-negativity test, and "double" stack-manipulation words can be used to fetch or move around pairs of integers. Be creative, and please share any interesting uses of built-ins you find [as a golfing tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68446/78410).

#### Resources

- [General information about Forth the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language))
- [Gforth home page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/) and [Gforth user manual](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/) ([another site hosting the same materials](https://gforth.org/manual/))

  - [Tutorial](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Tutorial.html#Tutorial), [Built-in reference](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Words.html#Words)
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#forth-gforth), [Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115720/forth), [Golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68446/78410)

#### Bounty

To facilitate more participation, I will award 50-rep bounties to **first 5 answers** in Forth by each user who hasn't used Forth before. (Sorry that I can't award this bounty to a question that already has my answer.)

Answer (score 4):

## List of all Forth solutions posted in November 2020

(First time posters highlighted in bold)

- [Sum the First n Even Fibonacci Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214556/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Print invisible text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214558/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz/214636#214636) by **[Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)** (+50)
- [Shortest infinite loop producing no output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214644/78410) by **[Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)**
- [Mixed number to an improper fraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214748/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Prime power switch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214749/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Output programming language name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214826) by **[Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334)** (+50)
- [Scream very loudly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214828) by [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334)
- [Pascal's Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214905/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) (+50)
- [Draw an ASCII-art rainbow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214907/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) (+50)
- [Pointers, pointers, pointers!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214908/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) (+50)
- [The squiggly sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214912/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) (+50)
- [Display the exponent from a binary floating point number as a decimal value](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214961/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) (+50)
- [A very long Terza Rima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214968/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Collatz Conjecture (OEIS A006577)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214973/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Print number triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47657/print-number-triangle/?lastactivity) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Compute the Lambert W function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215030/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Knight on the Rim is Grim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215040/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Find the tangent of the sum of inverse tangents](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215044/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Rectangles in rectangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215050/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Is it Christmas yet?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215115/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [I uppercase the source code, you reverse the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215153/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Count the Collatz survivors mod 2^n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215167/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Is it a leap year?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50798/is-it-a-leap-year/215169#215169) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Euler's Geometry Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215340/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Multiply or Divide by n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215649/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
   [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of all Forth tips posted in November 2020

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Forth-related challenges posted in November 2020

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```