# Language of the Month for March 2021: Factor

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout March 2021, our Language of the Month, nominated by myself (Bubbler) will be:

> ## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/)

#### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during March, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Factor, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Factor

> The Factor programming language is a concatenative, stack-based programming language with high-level features including dynamic types, extensible syntax, macros, and garbage collection. On a practical side, Factor has a full-featured library, supports many different platforms, and has been extensively documented.

Factor is *the* modern stack-based practical language. If Forth (LotM of November 2020) was too hard to use because of its low-level-ness and nothing else, Factor is probably the right language for you.

### Why Factor?

- Factor is functional and object-oriented. Any object or function can be pushed on the data stack. The "object" includes containers (arrays, hashmaps, and the like).
- Factor does not use syntax (if..then..else, for, while) for control flow. Instead, it extensively uses quotations (equivalent of anonymous lambda functions) and higher-order functions. For example, an equivalent of if-statement looks like `boolean [ true-func ] [ false-func ] if`.
- The standard library includes lots of higher-order functions that act on the stack or arrays, which can give a feel of working in Haskell.
- The [functional idiom](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-cleave-combinators.html) for reusing stack item(s) can give the feel of APL trains or Jelly links.
- When the stack shuffling gets extra cumbersome, you can get away with [local variables](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-locals-examples.html).
- Factor implements whole numeric tower (bigints, rationals, floats, and complex numbers whose components can be in any of the three real number types).
- Stack safety is enforced by checking the written stack effect against the actual one. It may be a hindrance to golf, but it makes Factor functions easier to debug. And you can ignore it by using a quotation for golfing purposes.
- Despite the verbosity of syntax (space-separated words), Factor is often on par with other practical languages (JS, Python, R) byte-count-wise, thanks to the rich set of library functions.

### Caveats

- It is recommended to install the Factor binary locally to search for the library functions. (Factor binary is available for Windows/Mac/Linux.)
- TIO seems to have a version different from the current stable (0.98), and some things that work locally may not work on TIO. e.g. `tuck ( x y -- y x y )` is missing, and `count` does not load with `auto-use`.

### Resources

- [Factor home page](https://factorcode.org/), [Factor/Learning on Concatenative Wiki](https://concatenative.org/wiki/view/Factor/Learning)
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#factor)
- [Tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75610/78410)
- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119181/factor). Ping me (@Bubbler) if you have any questions about Factor.
- [Tutorial](https://andreaferretti.github.io/factor-tutorial/)

#### Bounty

I (Bubbler) will award `50 × n` rep for any user's `n`-th Factor answer posted this month, up to `n = 10`, maximum 2750 rep in total per user.

Answer (score 3):

## List of all Factor solutions posted in March 2021

(First time posters highlighted in bold)

- **[Print 0 to 100 without 1-9 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220078) by [SjoerdPennings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45220)** (+50)
- [Approximate the Dottie number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220209/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- **[Reconstruct an integer from its prime exponents](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220320/95516) by [rak1507](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95516/rak1507)** (+50)
- [What is the area of this polygon?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220494/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Sum of primes between given range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220599/90812) by **[Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)** (+50)
- [Do I have a prime twin?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220617/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- **[Do I have a prime twin?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220659/62393) by [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393)** (+50)
- **[1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220678/5116) by [hdrz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5116/hdrz)** (+50)
- [Triangular code, triangular output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220799/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812) (+100)
- [Code point sum quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220831/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Is this number a factorial?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220863/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+50)
- [Count all possible Tweets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220948/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681) (+50)
- [It's Hip to be Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125237/its-hip-to-be-square/221012#221012) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+100)
- [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221063/5116) by [hdrz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5116/hdrz) (+100)
- [Reverse factorial function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205033/reverse-factorial-function/221094#221094) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+150)
- [Alphabet printing challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221116/5116) by [hdrz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5116/hdrz) (+150)
- [Removing The Nineteenth Byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221180/5116) by [hdrz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5116/hdrz) (+200)
- [Largest power of 2 that divides n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221287/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [**How high you can count?**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124362/how-high-can-you-count/221323#221323) By [**Wasif**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif) (+50)
- [Largest power of 2 that divides \$n\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221285/78410) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+200)
- **[What's the odd one out?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221385/9486) by [Silvio Mayolo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9486)** (+50)
- [Find the factorial!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial/221406#221406) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif) (+100)
- [Average of your code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207258/average-of-your-code/221422#221422) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif) (+150)
- [Print a 10 by 10 grid of asterisks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88653/print-a-10-by-10-grid-of-asterisks/221425#221425) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif) (+200)
- [Am I an insignificant array?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221433/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+250)
- [Follow a linked list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222521/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+300)
- [Is it a super-prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222522/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+350)
- [Repeated! Factorials!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222555/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+400)
- [Half, Half Half, and, Half](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222556/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+450)
- [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210071/the-vanilla-factorial-challenge/222641#222641) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif) (+250)
- [I reverse the source code, you reverse the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222692/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) (+500)
- [Printing criss cross of two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222705/5116)
   by [hdrz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5116/hdrz) *(invalid)*
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221285/95792) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of all Factor tips posted in March 2021

- [You are free to trash stdout and stack under the top](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220886/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
   [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Factor-related challenges posted in March 2021

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```