# Language of the Month for April 2021: Vim

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout April 2021, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Vim

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during April, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Vim, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Vim

<sup>Taken from the [nomination post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19280/66833)</sup>

Vim is a text editor that is meant to be an improvement over vi.

It's very concise - usual operations only take one or two ASCII bytes.

It's really good for string manipulation challenges ([string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) is our second most popular tags), so you are going to find chances to use it very often.

#### Resources

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#v). Vim is backwards-compatible with V, so (almost) all Vim programs should work in V
- [Vim.org](https://www.vim.org/)
- [Documentation](https://www.vim.org/docs.php)
- [Download](https://www.vim.org/download.php)
- [Tips for golfing in vim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71030/tips-for-golfing-in-vim)

Comment: `Vim is backwards-compatible with V, so (almost) all Vim programs should work in V` To address this point: The main differences are 1) `0` doesn't work (use `|` instead) and 2) a lot of commands are implicitly finished (ex commands and operators). So for example, the V program `d` is equivalent to the Vim program `dd`.

Comment: Is there a way to find all Vim answers posted on codegolf?

Comment: @OlivierDulac [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+%22vim%22) search will show all answers containing the word `Vim`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thankx! I was trying : codegolf homepage, and  `[Vim]` as a search, but maybe not all answers/questions are tagged appropriately. Your answer is probably best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## List of all Vim solutions posted in April 2021

(First time posters highlighted in bold)

- **[Is it a pangram?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222989/62393) by [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393)**
- [Follow a linked list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223071/62393) by [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393)

- **[Reverse stdin and place on stdout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223088/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)**
- [Multiplicative persistence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223090/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Multiplicative persistence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223102/31716) by [James](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/james)
- **[Backhanded^H^H^H^H^H^Hspaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223116/95792) by [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)**
- [Backhanded^H^H^H^H^H^Hspaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223118/62393) by [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393)
- [Backhanded^H^H^H^H^H^Hspaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223119/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Write out the Thue-Morse sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223127/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Longest Common Prefix of 2 Strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223122/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Print 0 to 100 without 1-9 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219576/print-0-to-100-without-1-9-characters/223143#223143) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Overwrite a string on a tape](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223115/62346) by [nmjcman101](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62346/nmjcman101)
- [Print 0 to 100 without 1-9 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223182/62393) by [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393)
- [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223196/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [It's Hip to be Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223205/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Range, Reverse, Sum!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223235/44809) by [Ray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44809)
- [Backwards Alphabet Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223237/44809) by [Ray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44809)
- [Range, Reverse, Sum!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223249/62393) by [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393)
- [Print a 10 by 10 grid of asterisks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223278/44809) by [Ray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44809)
- [How long is my number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223272/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Row, Column, Diagonal, Block](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223294/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Codegolf Rainbow : Draw in Black-and-White](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223329/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Print last inputted byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223411/44809) by [Ray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44809)
- [Average of your code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223428/44809) by [Ray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44809)
- [Display a clock face](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223436/44809) by [Ray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44809)
- [Equalize the array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223388/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Divide a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223438/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Average of your code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223415/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Print the SARS-Cov-2 (COVID-19) genome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223490/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Write a microwave timer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223473/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Output a Latin Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223624/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Solve a Diagonal Burrows-Wheeler transform](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223640/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223664/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- **[“DDoouubbllee ssppeeaakk!!”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223704/101474) by [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops)**
- [Let's decrease the monotony](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223729/101474) by [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops)
- [!I!n!s!e!r!t! !n!b!e!t!w!e!e!n!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223851/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Interpret brainf***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223869/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Is it better to walk or run in the rain?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223930/101474) by [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops)
- [Close neighbours stick together](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223954/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Find the Factorial!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223960/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Start from ones](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223700/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Reversencode the given string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223812/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Are All the Items the Same?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224028/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Are All the Items the Same?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224039/101474) by [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops)
- [Did I die or not?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224045/101474) by [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops)
- **[Help me compress this song](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224297/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)**
- [Implement ΔList](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224202/80214) by  [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- **[Create output twice the length of the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224507/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80050)**
- [ASCII Hangman in Progress](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224521/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Best Rolling Ao5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224519/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Write a "Hello" interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224547/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Halloween Golf: The 2spooky4me Challenge!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224556/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [This challenge uses the '+' character](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224722/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Implement Minceraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224378/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Print All Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224749/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221285/95792) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of all Vim tips posted in April 2021

- **[Rotate your loops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223433/101474) by [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops)**

  ```
    [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Vim-related challenges posted in April 2021

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```