# Language of the Month for June 2021: Red

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/78850), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout June 2021, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## [Red](https://www.red-lang.org/)

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/78850). In short, during June, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Red, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Red

- [Red](https://www.red-lang.org/) is a next-gen language, strongly inspired by [Rebol](http://rebol.com). Its unique syntax allows function calls without parentheses, including a wide range of functions.
- Red is language-oriented and includes several [DSLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_specific_language), including a gui description language (VID and View), 2d drawing dialect (Draw) and a parsing dialect (Parse).

- Red is meant to be a full-stack language. This means it includes a high-level dialect (dynamic, interpreted, but can be also compiled) and Red/system, a low level dialect for perfomance when necessary (always compiled).
- Red emphasizes the paradigm "Code is data".
- Red doesn't have reserved words. Even conditionals and looping constructs are ("native" function) values provided by runtime, which can be assigned any names.
- Red has a rich set of built-in datatypes - over 50.

### Resources

- [Red home page](http://www.red-lang.org/)
- [github pages](https://red.github.io/index.html)
- [source code and other community resources](https://github.com/red/)
- [gitter chat](https://gitter.im/red/red)
- [Code golf SE Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124927/red)

### Bounty

I ([Wezl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90614)) am awarding 50+ rep bounties for any user's second answer in Red *or* [Rebol](http://rebol.com) *or* [Rebmu](https://github.com/hostilefork/rebmu) (any scoring criterion) during the month of June.

<sup>[nomination (will be deleted)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20716/90614)</sup>

Comment: Minor correction: View is not a DSL, it's a graphical engine.

Answer (score 7):

## List of all Red solutions posted in June 2021

Please put first posts in bold and place "(bounty?)" afterwards to request a bounty

- **[Print “N NE E SE S SW W NW”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186582/print-n-ne-e-se-s-sw-w-nw/226620#226620) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif)**
- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226668/101522) by **[Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)**
- [Create a program that prints the number of characters it has, in words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226671/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Plot a centered circle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226687/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- **[Little Endian Number to String Conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226674/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)**
- [What is the link to your answer?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226679/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214) (bounty awarded +50)
- [Make a ;# interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226684/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [Plot a centered circle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226688/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [Don't google "google"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58891/dont-google-google/226718#226718) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif) (bounty awarded +50)
- [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226748/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller) (bounty awarded +50)
- [Open the browser to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76604/open-the-browser-to-http-codegolf-stackexchange-com/226772#226772) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif)
- [Write a polyglot that prints the language's name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226855/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Split a list at the second occurrence of the first element](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228914/75681)
   by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Write a hello world GUI program that closes itself after three seconds](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226889/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [Split a list at the second occurrence of the first element](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228949/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [Print random integers until 0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228950/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [Print the tetration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228957/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Don't google “google”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228975/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [Create an ascii line given length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228978/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [The next colour](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228986/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- **[Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229027/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)**
- **[Sylvester's sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229029/97916) by [chunes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97916/chunes)**
- **[Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229091/88546) by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)** (bounty awarded +100)
- [Shortest Code to randomly place points and connect them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229240/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) (bounty awarded +100)
- [I'm Lazy: Close my Superparens](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229262/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Shortest Code to randomly place points and connect them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229263/104280) by [9214](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104280/9214)
- [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229315/88546) by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)
- [Output programming language name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229496/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Collatz's ice cream cone factory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229537/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- **[Compute the generalised XOR](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226765/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)**
- [I'm Lazy*: Top-left align my text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226871/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l) (bounty?)
- [Taking the long route](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229126/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Decode USB packets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229572/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Encode USB packets (part 2)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229657/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Consecutive Distance Rating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229735/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Consecutive Distance Rating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229736/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Binomial transform](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229804/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Can you give me half? (No digits)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230147/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Implement a cleave function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230174/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [What's missing (aka the vanilla multiset difference challenge)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230282/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Is this a Permutation of 1..n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230408/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Print instructions for typing \` in chat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230502/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Create a Pride Flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230563/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Write a C++ demangler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230601/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Get the the day of the year of a given date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230720/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

* Not second answer but for various reasons the bounty is for another answer.

## List of all Red tips posted in June 2021

- [Type casting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226780/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [More on type casting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226826/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Flatten a list of lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226827/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Use `any` to provide a default value](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229178/90614) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [The many uses of `collect` and `keep`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229241/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [String conversion with `do`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229279/88546) by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)
- [Use `alter` instead of append/insert](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229320/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [Use some of the predefined char! values](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230567/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- [forall instead of foreach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230568/75681) by [Galen Ivanov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75681/galen-ivanov)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
   [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Red-related challenges posted in June 2021

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```