# Language of the Month for September 2021: jq

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/78850), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout September 2021, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/78850). In short, during September, those who wish to participate should learn jq, and use it to solve challenges.

### Information about jq

jq is a lightweight practical language for querying JSON files. It's like sed for JSON files.

- Streams in jq can be very powerful. Operators see individual items in strings when applied:

```
range(4) -> 0, 1, 2, 3
range(4) + 2 -> 1, 2, 3, 4

# Sometimes, a cartesian-product-like output can be produced with

range(2) + range(4) -> 0,1, 1,2, 2,3, 3,4
```

- Piping - Outputs of the previous expression can be piped.

```
3 | .+2  #  -> 5

[3, 4, 5] | max   # -> 5
```

- Compact syntax

```
[1, 2, 3] | map( . + 1 ) # -> [2, 3, 4]

# (This could also be achieved as [1, 2, 3][]|.+1)
```

### Bounty

I (Emanresu A, or whatever I end up changing my name to) will award a +50 bounty for any user's first jq answer posted during this month. A user doesn't qualify if they have posted a jq answer before.

I will only award this bounty on questions which I haven't answered, because I have to award +100 or more on questions which I have. If the question you answered has been answered by me as well, provide another jq answer and I'll happily bounty that.

### Resources

- [Official website](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- [Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)
- [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/)
- [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#jq)
- [Tips thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233883/tips-for-golfing-in-jq)

Comment: Your last example can be golfed even further with `1,2,3|.+1`! [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yyr8/99Qx0jHuEZP2/D//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V180pzcnQz8wpKSwA)

Comment: `range(4)+2` should be `2,3,4,5`

Comment: is there going to be a jq chat room?

Comment: @Wezl [There is now!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129436/jq)

Comment: Well, there *was*, but nobody used it. :(

Answer (score 3):

## List of all jq solutions posted in September 2021

*First-time answerers highlighted in bold, bounty requests in italic. For bounty requests, I can't award it if I've bountied the question already or answered it already*.

- [Remove oddly nested substrings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233904/100664) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- ["-rot" transform](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233938) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Is it a brainfuck instruction?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203330/is-it-a-brainfuck-instruction/234970#234970) by [wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif)
- **[The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210071/the-vanilla-factorial-challenge/234981#234981) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)**
- [Make my number binary](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/283838/283953#answer-283953) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Jimmy these arrays down](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93991/jimmy-these-arrays-down/235028#235028) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Index and return 3 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231736/index-and-return-3-characters/235033#235033) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Make the Mexican Wave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53812/make-the-mexican-wave/235044#235044) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Generate the Abacaba sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68978/generate-the-abacaba-sequence/235046#235046) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- ["Hello, {name}!"](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/283966/283977#answer-283977) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- **[Make the Mexican Wave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235047/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)**
- [It was just a bug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235048/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/234999/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Find me vowels near you](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235055/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [Recursively concatenated cumulative sums of [N] with M iterations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144512/recursively-concatenated-cumulative-sums-of-n-with-m-iterations/235059#235059) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Generate alphabet with 4 copies of each letter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235061/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- **[Code Golf Christmas Edition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235063/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)**
- [Print this diamond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235066/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Hunt for discount](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235065/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Approximation of e](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/approximation-of-e/235071#235071) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Generate the Abacaba sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235077/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [Generate alphabet with 4 copies of each letter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15882/generate-alphabet-with-4-copies-of-each-letter/235078#235078) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- **[Display a number in Toki Pona](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/234995/display-a-number-in-toki-pona/235085#235085) by [Lynn](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)**
- [Euler's numerus idoneus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233942/eulers-numerus-idoneus/235086#235086) by [Lynn](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)
- [Print this diamond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/print-this-diamond/235087#235087) by [Lynn](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)
- [Make the Mexican Wave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53812/make-the-mexican-wave/235088#235088) by [Lynn](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)
- [The qvolume of an integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186151/the-qvolume-of-an-integer/235097#235097) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Distinct Sieves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84297/distinct-sieves/235099#235099) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Longest Zero Sum Sub-array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235135/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235141) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- ***[Output a Latin Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223590/output-a-latin-square/235161#235161) by [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)***
- [Print a conversion table for (un)signed bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217614/print-a-conversion-table-for-unsigned-bytes/235163#235163) by [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)
- [Who is the rightful ruler?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235180/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [When's the Listening Party?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/whens-the-listening-party/235133#235133) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Unlolify a lolified message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235199/unlolify-a-lolified-message/235205?noredirect=1#comment535215_235205) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Show me the trajectory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235297/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Implement a 2-tag system simulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235382/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Triple countdown sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235523/triple-countdown-sequence/235528#235528) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of all jq tips posted in September 2021

- [Use try-// instead of if-then-else](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235138/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of jq-related challenges posted in September 2021

- 
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```