# Language of the Month for October 2021: Lean

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/78850), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout October 2021, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## [Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/)

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/78850). In short, during October, those who wish to participate should learn Lean, and use it to solve challenges.

### Information about Lean

<sup>Taken from the [nomination post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22227/66833)</sup>

Lean is a relatively new theorem proving language. It is very user-friendly and it has [a comprehensive math library](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib) which is "slowly eating away mathematics", as [Kevin Buzzard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Buzzard) puts it.

### Pros

- Can be used as a programming language with formal verification support. The upcoming stable release (Lean 4) will make it even easier to program in Lean.
- Strong focus on approachability and soundness.
- There is an active community of Lean users ready to answer your Lean questions.

### Caveats

- Intimidating documentation. It's much faster to ask a question in the Zulip chat than trying to parse the (often very complex and dense) mathlib docs and Lean reference.
- You can't really Google anything about Lean. Lean is relatively obscure. But hey, the same goes for other theorem proving languages, right?

### Resources

- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130185/the-lean-to)
- [Tips for golfing in Lean](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236157/tips-for-golfing-in-lean)
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#lean)
- [GitHub repo (Lean 4)](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4)
- [GitHub repo (Lean 3)](https://github.com/leanprover-community/lean)
- [GitHub repo (mathlib)](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib)
- [The Natural Number Game](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/)
- [Community home page](https://leanprover-community.github.io)
- [Official home page](https://leanprover.github.io)
- [Zulip chat](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## List of all Lean solutions posted in October 2021

(First time posters highlighted in bold)

- [Replace twos with threes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236057/) by **[Wheat Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)**
- [Is it a row of Pascal's triangle?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236062/) by [Wheat Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [What an Odd Function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236161/) by [Wheat Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [∀ a b. a + b = b + a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236117/) by **[Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/)**
- [∀ a b. a + b = b + a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236109/) by **[Mario Carneiro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11143/)**
- [Lean golf: Pascal vs. Fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236140/) by [Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/)
- [Lean golf: List Game (rev_rev)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236185/) by [Wheat Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [Lean golf: List Game (rev_rev)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236190/103581) by [Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/)
- [Every Pong is Abelian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236345/95792) by [**user**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)
- [Swap Two Values in a List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236347/95792) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of all Lean tips posted in October 2021

- [Introductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236158/) by [Wheat Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [Use `by` instead of `begin ... end`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236168/) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/)
- [The `;` and `<|>` combinators](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236176/) by [It'sNotALie.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7819/)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Lean-related challenges posted in October 2021

- [∀ a b. a + b = b + a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236105/) by [Wheat Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [Lean golf: Balanced Bracket Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236143/) by [Huỳnh Trần Khanh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103581/)
- [Lean golf: Pascal vs. Fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236132/) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/)
- [Lean golf: List Game (rev_rev)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236182/lean-golf-list-game-rev-rev) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/)
- [Lean golf: List Game Lv2 (is_in_append, is_in_rev)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/236235/66833) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/)
- [Every Pong is Abelian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/236295/) by [Wheat Witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```