# Language of the Month for December 2021: BQN

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout December 2021, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN)

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during December, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) BQN, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about BQN

<sup>Taken from the [nomination post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23990/78410)</sup>

BQN is a powerful modern language based on the ideas of Ken Iverson's APL, which is already quite popular on CGCC.

The main aim of BQN is to remove irregular and burdensome aspects of the APL tradition while adding newer modern concepts to the mix. This makes BQN oftentimes more practical than APL, and gives it a much more consistent, streamlined design refined from many years of array programming experience.

### Why BQN?

- BQN uses cool looking(important), carefully chosen symbols. This makes it readable and practical, yet very golfy.
- BQN provides strong fundamentals for array programming which you can use for algorithmic coding in any language.
- Lisp style functional programming support which is outlined [here](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/functional.html).
- BQN has the most powerful [tacit system](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/train.html) available in an APL family language.
- [Why BQN?](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/commentary/why.html) is a more comprehensive document on what BQN is currently and what it aims to be.

### Resources

- [The APL Orchard](https://apl.chat) (SE chatroom)
- [online interpreter](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html)
- [C implementation](https://github.com/dzaima/CBQN/)
- [Java implementation](https://github.com/dzaima/BQN/)
- APL Farm [Matrix](https://app.element.io/#/room/%23aplfarm:matrix.org) and [Discord](https://discord.gg/yHna7nt7zx) chatrooms
- [BQNcrate](https://mlochbaum.github.io/bqncrate/), a collection of short snippets for common tasks
- [Tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/237866/78410)

Answer (score 4):

## List of all BQN answers posted in December 2021

- [AoCG2021 Day 1: Automated delivery frenzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237856/aocg2021-day-1-automated-delivery-frenzy/237942#237942) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [AoCG2021 Day 2: Naughty or nice?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237920/aocg2021-day-2-naughty-or-nice/237955#237955) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [AoCG2021 Day 3: Say-Look-Say](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237995/aocg2021-day-3-say-look-say/238009#238009) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Create an ASCII line, given a length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/228953/create-an-ascii-line-given-a-length/238084#238084) by [PyGamer0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103854)
- [Print a Tabula Recta!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238225/45220) by [SjoerdPennings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45220)
- [Bernardino identifies unaltered dollar words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238255/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Output programming language name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238286/45220) by [SjoerdPennings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45220)
- [Swap every two elements in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238285/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [AoCG2021 Day 10: Memory reallocation routine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238319/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [AoCG2021 Day 9: Spiral memory stress test](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238258/aocg2021-day-9-spiral-memory-stress-test/238320#238320) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [AoCG2021 Day 11: Garbageful streams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238353/aocg2021-day-11-garbageful-streams/238365#238365) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Chunk Sort a Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238489/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Alphabet Staircase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238518/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Return all letter counts as an integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238565/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [Implement Minceraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238571/45220) by [SjoerdPennings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45220)
- [Generate the Chess Numbers™](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238594/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Helloellolloloo Worldorldrldldd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239642/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Greatest Common Divisor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239703/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [Pascal's Triangle as a 2-dimensional list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239718/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [AoCG2021 Day 18: Stripping Strips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239744/64121) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- [Check if the string is reshaped](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239788/check-if-the-string-is-reshaped/239795#239795) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Nesting list with value `n` amount of times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239910/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Bubbler and 3 others are typing․․․](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239972/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Convert the decimal digits of a string's Unicode codepoints to binary, reinterpret as decimal, and take the sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239935/convert-the-decimal-digits-of-a-strings-unicode-codepoints-to-binary-reinterpr/240032#240032) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [When does Santa enter the basement? (AOC Day 1)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73384/when-does-santa-enter-the-basement-aoc-day-1/240096#240096) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Swap Two Values in a List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240195/95126) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)
- [Repeating slices of an array incrementally](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240212/95126) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)
- [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240265/95126) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)
- [Shuffle a subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240334/95126) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)
- [An ASCII self-referential sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240354/95126) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in December 2021

- [Use `⊒˜` instead of `↕∘≠`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237866/tips-for-golfing-in-bqn/238023#238023) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [BQN's combinators](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237866/tips-for-golfing-in-bqn/238371#238371) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in December 2021

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```