# Language of the Month for January 2022: Add++

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout January 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus)

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during January, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Add++, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Add++

Add++ is a language that combines both short commands and other golfing features with general usability and practical language features. For example, I've written a [programming language](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Adjust) in Add++, and most solutions in Add++ are easy to understand for users of both practical and golfing languages. For example, it's ease at switching between functional and vanilla mode allows it to create competitive hybrid programs.

### Why Add++?

- There aren't many languages like it. In my experience on the site, I don't recall seeing any languages with a similar model to Add++
- It is widely usable. I would describe Add++ as a practical language with one- or two-byte commands, so it's easily accessible to all golfers
- It's somewhat used across the site. Primarily by me, but there are multiple answers by other users, and we already have a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113154/add)
- Due to its wide range of builtins, it is very powerful, and so can complete most challenges competitively with other golfing languages.

  - Closer to Pyth and CJam rather than Jelly and 05AB1E however
- It has [version tracking](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus/blob/master/versions.md), and each version can be run via command-line flags
- Its [docs](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus/wiki) are fairly comprehensive, thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)

### Caveats

The docs do not contain a comprehensive list of commands, and it is somewhat strict in its syntax, which can lead to a lot of errors. Furthermore, Add++ still has some bugs in the code, along with some confusing behaviours.

I'm currently writing the latest version (v6) in order to someone mitigate the biggest problems I have with Add++, but this is, at time of writing, unreleased.

### Resources

- [Github repo](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus)
- [Tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240402/66833)
- [Wiki](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus/wiki)
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#addpp)
- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113154/add). Feel free to ping me (`@cairdcoinheringaahing`) if you have any questions, I'll respond when I can.

### Bounties

I'll be offering a +50 rep bounty to any user's *second* Add++ answer. The first answer can be posted during or before this month, but the second must be posted during January 2022. In addition, I'm offering +300 to any user's tenth Add++ answer posted during Add++'s LOTM.

Additionally, as the "relevant challenges" portion of LOTM doesn't really get much attention, I'm offering a +500 bounty to any user who posts an Add++ themed challenge that goes on to score 10 or more

Comment: Clever bounty system!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## List of all Add++ answers posted in January 2022

(first-time posters in **bold**)

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```
- [Numbers by Position](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201176/numbers-by-position/240406#240406) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Produce the number 2014 without any numbers in your source code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code/240407#240407) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Incrementally Increment Identical Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240421/incrementally-increment-identical-integers/240454#240454) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Create an array with repeated numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42536/create-an-array-with-repeated-numbers/240457#240457) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Reverse Array Sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135417/reverse-array-sum/240459#240459) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Reverse factorial function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205033/reverse-factorial-function/240460#240460) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime/240461#240461) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Collect the elements of an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240512/collect-the-elements-of-an-array/240513#240513) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Is this even or odd?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/is-this-even-or-odd/240543#240543) by [Fmbalbuena](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106959/fmbalbuena)
- [Encode integers with some others](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240597/encode-integers-with-some-others/240609#240609) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Recover the power from the prime power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167199/recover-the-power-from-the-prime-power/240610#240610) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [One OEIS after another](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240880/106959) by [Fmbalbuena](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106959/fmbalbuena)

## List of relevant tips posted in January 2022

- [Use `D` loops if code needs to be executed at least once in a `W` loop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240403/66833) by [Fmbalbuena](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106959/fmbalbuena)
- [Use `L` for the main function, `D` for helper functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240404/66833) by [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)
- [Call your helper functions `I`, `K`, `Y`, `Z`, `g`, `k`, `l`, `u` or `w`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240418/66833) by [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in January 2022

- [Collect the elements of an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240512/66833) by [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/66833), based around Add++'s `BC` builtin
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```