# Language of the Month for February 2022: tinylisp

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout February 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp)

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during February, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) tinylisp, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about tinylisp

I (DLosc) invented tinylisp, a minimalist Lisp dialect, for [an interpreter golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62886). Because [Lisp is powerful](https://www.xkcd.com/224/), tinylisp's small set of builtins can be combined to solve a wide variety of tasks. It also has a half-decent standard library, implemented using those builtins, that provides many more functions for arithmetic, list manipulation, and functional programming.

### Why tinylisp?

- The core builtins are one character each, contributing to golfiness.
- The standard library costs bytes to load, but provides many higher-level functions. Sometimes using the library is shorter; sometimes avoiding it is shorter.
- Being a Lisp dialect, tinylisp is pretty good at functional programming and list manipulation.

### Caveats

- The only documentation is the GitHub readme, which gives a decent introduction to the syntax and builtins but doesn't cover the library at all.
- There is no way to take input, and only limited ways of producing output. Most tinylisp solutions are therefore function solutions.
- String operations are supported, but not very thoroughly. All numbers are integers--no rationals or floating point.
- If you don't already speak Lisp, tinylisp might be hard to understand. On the other hand, Lisp is cool, and tinylisp could serve as a good introduction!

### Resources

- [Github repo](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp)
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#tinylisp)
- [Tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108311)
- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52509)
- [Ungolfing script](https://tio.run/##dVRNb9pAEL3vr1j5ZBcLBXpDpRVSURWpMQfIibjIiYeyzbJ2dxdU@vHbycysN0CSXpDffLyZeTNLe/Cbxrw/HtW2bayXFnLpDk6I2/l09XVWfFkVk5vpXI7lwu5AXBefp8VisrieFavJzey2WKBnIMRF5B8hkyoZ4U9dD5Mc0QOhh8Y4RjWhGtYMgAD83FX6E@MN4Q1UNSNFSIVITd8anAuBjqDb3YcKnpCvlGa0Z9J9ReifEFhL@uYRjPoNqVYGspEIBoftWuivlakrrdNk@S3NZNn7ezdPckmRfeetatMsE1Kt5aUoSHJiWZ7s/e/gU3bkwZ/JdWPDp1SmyykFVvY7G3Fos62sg5C8Uh4sd2oBqAJmaNiDxu8r8QYlJ1BTqhtXjscyyRIyyXsL1eNLXxp8qGJX41V5csei2@pXyt95zFhelbInBxzFDD1ss/NhtxK0g9F/KF5kcc2TJkuOInaKCNrgxNsKlUVDjkPXYPz49UGSYjTkoQUOzaRyuErnqRELbqe95NEFD45Tbnl/HTvhyI7V3@Bn5SmMhScVBqOy7KTtRPkohzw3mjSYro9ovGhvOSy5Q9N47lLSWoOdiD7EnNg6ahW7DuonMgkBZ8M8R2BnvGBoaeY7k4QE@a6b8HxHXRDTdVuINcnX/9Eok0bmjIgyDI3p8ZZ5W6QQvR5SCP9N8BHVyvTxAmuyuvTi/V2@zOdzD6dIRxjukYehd9haZXx6dgxZdjw@AQ) (put your golfed code in the Input box)
- [Syntax highlighter](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/tinylisp/highlight/)

### Bounties

*(Adapted from caird's bounty scheme for Add++ last month)*

I'll be offering a +50 rep bounty to any user's *second* tinylisp answer. The first answer can be posted during or before this month, but the second must be posted during February 2022. In addition, I'm offering +200 to any user's tenth tinylisp answer posted during tinylisp's time as LotM.

Additionally, as the "relevant challenges" portion of LotM doesn't get enough attention, I'm offering a +500 bounty to any user who posts a tinylisp-themed challenge that goes on to score 10 or more.

Finally, if somebody posts a shorter answer to the original [Tiny Lisp, tiny interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62886) challenge, I will give a +500 bounty to the new shortest solution at the end of the month. The current leader is [Ell's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62975/16766) at 640 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## List of all tinylisp answers posted in February 2022

(first-time posters in **bold**, 50-point bounty marked with <sup>+</sup>, 200-point bounty marked with <sup>++</sup>)

- [Find the number of integers in the range from 1 to N that ends with 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200363/find-the-number-of-integers-in-the-range-from-1-to-n-that-ends-with-2/242141#242141) by **[Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)**
- [Reversed Multiple Pair](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241992/reversed-multiple-pair/242142#242142)<sup>+</sup> by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Ken Iverson’s Favourite APL Expression?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216479/ken-iverson-s-favourite-apl-expression/242143#242143) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Next Greater Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240743/next-greater-number/242146#242146) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Patience, young "Padovan"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182797/patience-young-padovan/242147#242147) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Determine the depth of an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71476/determine-the-depth-of-an-array/242148#242148) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242156/106710) by **[ThisFieldIsRequired](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106710/thisfieldisrequired)**
- [Prime a*b+c of N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242210/106710)<sup>+</sup> by [ThisFieldIsRequired](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106710/thisfieldisrequired)
- [The dragon Curve sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128858/the-dragon-curve-sequence/242208#242208) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Egyptian fraction representations of 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242198) by **[Axuary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101349/axuary)**
- [Egyptian fraction representations of 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242223)<sup>+</sup> by [**Giuseppe**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [The dragon Curve sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128858/the-dragon-curve-sequence/242229#242229) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Bernardino identifies unaltered dollar words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116933/bernardino-identifies-unaltered-dollar-words/242234#242234) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Reverse Array Sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242237/97916) by **[chunes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/97916/chunes)**
- [Implement the hyperfactorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242259/97916) by [chunes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/97916/chunes)
- [Implement an Over function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242262/97916)<sup>+</sup> by [chunes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/97916/chunes)
- [The shortest code to invert bit-wise a binary string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30361/the-shortest-code-to-invert-bit-wise-a-binary-string/242266#242266) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/242270#242270) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Digital Sumorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176948/digital-sumorial/242285#242285)<sup>++</sup> by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Implement an argwhere function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241357/implement-an-argwhere-function/242227#242227) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Find the maximum length in a ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240673/find-the-maximum-length-in-a-ragged-list/242235#242235) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Scan a ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240612/scan-a-ragged-list/242238#242238) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Double trace of a square matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236579/double-trace-of-a-square-matrix/242296#242296) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Print a 10 by 10 grid of asterisks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88653/print-a-10-by-10-grid-of-asterisks/242331#242331) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Draw an asterisk triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95780/draw-an-asterisk-triangle/242333#242333) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Maximal number of regions obtained by joining n points around a circle by straight lines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96887/maximal-number-of-regions-obtained-by-joining-n-points-around-a-circle-by-straig/242337#242337) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Shortest code to produce infinite output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output/242378#242378) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Output the sign](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103822/output-the-sign/242380#242380) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Halloween Golf: The 2spooky4me Challenge!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62350/halloween-golf-the-2spooky4me-challenge/242383#242383) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [In for a bumpy ride](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167924/in-for-a-bumpy-ride/242418#242418) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Output the sign](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103822/output-the-sign/242503#242503) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Alphabet Staircase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/147469/alphabet-staircase/242300#242300) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Is this number evil?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/169724/is-this-number-evil/242360#242360) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Sum the array times n, except the last](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206967/sum-the-array-times-n-except-the-last/242362#242362) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Sum of two squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242459/sum-of-two-squares/242494#242494) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Chunk Sort a Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238329/chunk-sort-a-sequence/242556#242556)<sup>++</sup> by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Distance to closest subsequent value](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242532/distance-to-closest-subsequent-value/242557#242557) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Sum of two squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242459/sum-of-two-squares/242566#242566) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Be the First 1 (leave only the first Truthy)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119472/be-the-first-1-leave-only-the-first-truthy/243302#243302) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Sing Happy Birthday to your favourite programming language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/sing-happy-birthday-to-your-favourite-programming-language/242399#242399)<sup>(+)</sup> by [Axuary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101349/axuary)
- [Add two numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84260/add-two-numbers/243148#243148) by [Axuary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101349/axuary)
- [Is this number triangular?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122087/is-this-number-triangular/242613#242613) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Rolling a ball over a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242660/rolling-a-ball-over-a-list/242685#242685) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Find the sum of the divisors of N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142071/find-the-sum-of-the-divisors-of-n/243354#243354) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in February 2022

- [Try switching the order of expressions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242233/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Abuse builtins for type-checking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242255/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in February 2022

- [Ungolf my tinylisp code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242257/ungolf-my-tinylisp-code) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```