# Language of the Month for March 2022: PARI/GP

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/9288), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout March 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/9288). In short, during March , those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) PARI/GP, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about PARI/GP

PARI/GP is a CAS (Computer Algebra System) designed for number theory. It consists of two parts: PARI is a C library, GP is an interactive shell and a scripting language. Even if you are not familiar with algebraic number theory, GP is still a powerful language for golfing math problems.

### Reasons

- Intuitive syntax and good documentations. Easy to learn.
- Built-in types for vectors, matrices, polynomials, power series, and many other math objects.
- Lots of built-ins, especially for number theory, but also for linear algebra, polynomials, and other branches of algebra.
- Single byte operator `#` for length (of vectors, matrices, strings, etc.).
- Many OEIS pages have a PARI/GP program for the sequence.

### Caveats

- Not so many built-ins outside of math. On the other hand, this force you to think out of the box, for example, using polynomials to solve array challenges.
- Very limited array programming. You can add two vector or multiply a vector by a scalar, but there is no built-in to do element-wise multiplication.
- You need to know some math to master the language.
- The version on TIO is somewhat out of date.

### Resources

- [Official website](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)
- [Tutorial](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.13.3/tutorial.pdf)
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#pari-gp)
- [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWaBSUBgA)
- [Run PARI/GP in your browser](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html)
- [Golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78193/9288)
- [Reference card for 2.13.3 (the newest version)](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.13.3/refcard.pdf)
- [Reference card for 2.11.1 (the version on TIO)](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.11.1/refcard.pdf)

### Bounties

I (alephalpha) will be offering a +50 rep bounty to any user's first PARI/GP answer during this month, and +200 to any user's tenth PARI/GP answer during this month. This includes using the GP scripting language, or using the PARI lib in a C/C++ answer.

Comment: PARI/GP is now on ATO: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?L=pari_gp

Answer (score 4):

## List of all PARI/GP answers posted in March 2022

(first-time posters in **bold**)

- [Find the Factorial!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243665/108218) by **[Ginger Industries](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108218/ginger-industries)**
- [Draw a battery indicator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243517/106710) by **[ophact](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106710/ophact)**
- [Draw an ASCII grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243521/100664) by **[emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664)**
- [Complex permutation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244106/103854) by [**PyGamer0**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103854/pygamer0)
- [Output a random unary string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243525/output-a-random-unary-string/243546#243546) by **[DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)**
- [Codegolf the Hafnian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156988/codegolf-the-hafnian/243588#243588) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Calculate a square and a square root!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243652/107017) by **[oeuf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107017/oeuf)**
- [Fill in the next numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243764/fill-in-the-next-numbers/243775#243775) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Is it irrational?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243850/is-it-irrational/243883#243883) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Zip uneven lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244049/zip-uneven-lists/244094#244094) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Randomly Rounding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244210/randomly-rounding/244240#244240) by [**jezza_99**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Sort numbers in a ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244101/sort-numbers-in-a-ragged-list/244260#244260) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Recursively rotate a ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244198/recursively-rotate-a-ragged-list/245289#245289) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Recreate Minecraft's lighting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245451/recreate-minecrafts-lighting/245461#245461) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [The interstice of two binary numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245539/the-interstice-of-two-binary-numbers/245577#245577) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Expand a matrix goo-ily](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245583/expand-a-matrix-goo-ily/245588#245588) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Convert from variable-width Two's Complement to Integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245492/convert-from-twos-complement-to-decimal/245637#245637) by [Joe Slater](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103291/joe-slater)
- [Remove unmatched brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245625/remove-unmatched-brackets/245660#245660) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Removed J-brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245692/removed-j-brackets/245695#245695) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Find the J twin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245748/find-the-j-twin/245758#245758) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in March 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in March 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```