# Language of the Month for April 2022: Curry

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/9288), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout April 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Curry

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/9288). In short, during April, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Curry, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Curry

At first brush Curry just looks like a dialect of site darling Haskell.  It has a slightly different basic library, and slightly more powerful pattern matching.

But Curry has something that makes it really interesting.  Curry can also do logical programming.  Meaning that while Haskell always takes the first available path, Curry will take all paths looking for correct result.  You can get the compiler to do the search for you.  This is the power behind Prolog combined with the clean expressive functional nature of Haskell.

Not only does this make Curry really unique and interesting as a language,  this opens up all sorts of opportunities for golfing. Curry can be logical when it's the best and functional when it's not.

If you're into Haskell or Prolog golf I cannot recommend Curry enough.  If you're not so into those but you are interested I think Curry is an excellent way to sample both techniques.

### Resources

- [Curry chatroom on CGCC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135209/curry)
- [PAKCS on TIO](https://tio.run/#curry-pakcs)
- [Sloth on TIO](https://tio.run/#curry-sloth)
- The [MCC](http://danae.uni-muenster.de/curry/) implementation.
- The [KiCS2](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/) implementation.
- The [Curry2Go](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/curry2go/) implementation.
- [A Curry tutorial](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Ecurry/tutorial/tutorial.pdf)
- The [KiCS2 manual](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/Manual.pdf).
- [Currygle](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/currygle/) a Curry search engine based on Hoogle.

Comment: Yet another implementation: https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/curry2go/

Comment: @alephalpha I've added that into the post.  I have to wonder if that implementation was made entirely for the purposes of that pun.

Comment: heres the [official curry report](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/_media/documentation/report.pdf), which contains more details about some of the language syntax and specifications than the tutorial linked here

Answer (score 2):

## List of all Curry answers posted in April 2022

- [Damerau-Damerau distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245804/damerau-damerau-distance/245858#245858) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Generate all groupings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242783/generate-all-groupings/245907#245907) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Prime numbers in large number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171038/prime-numbers-in-large-number/245943#245943) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
- ["DDoouubbllee ssppeeaakk!!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188988/ddoouubbllee-ssppeeaakk/245945#245945) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Zip uneven lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244049/zip-uneven-lists/245946#245946) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Flippign Lettesr Aroudn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/flippign-lettesr-aroudn/245947#245947) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Length-terminated sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194230/length-terminated-sequences/245948#245948) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Is it a tower permutation?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243173/is-it-a-tower-permutation/245951#245951) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Is it a circumfix?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194929/is-it-a-circumfix/245958#245958) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Is it a fibonacci-like sequence?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242935/is-it-a-fibonacci-like-sequence/245968#245968) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Convert prefix to infix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237574/convert-prefix-to-infix/245969#245969) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [AoCG2021 Day 20: Wonky license check](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239852/aocg2021-day-20-wonky-license-check/245970#245970) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Are the brackets fully matched?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched/245977#245977) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Is it double speak?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189358/is-it-double-speak/245991#245991) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Determine whether strings are anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/determine-whether-strings-are-anagrams/246041#246041) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Repeat List Until Longer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243958/repeat-list-until-longer/246043#246043) by [des54321](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111305)
- [Find the J twin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245748/find-the-j-twin/246054#246054) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Complex permutation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244078/complex-permutation/246055#246055) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [AoCG2021 Day 2: Naughty or nice?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237920/aocg2021-day-2-naughty-or-nice/246057#246057) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Code-Golf: Permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/code-golf-permutations/246062#246062) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)
- [Print a bunch of uninteresting numbers!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/print-a-bunch-of-uninteresting-numbers/246093#246093) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Convert the type modifiers from prefix to C-fix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246125/convert-the-type-modifiers-from-prefix-to-c-fix/246126#246126) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Generate all Sublist Partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121388/generate-all-sublist-partitions/246201#246201) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Is this propositional formula an instance of an axiom?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246228/is-this-propositional-formula-an-instance-of-an-axiom/246229#246229) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Pair my brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246238/pair-my-brackets/246261#246261) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Convert J brackets back to 2-D list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246316/convert-j-brackets-back-to-2-d-list/246322#246322) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Count of "a"s and "b"s must be equal. Did you get it computer?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/count-of-as-and-bs-must-be-equal-did-you-get-it-computer/246528#246528) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- [Parse Ternary Lambda Calculus for correctness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233589/parse-ternary-lambda-calculus-for-correctness/246676#246676) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in April 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in April 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```