# Language of the Month for June 2022: J-uby

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout June 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## J-uby

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during June, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) J-uby, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about J-uby

J-uby is a superset of Ruby that attempts to tacitify ruby using its metaprogramming features, overloading existing operators as combinators and other neat little things.

Cyoce, a fellow code golf user, made J-uby in 2017. Since then it has been largely unchanged and underused. There are many golfing tricks to be found, and many Ruby features to exploit.

### Resources

- [Repository](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby)
- [Cyoce's answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A41042+J-uby)
- [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#j-uby)

Answer (score 7):

## List of all J-uby answers posted in June 2022

- [`lol` is an ambigram, `dad` isn't](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248070/lol-is-a-palindrome-dad-isnt/248074#248074) by [badatgolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108879/badatgolf)
- [Reverse hex cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247804/reverse-hex-cipher/248083#248083) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Sum of all integers from 1 to n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133109/sum-of-all-integers-from-1-to-n/248137#248137) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Find the Factorial!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial/248140#248140) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Is it a semiprime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138011/is-it-a-semiprime/248222#248222) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in June 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in June 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```