# Language of the Month for July 2022: Piet

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout July 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Piet

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during July, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Piet, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Piet

Piet is a classic esolang that dates back to 2001 (according to Esolangs article), which is unique in that it operates on an image rather than source code.

But "source code being an image" is only part of its uniqueness. The instruction pointer moves around in the unit of single-colored areas, as opposed to individual cells. Also, the commands execute when the IP crosses the border, and the relative difference between two colors defines the command. Finally, pushing a large number can be done in one step but it requires an area of that many cells, which gives a metagolfing potential for pushing number constants.

### Resources

- [Official Piet spec](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html)
- [npiet](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/), a "classic" Piet interpreter
- [Esolangs article](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet)
- [Bubbler/piet](https://bubbler-4.github.io/piet/), a "new" Piet editor/interpreter
- [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet) which most of the new Piet answers use for scoring
- [Golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245785/78410) / [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135395/piet)

I (Steffan) will also offer a +100 bounty for any user's 2nd Piet answer in July.

Answer (score 6):

## List of all Piet answers posted in July 2022

- [Print the ASCII Code page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249375/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Division and remainder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114003/division-and-remainder/249414#249414) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Semidivisibility](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220281/semidivisibility/249428#249428) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Divisibility test](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86149/divisibility-test/249429#249429) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Output the hours at 90 degrees](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152114/output-the-hours-at-90-degrees/249456#249456) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Print the ASCII Code page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249510/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Output the hours at 90 degrees](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249558/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [The letter A without A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249562/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Erverse Hte Ifrst Wto Eltters fo Aech Owrd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249617/104752) by [m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104752)
- [Sum of Powers of 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250053) by [Nilster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103091)
- [Multiply two numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/multiply-two-numbers/250255#250255) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Encode the alphabet cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250392/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Output a googol copies of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250363/104563) by [sfieger](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/104563/sfieger)
- [Letters to numbers to letters (poorly)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250468/104563) by [sfieger](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/104563/sfieger)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in July 2022

- [If-else-bounce-merge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249511/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in July 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```