# Language of the Month for September 2022: Prolog

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout September 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Prolog

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during September, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Prolog, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Prolog

> Prolog or PROgramming in LOGics is a logical and declarative programming language. It is one major example of the fourth generation language that supports the declarative programming paradigm. This is particularly suitable for programs that involve symbolic or non-numeric computation. This is the main reason to use Prolog as the programming language in Artificial Intelligence, where symbol manipulation and inference manipulation are the fundamental tasks.
>
> In Prolog, we need not mention the way how one problem can be solved, we just need to mention what the problem is, so that Prolog automatically solves it. However, in Prolog we are supposed to give clues as the solution method.

-- [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prolog/prolog_introduction.htm)

### Resources

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog)
- [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/) (on [TIO](https://tio.run/#prolog-swi))
- [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/)
- [Tutorial](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/prolog/) on Learn X in Y Minutes
- or on [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prolog/prolog_introduction.htm)
- [Tips for golfing in Prolog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/tips-for-golfing-in-prolog)
- [Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74093/the-prolog-cabin)

### Bounty

I, Steffan, will offer a +100 bounty for any user's 5th Prolog answer in September.
I, user, will *try* to offer a n*100 bounty for any user's nth Prolog answer in September.

Comment: Wonder where that come from

Comment: @TKirishima I actually nominated it a few months ago, before weekgolf even existed lol

Comment: Most of the people here probably don't even know week.golf exists, to be honest. It was just a coincidence.

Comment: TIL about week.golf.

Comment: @Steffan Any advice on learning with SWI vs GNU?

Comment: @Jonah I've never used GNU prolog, so idk.

Answer (score 4):

## List of all Prolog answers posted in September 2022

- [Previous Fibonacci number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247835/previous-fibonacci-number/251536#251536) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Sum of Modulo Sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102685/sum-of-modulo-sums/251537#251537) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [The second even sublime number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251351/the-second-even-sublime-number/251547#251547) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210071/the-vanilla-factorial-challenge/251552#251552) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Code-Golf: Permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/code-golf-permutations/251559#251559) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Anti-divisors of a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250883/anti-divisors-of-a-number/251560#251560) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Cartesian - polar conversion couple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250918/cartesian-polar-conversion-couple/251562#251562) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210071/the-vanilla-factorial-challenge/251561#251561) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Add parentheses to Polish notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251570/91213) by [Mousetail](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91213/mousetail)
- [Calculate average characters of string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53675/calculate-average-characters-of-string/251567#251567) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Sum of all integers from 1 to n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133109/sum-of-all-integers-from-1-to-n/251569#251569) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine/251565#251565) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Carry-less sum given a base b](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251283/carry-less-sum-given-a-base-b/251574#251574) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Add parentheses to Polish notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250861/add-parentheses-to-polish-notation/251577) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Shifted auto-sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250338/shifted-auto-sum/251578#251578) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Rearrange to a palindrome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250283/rearrange-to-a-palindrome/251579#251579) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Difference of three input integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71335/difference-of-three-input-integers/251584#251584) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Make a list flat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248245/make-a-list-flat/251587#251587) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Zip uneven lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244049/zip-uneven-lists/251591#251591) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [All together now](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77608/all-together-now/251612#251612) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Sum of partition numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251603/sum-of-partition-numbers/251619#251619) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [How does the square end?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136078/how-does-the-square-end/251600#251600) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Make a list flat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248245/make-a-list-flat/251590#251590) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Am I not good enough for you?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181350/am-i-not-good-enough-for-you/251593#251593) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Is it a Mersenne Prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104508/is-it-a-mersenne-prime/251624#251624) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Find the nth Mersenne Prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251594/find-the-nth-mersenne-prime/251625#251625) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Sort odd numbers first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168765/sort-odd-numbers-first/251628#251628) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [It's time for a clock challenge!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107116/its-time-for-a-clock-challenge/251631#251631) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Is This an Equivalence Relation?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251626/is-this-an-equivalence-relation/251635#251635) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Is it a pangram?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66197/is-it-a-pangram/251644#251644) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Sums of Consecutive Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66193/sums-of-consecutive-integers/251645#251645) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Minimum excluded number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/minimum-excluded-number/251648#251648) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [One OEIS after another](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133754/one-oeis-after-another/251651#251651) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Lengthen letter runs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119278/lengthen-letter-runs/251653#251653) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Check whether letters of word are in alphabetical order](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47201/check-whether-letters-of-word-are-in-alphabetical-order/251654#251654) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [The "Fly straight, dammit" sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251689/the-fly-straight-dammit-sequence/251707#251707) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Sum of combinations with repetition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155938/sum-of-combinations-with-repetition/251717#251717) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Number of ways to make an amount with coins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251674/number-of-ways-to-make-an-amount-with-coins/251721#251721) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Convert superscript numbers to normal numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238462/convert-superscript-numbers-to-normal-numbers/251734#251734) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Persistence of a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251656/persistence-of-a-number/251757#251757) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- ["DDoouubbllee ssppeeaakk!!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188988/ddoouubbllee-ssppeeaakk/251761#251761) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Scream very loudly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200306/scream-very-loudly/251763#251763) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Tut-tut-tut-tut-tut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251772/tut-tut-tut-tut-tut/251784#251784) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Numbers by Position](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201176/numbers-by-position/251825#251825) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Get the length of a Sumac Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251861/91213) by [Mousetail](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91213/mousetail)
- [Sudoku Solver Diagonal Constraint](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251925/sudoku-solver-diagonal-constraint/251964#251964) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Fibonacci word fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251740/fibonacci-word-fractal/251918#251918) by [crowproxy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114450/crowproxy)
- [Re-name all identifiers to a single letter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251864/re-name-all-identifiers-to-a-single-letter/251901#251901) by [crowproxy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114450/crowproxy)
- [Decipher a squashed sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249208/decipher-a-squashed-sequence/251881#251881) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)
- [Re-name all identifiers to a single letter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251864/re-name-all-identifiers-to-a-single-letter/252173#252173) by [0                                                                                                                '](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20059/0)
- [Am I a Fibonacci Number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126373/am-i-a-fibonacci-number/252215#252215) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Find the sum of the divisors of N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142071/find-the-sum-of-the-divisors-of-n/252243#252243) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in September 2022

- [Shorter stdlib alternatives](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/tips-for-golfing-in-prolog/251862#251862) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in September 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```