# Language of the Month for October 2022: Nim

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout October 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Nim

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during October, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Nim, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Nim

The Nim programming language is a ergonomic general purpose programming language, featuring:

- Concise string handling
- First class functions, called "procedural types"
- User-defined iterators
- Metaprogramming of all sorts, everything from text-substitution, to macros that operate on its AST ([Introduction to metaprogramming in Nim](https://hookrace.net/blog/introduction-to-metaprogramming-in-nim/))
- Great C/C++/JS interop
- Large stdlib
- Usually quick compile/run time (good for [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenges)

### Resources

Nim has a very active community ([forum](https://forum.nim-lang.org), [subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/nim)). It can be run online at [TIO](https://tio.run/#nim) and [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?L=nim).

A quick intro, covering only the most basic constructs:

- [Nim basics](https://narimiran.github.io/nim-basics/)

For more extensive reading:

- [Installation instructions](https://nim-lang.org/install.html)
- [For C Programmers](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/wiki/Nim-for-C-programmers)
- [For Python Programmers](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/wiki/Nim-for-Python-programmers)
- [More extensive resources](https://nim-lang.org/documentation.html)
- [Tips for golfing in Nim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101179/tips-for-golfing-in-nim)

Comment: @DialFrost https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=62125375#62125375

Answer (score 5):

## List of all Nim answers posted in October 2022

- [Repeat Values In Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252442/repeat-values-in-array/252591#252591) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Draw the Ukrainian Flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245318/draw-the-ukrainian-flag/252592#252592) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Cat goes "Meow"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252680/104836) by [Qaziquza](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104836/qaziquza)
- [Which weekday was it?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252621/which-weekday-was-it/252687#252687) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Are All the Items the Same?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224000/are-all-the-items-the-same/252613#252613) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Is it a pure word?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241080/is-it-a-pure-word/252675#252675) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Implement a strange automaton](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135942/implement-a-strange-automaton/252731#252731) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Mix pi and e to make pie!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252851/104836) by [Qaziquza](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104836/qaziquza)
- [Concatenating n with n + 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167818/concatenating-n-with-n-1/252887#252887) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Modulus Summation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150563/modulus-summation/252888#252888) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Concatenating n with n + 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167818/concatenating-n-with-n-1/252926#252926) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- [Implement the flip-floperator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253735/78274) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in October 2022

- [Use on and off as a boolean value](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252588/90812) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in October 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```