# Language of the Month for November 2022: J

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout November 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## J

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during November, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) J, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about J

J is a high-level, general-purpose programming language that is particularly suited to the mathematical, statistical, and logical analysis of data. It is a powerful tool for developing algorithms and exploring problems that are not already well understood.

### Resources

- [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jsoftware/jsource)
- [Wiki](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Main_Page)
- Run J on [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboWaBSUBgA) and [TIO](https://tio.run/#j)
- [Official site](https://jsoftware.com/)
- [Tutorial](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/contents.htm)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_(programming_language))
- [Tips for golfing in J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/tips-for-golfing-in-j)

### Bounty

I, [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an), will offer a +100 bounty to every user's 1st J answer in November.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## List of all J answers posted in November 2022

(Bolded means bountied)

- **[Indexize a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114249/indexize-a-number/253976#253976) by [south](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110888/south)**
- **[The Art of Word Shaping](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99749/the-art-of-word-shaping/254016#254016) by [Jonah](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)**
- [Power sequence differences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253989/power-sequence-differences/254023#254023) by [south](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110888/south)
- [Unslice a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73805/unslice-a-string/254071#254071) by [Jonah](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)
- [Nth Differences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142458/nth-differences/254262#254262) by [Jonah](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)
- [Letters, Get Moving!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66556/letters-get-moving/254334#254334) by [Jonah](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)
- [Maximum average ord](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254224/maximum-average-ord/254365#254365) by [south](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110888/south)
- [Length of Binary as Base 10 [OEIS A242347]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253857/length-of-binary-as-base-10-oeis-a242347/254424#254424) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Previous Fibonacci number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247835/previous-fibonacci-number/254474#254474) by [south](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110888/south)
- [Shifted auto-sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250338/shifted-auto-sum/254498#254498) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Reverse hex cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247804/reverse-hex-cipher/254500#254500) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- **[UNIX Uniq Uknow?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92285/unix-uniq-uknow/254617#254617) by [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)**
- **[Help me sell day-old bagels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241373/help-me-sell-day-old-bagels/254779#254779) by [m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104752/m90)**
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in November 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in November 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```