# Language of the Month for December 2022: Pip

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout December 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Pip

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during December, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Pip, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Pip

Pip is an interpreted, imperative code-golf language created by @DLosc.

> Unlike most golfing languages, but like many practical languages, Pip is an imperative language with infix operators. It also uses plain ASCII instead of a custom codepage. These features make it a great introduction to golflangs for users of imperative languages like Python, JavaScript, and Perl.

Pip's more "traditional" style of programming, combined with a number of uncommon builtin features, makes it very interesting to program in.

- Pip is very strong with regex. It has [operations](https://dloscutoff.github.io/pipdoc/regex) that allow combination of strings and regexes, and has special regex match variables.
- Pip's [bugs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230321/80214) make it a hilariously golfy language (and what is code golf, if not funny?).
- Operator precedence and input format optimization are very important in Pip, which is a mini challenge in itself.

#### Interpreters

- Download from [GitHub](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) (requires Python >= 3.8)
- [DSO](https://dso.surge.sh/#pip)
- [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?L=pip) (currently broken)
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#pip) (outdated)
- [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip)

#### Information

- [Documentation](https://dloscutoff.github.io/pipdoc/)
- [Tutorial](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/wiki) (in progress)
- [Esolangs.org](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pip)
- [Tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210380/tips-for-golfing-in-pip/)

@DLosc and @Razetime are usually available in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) to answer any Pip questions. (Feel free to ping either of us.)

## Bounty

I, [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan), will offer:

- +100 bounty to every user's 1st Pip answer in December
- +250 bounty to every user's 5th Pip answer in December

If I forget to offer a bounty, feel free to ping me in chat.

Answer (score 6):

## List of all Pip answers posted in December 2022

- [Subtract my odds from my evens](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131755/subtract-my-odds-from-my-evens/255095#255095) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Construct the Identity Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/construct-the-identity-matrix/255103#255103) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [CGAC2022 Day 1: Let's build a chocolate pyramid!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255042/cgac2022-day-1-lets-build-a-chocolate-pyramid/255150#255150) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Construct the Identity Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/construct-the-identity-matrix/255151#255151) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Given an int input n, print out n*reversed(n)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144816/given-an-int-input-n-print-out-nreversedn/255152#255152) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Generate the n'th Fermi-Dirac Prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253682/generate-the-nth-fermi-dirac-prime/255166#255166) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [CGAC2022 Day 5: Preparing an advent calendar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255202/cgac2022-day-5-preparing-an-advent-calendar/255214#255214) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Find the nth number where the digit sum equals the number of factors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254910/find-the-nth-number-where-the-digit-sum-equals-the-number-of-factors/255226#255226) by [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Shorten the Java Package](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119126/shorten-the-java-package/255128#255128) by [Baby_Boy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106844/baby-boy)
- [CGAC2022 Day 7: Fen The Wicked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255274/cgac2022-day-7-fen-the-wicked/255278#255278) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Smallest Zeroless Base](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146305/smallest-zeroless-base/255298#255298) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [CGAC2022 Day 8: Fen The Wicked, Part 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255305/cgac2022-day-8-fen-the-wicked-part-2/255308#255308) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [CGAC2022 Day 9: Playing with bits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255344/cgac2022-day-9-playing-with-bits/255353#255353) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [CGAC2022 Day 9: Playing with bits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255344/cgac2022-day-9-playing-with-bits/255367#255367) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [CGAC2022 Day 12: Santa's gift and the laser lock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255405/cgac2022-day-12-santas-gift-and-the-laser-lock/255474#255474) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [CGAC2022 Day 14: Chimney cleaning](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255464/cgac2022-day-14-chimney-cleaning/255479#255479) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [CGAC2022 Day 16: Playing with bits, Part 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255555/cgac2022-day-16-playing-with-bits-part-2/255565#255565) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Approximate my atomic weight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255521/approximate-my-atomic-weight/255567#255567) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Make every consonant after a vowel uppercase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255604/make-every-consonant-after-a-vowel-uppercase/255613#255613) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [CGAC2022 Day 17: Present Heap](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255591/cgac2022-day-17-present-heap/255637#255637) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Sum every second digit in a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255684/96037)
   by [mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat)
- [CGAC2022 Day 18: Light all of the candles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255638/cgac2022-day-18-light-all-of-the-candles/255641#255641) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [CGAC2022 Day 16: Playing with bits, Part 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255555/cgac2022-day-16-playing-with-bits-part-2/255735#255735) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Replace all vowels with repeated "aeiou"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255773/96037) by [mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat)
- [CGAC2022 Day 20: Reconstruct Santa's Book](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255737/cgac2022-day-20-reconstruct-santas-book/255794#255794) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Create \$n\$ sublists with the powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16...)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255804/create-n-sublists-with-the-powers-of-two-1-2-4-8-16/255819#255819) by [mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat)
- [Replace 0s In a String With Their Consecutive Counts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255822/replace-0s-in-a-string-with-their-consecutive-counts/255826#255826) by [mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat)
- [Create \$n\$ sublists with the powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16...)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255804/create-n-sublists-with-the-powers-of-two-1-2-4-8-16/255874#255874) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [8086 Segment Address to Linear](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255850/8086-segment-address/255878#255878) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Create \$n\$ sublists with the powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16...)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255804/create-n-sublists-with-the-powers-of-two-1-2-4-8-16/255929#255929) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Keep elements in sequence that have a letter repeated at least 3 times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255902/keep-elements-in-sequence-that-have-a-letter-repeated-at-least-3-times/255919#255919) by [mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat)
- [Keep elements in sequence that have a letter repeated at least 3 times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255902/keep-elements-in-sequence-that-have-a-letter-repeated-at-least-3-times/255932#255932) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [CGAC2022 Day 25: When The Planets Align](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256017/cgac2022-day-25-when-the-planets-align/256018#256018) by [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)
- [Friend, or Foe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256050/friend-or-foe/256070#256070) by [The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in December 2022

- [Manipulating operator precedence with `:`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255093/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in December 2022

- [Is it true? Ask Pip!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256166/is-it-true-ask-pip) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```