# Language of the Month for September 2020: R

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766) to restart the Language of the Month with the top-voted nomination from the old nominations list, we have a new featured language! Throughout September 2020, our Language of the Month, nominated by [JayCe](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80010), will be:

> ## [R](https://www.r-project.org/)

#### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during September, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) R, use it to solve challenges, and discuss it in the [R chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112541). Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

#### Information about R

R is a free software environment for statistical computing and graphics. It compiles and runs on a wide variety of UNIX platforms, Windows and MacOS.

- It is a general-purpose language, meaning it can be used to answer all questions on this site. Though to be honest, processing strings requires a bit of flexibility.
- Its vectorized syntax allows for concise answers in case of multiple input.
- R is a functional programming language - almost everything is a function - including things that you would think (thanks to the parser) are just operators. This can yield some very powerful golfs, as displayed [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171490/67312).
- Environments, combined with lexical scoping are a power feature of the language.
- It is really good at plotting stuff.

And most importantly: Golfing R is fun :)

#### Documentation

- The official website has [several online manuals](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html), including [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)
- [A list of resources for learning R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/free-resources-for-learning-r)
- [Entry in the showcase of languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44726/16766)
- [Golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r)

(If you consider yourself knowledgeable in R and would like to help teach it to other users, feel free to join the [R chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112541)!)

#### Interpreters

- [Download](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) for Linux, Mac OS X, or Windows
- [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#R)
- [RDRR](https://rdrr.io/snippets) (includes most of the packages available for R)

---

## `cat("Happy golfing!")`

Comment: This is very exciting, and (as one of the few [but hopefully about to become many] contributors in R) I'm very happy that R has been chosen.  Apart from continuing to post anwsers in R, is there anything else that I could do to help or encourage others?

Comment: I have in mind something like choosing a small selection of existing challenges that work well in R (so: not text-based challenges!), so that any/everyone that's interested could focus on the same set...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You can also post an R-themed challenge. In the past I've done a couple of challenges implementing some of R's more interesting built-ins (`fivenum`, `nextn`, and `match` if I recall correctly), and I have a couple more in the Sandbox at the moment (`jitter` and `ave`). I'm also toying with having people implement some statistical routines (e.g., given a dataset calculate the empirical CDF / Kaplan-Meier estimator for survival function) but I'm struggling with the I/O a little.

Comment: Also can we get a [tag:featured] on here?

Comment: @Giuseppe Makes sense to me, but I think a mod has to do that.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen and Giuseppe: Please add your own September R solutions to the list below, too! (When you get the chance.)

Comment: related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r

Comment: There is already a (now frozen) chatroom for golfing in R: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81960/golfr ; shouldn't we resuscitate it rather than open a new chatroom?

Comment: @RobinRyder Well, shoot. I tried to look for one, but "R" is impossible to search for, so I didn't find it. I could see about getting that unfrozen. There's no content to speak of in the new one yet.

Comment: @DLosc Sounds good; if you can get in unfrozen, I am sure a few of us regular R golfers can keep it active.

Comment: As a frequent tidyverse user, I'm curious if anyone has a tidyverse answer that beats a base R answer.

Comment: @qrt I never use it normally, but I'd also be interested to know if it could be golf-competitive (especially as the ```%>%``` paradigm almost makes it into a different language variant to base R).  Obviously, the usual need to include ```tidyverse::```, ```dplyr::``` or ```library(tidyverse)``` would normally be a disincentive (especially for short challenges), but it would still be interesting to see whether a 'non-competing' R+tidyverse entry that omitted these characters could ever/often beat base R.  Are you tempted to try?

Comment: `library(magrittr)` could come in useful if you need to recycle expressions - example from the forward-pipe help: `rnorm(100) %>% {c(min(.), mean(.), max(.))} %>% floor`.

Answer (score 4):

## List of all R solutions posted in September

(First time posters highlighted in bold)

- [Spiralize a Word, Triangularly!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210454/spiralize-a-word-triangularly/210483#210483) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [My smartphone's phonebook](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210262/my-smartphones-phonebook/210406#210406) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Prime Power Switch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210437/prime-power-switch/210471#210471) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Implement the Polygamma function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210425/implement-the-polygamma-function/210432#210432) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- **[Output the PPCG Prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210654/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/)**
- [Product over a range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210679/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/)
- [Binary to decimal converter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210756/16766) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/)
- **[Write a “Hello” interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210497/write-a-hello-interpreter/210529#210529) by [Cong Chen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98085/cong-chen)**
- [Minimum number of platforms required for a railway station](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210809/minimum-number-of-platforms-required-for-a-railway-station/210865#210865) by [Cong Chen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98085/cong-chen)
- [split and capitalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164629/split-and-capitalize/210918#210918) by [Cong Chen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98085/cong-chen)
- [-perfect numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211028/n-perfect-numbers/211058#211058) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Connect the Three Kingdoms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210917/connect-the-three-kingdoms/210974#210974) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Avoid walking into a rectangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210875/avoid-walking-into-a-rectangle/210878#210878) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Double Prime Words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210733/double-prime-words/210854#210854) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Approximate when you are going to die](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210725/approximate-when-you-are-going-to-die/210814#210814) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Approximate when you are going to die](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210725/approximate-when-you-are-going-to-die/210781#210781) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Divisible strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210770/divisible-strings/210788#210788) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Days and months make years](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150084/days-and-months-make-years/210616#210616) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- [Diophantine Approximation: find lowest possible denominator to approximate within given precision](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210572/diophantine-approximation-find-lowest-possible-denominator-to-approximate-withi/210579#210579) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/)
- **[Primes in the prime factorization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211334/80214) by [user8617947](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74544/user8617947)**
- **[Get thee behind me Satan-Prime!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211463/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)**
- [Print the Greek Alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211723/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [The Decryption Function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211408/67312) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Implement the polygamma function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210435/67312) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) -- this one barely counts as a golf.
- [Approximate when you are going to die](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210797/86301) by [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)
- [Double Prime Words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210808/86301) by [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)
- [How many of each pill to achieve the total daily dose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210823/86301) by [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)
- [Implement the random Fibonacci sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211166/implement-the-random-fibonacci-sequence/211179#211179) by [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)
- [I uppercase the source code, you reverse the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211226/i-uppercase-the-source-code-you-reverse-the-input/211236#211236) by [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)
- [Is that number a Two Bit Number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211858/86301) by [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
   [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of [all R tips posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A4024+created%3A2020-09-01..2020-09-30+is%3Aanswer) in September

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of R-related challenges posted in September

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

Comment: This should be Community wiki, right?

Comment: @Razetime Good idea, I'll do that.

Comment: I will be awarding a 50 rep bounty to all first-time R golfers during that period. Please ping me if you add an eligible answer to the list!