# Should we allow people to nominate their own language for Language of the Month?

Tags: discussion, meta, language-of-the-month

In a [comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/nominations-for-language-of-the-month/14754#comment53859_14737) on the Language of the Month nominations thread, Peter Taylor raised a valid point:

> It might be worth prohibiting nominations of your own language. If a language is genuinely interesting, it should be possible to find someone else who's willing to advocate it; and if you can't find anyone else to advocate it, you're going to be a bottleneck to answering questions in chat etc.

As of this writing, the comment has four upvotes, which indicates to me that several people think prohibiting self-nominations may be a good thing.

On the other hand, when I [brought up the issue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42698411#42698411), some people argued against such a ban:

> I'm totally fine with allowing self-nominations. The whole point of voting is to filter out what's actually good.

Destructible Lemon made a salient point:

> I'd like to comment that the thing was designed to help people raise awareness of their languages and stuff, not to have a language appreciation club or something

So, what do you think? To self-nominate, or not to self-nominate?

<sub>If we decide we don't want self-nominations, I propose that this rule apply only to *future* nominations. Existing nominations should be allowed to stay.</sub>

Comment: I also commented that a language appreciation club could be a good thing in its own right, but as a separate thing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes:

The intention of the language of the month was to generate interest in obscure languages made by ppcg users

> Whereas, many of us are the **inventors** of said interesting languages, and would like to teach them to others, and

from the [original proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14645/16766) (emphasis mine)

If we don't allow self nominations, it means that the (possibly high quality) languages that need help will all languish in author-only-use, which could be argued to be the very reason the language of the month was proposed, or why it was supported.

Answer (score 11):

## Also Yes:

Nothing wrong with the other answer, but I would like to propose an alternate change rather than no change.

I think self-nomination is valid and well within the spirit of the event. The goal (seems to be) to get exposure to interesting but not-well-known languages, and having a proposal written by a person who (presumably) knows the language best and has the most interest in it seems like a valid way to showcase key features. I think at least part of the problem originated from a particular answer (which seems to have been deleted, so I won't name names) which featured a language which was essentially still in development.

So, instead of considering "maybe the creator is biased and will nominate a bad language", which has a lot of fallout, simply add two requirements:

1. The language should have a stable implementation available.
2. The language should have useful documentation for said implementation.

The phrasing could probably use some more precision, but I think these rules should avoid problems of languages that change/replace/remove features, creating an unstable golfing environment, as well as having an alternate resource for answering questions than just the creator. If making these hard rules is too restrictive, I think they're at least good metrics for *evaluating* proposals (e.g. "it's hard to pick up this language from just the documentation, so I don't think it's a good option").