# Language of the Month for March 2018: Brachylog

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14645/16766) to have a Language of the Month, and since the [list of nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14737/16766) has a single highest-voted entry as February nears its end, I am pleased to announce the very first featured language! Throughout March 2018, our Language of the Month, proposed by [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize), will be:

> ## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog)

#### What's a Language of the Month?

See the meta posts linked above. In short, during March, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Brachylog, use it to solve challenges, and discuss it in the [Brachylog chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34284/brachylog). Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

#### Information about Brachylog

Copied from the nomination post:

- Brachylog is a **declarative logic language**. You will thus discover new programming principles and mechanisms, such as unification, backtracking, and constraint integer arithmetic, that you've probably never experienced in other non-declarative languages.
- Programming with a declarative language such as Brachylog requires a significantly **different mindset** compared to your typical imperative languages. This may give you a new perspective on solving programming problems in general (see [this quote by a PPCG user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41350518#41350518)).
- Brachylog is a **general purpose code golf** language. Although it's much better at some tasks than others, and not always as competitive as say Jelly, you should be able to tackle the vast majority of challenges with it, and it can sometimes be remarkably terse.

#### Documentation

- [Brachylog's wiki](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki)
- [Brachylog's chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34284/brachylog)
- [A short Youtube video presenting the basic philosophy of Brachylog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYVhZ-MFcUs)

#### Interpreter

The simplest way to run Brachylog is through [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#brachylog2)

You can also download the sources of Brachylog [here](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/tree/master/src), and run the language using [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) (this is pretty much only useful if you somehow want to use the debugger).

---

#### [`"Happy golfing!"w`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X8kjsaCgUiE9PyctMy9dUan8/38A)

Comment: Following [the example from Literature.SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/995/298) I've added a CW post where we can collect all new Brachylog-specific content people create this month (solutions, new tips, and maybe even the odd Brachylog-related challenge).

Answer (score 10):

## List of [all Brachylog solutions posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=brachylog+created%3A2018-02-28..2018-03-31+is%3Aanswer) in March

- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156864/8478) by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478)
- [ID generator with no matching contiguous pairs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156944/32014) by [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014)
- [Non-discriminating Programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156972/8478) by [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)
- [Non-discriminating Programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156976/8478) by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)
- [Non-discriminating Programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156987/71256) by [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz)
- [Collatz Conjecture (OEIS A006577)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157045/8478) by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478)
- [Bernardino identifies unaltered dollar words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157180) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766)
- [Sort by shuffling blocks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157189/8478) by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478)
- [Garble that string!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157202/32014) by [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014)
- [Number of sums of factors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157216/32014) by [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014)
- [Find relevant digit groupings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157328/8478) by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)
- [Necklace splitting problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157417/32014) by [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014)
- [Compute the Kolakoski sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157464/8478) by [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014)
- [Duck, duck, goose!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158028/41024) by [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024)
- [Transitive equality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158256/32014) by [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014)
- [The Spanish license plates game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159503/8478) by [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76359)
- [Non-discriminating Programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159506/8478) by [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76359)
- [What is my exponential potential?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159529/8478) by [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76359)
- [Blue duck, red duck, gray duck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159574/41024) by [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of [all Brachylog tips posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A108296+created%3A2018-02-28..2018-03-31+is%3Aanswer) in March

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Brachylog-related challenges posted in March

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID> by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```