# Language of the Month for April 2018: Brain-Flak

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14645/16766) to have a Language of the Month, and since the [list of nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14737/16766) has a single highest-voted entry as March nears its end, I am pleased to announce the next featured language! Throughout April 2018, our Language of the Month, nominated by [Destructible Lemon](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55896/destructible-lemon), will be:

> ## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)

#### What's a Language of the Month?

See the meta posts linked above. In short, during April, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Brain-Flak, use it to solve challenges, and discuss it in the Brain-Flak chat room, [The Third Stack](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41599/the-third-stack). Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

#### Information about Brain-Flak

Brain-Flak is a minimalist stack-based turing tarpit. It uses only the brace characters `()[]{}<>`, which must be balanced. Data consists of integers stored on a pair of stacks. However, despite its humble feature set, there is a surprising depth and elegance to the language.

- Brain-Flak is entirely composed of *atoms*, which can either be niladic (taking 0 arguments) or monadic (taking exactly one argument). A nilad is a pair of brackets with nothing between them, i.e. one of `"()", "{}", "[]",` or `"<>"`. A monad is a pair of brackets with any number of other atoms between them.

  Due to the nature of using only brackets for code, these atoms are highly nestable. One of the most fun pieces of using brain-flak is learning how to use these atoms efficiently for both their functionality and returned value.
- Even though it was designed as a turing tarpit with only 8 commands, there are certain tasks that can done very tersely in brain-flak. Most notably, operations with polygonal numbers and summations.

#### Documentation

The readme on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) contains a good summary of the language. Further help can be found at:

- [Brain-Flak wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/wiki)
- [Esolangs.org page](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brain-Flak)
- [Tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95403/tips-for-golfing-in-brain-flak)
- [The Third Stack chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41599/the-third-stack)

  For help, you can ping [@DJMcMayhem](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/144962) or [@user56656](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/218449/user56656).

  (If you consider yourself knowledgeable in brain-flak and would like to help teach it to other users, feel free to add your name to the list)

#### Interpreter

The simplest way to run Brain-Flak is through Try It Online! There are two interpreters available on TIO: the [original Ruby interpreter](https://tio.run/#brain-flak) and an implementation in [Haskell](https://tio.run/#brainhack).

You can also download implementations in [Ruby](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), [C](https://github.com/Flakheads/CraneFlak), [Haskell](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), and [Prolog](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainFlog).

---

#### [`(([((((()()())()())({}){}))]((((([]([][]([[]]([[]()()]([][]()([]()({}{}{})({})({})))))))[[]()])<([][][][])>[][])()[[]])))[[][]]())`](https://tio.run/##LYwxDoAwDAO/Ew/9AULiHVWGMiAhEEPXqm8PtdvYuSFxctZyf@l6yxNhlo0FaqF1DMO1yD5MZBcYWSOY0DqlM/YsJR2bkhR20bjxGeBHICLS8QM)

<sup>Thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king), [user56656](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56656/user56656), and [Nitrodon](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69059/nitrodon) for golfing help :D</sup>

Comment: I would like to point out that Brain-Flak will also turn 2 years old this April!  Last year we threw it a bit of a party with some themed challenges, and we are planning on doing it again.  Convenient that Brain-Flak is also the language of the month!

Comment: This feels like a joke :P

Comment: [142 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYxBDoAwCAS/wx76CN/RcKgHE6Px4NX4dtwFUyBkSmHWe@xX285xRJgCNgOVeN4qIouQ2F0pUDe4gM1zLQ/zxyFT17Kb1YjyrgdnUk8n/iuJIqItHw "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing [140 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsAwCAS/4x7yiL5DPCSHQmnpodeQt1tXaTXIOpEZTz/utl/9dJcosJHhq7mCzFWPn@CaUY3NwCkwhhhExQxUKc9MpFA4lUswSn9bqusU7t62Fw "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Comment: @Christopher I was very, *very* close to posting "Language of the Month: Malbolge" as an April Fools' joke. But DJ was so excited about Brain-Flak being featured, I decided that would be kinda mean of me.

Comment: [You know I can't resist.](https://tio.run/##LYwxDoAwDAO/Ew/9AULiHVWGMiAhEEPXqm8PtdvYuSFxctZyf@l6yxNhlo0FaqF1DMO1yD5MZBcYWSOY0DqlM/YsJR2bkhR20bjxGeBHICLS8QM "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Comment: @DLosc hahaha that is great

Answer (score 11):

## List of [all Brain-Flak solutions posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%23+brain-flak%22+created%3A2018-03-31..2018-04-30+is%3Aanswer) in April

- [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161530/76162) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162)
- [Arbitrary-length currying](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162326/48198) by [BMO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bmo?tab=profile)
- [Color count, sorted by occurences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161437) by [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434)
- [Expand Compressed Brain-Flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161446/48198) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king?tab=profile)
- [Expand Compressed Brain-Flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161083) by [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434)
- [Generate Men of Culture](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162530) by [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434)
- [How many arguments were passed?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161775/48198) by [BMO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bmo?tab=profile)
- [Magic the Gathering: Friends or Foes?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161473/48198) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king?tab=profile)
- [Magic the Gathering: Friends or Foes?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161512/48198) by [Nitrodon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69059/nitrodon?tab=profile)
- [Make an Emergency Corridor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161333/76162) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162)
- [Print the Previous Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161760/31716) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162)
- [Same length, different string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161258/48198) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king?tab=profile)
- [Up go the bits!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161679/48198) by [MegaTom](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31203/megatom?tab=profile)
- [Output some reserved word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162404/31716) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162404/31716)
- [Output some reserved word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162485/31716) by [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem)
- [Scrabble scorer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162632/31716) by [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem)
- [Seidel Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162646/69059) by [Nitrodon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69059)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of [all Brain-Flak tips posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A95403+created%3A2018-03-31..2018-04-30+is%3Aanswer) in April

- [Check your negatives](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161469/48198) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king?tab=profile)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Brain-Flak-related challenges posted in April

- [Expand Compressed Brain-Flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161056/31716) by [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```