# Language of the Month for May 2018: MATL

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14645/16766) to have a Language of the Month, and since the [list of nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14737/16766) had a single highest-voted entry at the beginning of May, we have a new featured language! Throughout May 2018, our Language of the Month, nominated by [DJMcMayhem](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43131877#43131877) and [Sanchises](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43141097#43141097), will be:

> ## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL)

#### What's a Language of the Month?

See the meta posts linked above. In short, during May, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) MATL, use it to solve challenges, and discuss it in the MATL chat room, [MATL CHATL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39466/matl-chatl). Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

#### Information about MATL

MATL is a **stack-oriented** language based on MATLAB/Octave and suitable for code golf. Many functions are similar to those of MATLAB, sometimes with extended funcionality.

To simplify stack handling there are **clipboards**, similar to variables in other languages. An interesting feature is an automatic clipboard that holds the inputs of recent function calls. This often avoids the need to manually copy.

There are different types of functions. Most are **normal functions**, which perform operations on inputs and produce outputs. Other types are stack-handling functions, for duplicating, deleting or moving elements in the stack; and clipboard functions, for copying and pasting elements from the clipboards.

#### Documentation

- [Esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL).
- [Entry in the showcase of languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-of-languages/76535#76535).
- [Language specification](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/blob/master/spec/MATL_spec.pdf).
- [Golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78152/tips-for-golfing-in-matl).

For help, you can ping [@LuisMendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) or visit the [MATL CHATL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39466/matl-chatl).

(If you consider yourself knowledgeable in MATL and would like to help teach it to other users, feel free to add your name to the list)

#### Interpreters

There are two online interpreters:

- [**Try It Online!**](https://tio.run/#matl)
- [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.suever.net/) (featuring [real-time](https://matl.suever.net/?code=2%24rEk%60t%27%23.%27w%29XxDt3Y6Z%2ByyHIhm%2abbI%3D%3C%2BT&inputs=25%0A125&version=19.2.0), [graphical](https://matl.suever.net/?code=Q%3AqG%2Fq1e3YytP%2B1e6j%2aZeYsXG&inputs=700&version=19.6.0) and [sound](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%25+Create+values+of+t+from+0+-+1+seconds+at+44100+Hz%0A0+l+44100+%2F+1+3%24%3A+2YP+%2a+%2a+XJx%0A%0A%27C-Major%3A%27D%0AJ+261.626+%2a+X%2C+J+329.628+%2a+X%2C+%2B+J+391.995+%2a+X%2C+%2B+TY%23%0A%0A%27F-Major%3A%27D%0AJ+261.626+%2a+X%2C+J+349.228+%2a+X%2C+%2B+J+440.000+%2a+X%2C+%2B+TY%23%0A%0A%27G-Major%3A%27D%0AJ+246.942+%2a+X%2C+J+293.665+%2a+X%2C+%2B+J+391.995+%2a+X%2C+%2B+TY%23&inputs=&version=20.6.0) output)

You can also download the interpreter from [Github](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) and run it on MATLAB or on Octave.

Answer (score 12):

## List of [all MATL solutions posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%23+MATL%22+created%3A2018-04-30..2018-05-31+is%3Aanswer) in May

- [Detect rectangular text with rectangular code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164076/36398) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- [Weighted average - the pressup trend problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164112/31716) by [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem)
- [Bringing a pair of integers to equality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164122/36398)  by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- [The Add-Multiply-Add Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164161/59487) by [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)
- [Find arsonist's lullaby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164491/36398) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- [Sign-Swapping Sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164535/36398) by [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)
- [Circular Limited Sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164536/56433) by [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)
- [Modular broadcasting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164594/67312) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Collatz Conjecture (OEIS A006577)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164663/31516) by [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)
- [Orthodiagonal steps](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164856/36398) by [Sanchises](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32352/sanchises)
- [Orthodiagonal steps](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164872/59487) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)
- [Find the Fibonacci Patterns](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164882/36398) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- [Progression of Matrix Columns](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164925/67312) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Up and down, up and down](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164997/36398) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)
- [Is this a consecutive-prime/constant-exponent number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165006/59487) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)
- [Is this a consecutive-prime/constant-exponent number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165136/36398) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- [Merge two values](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165344/36398) by [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)
- [Determining Yes or No?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165347/36398) by [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)
- [Beginners 10x10 multiplication matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165513/36398) by [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)
- [Produce a List of Rotonyms 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165625/36398) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of [all MATL tips posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A78152+created%3A2018-04-30..2018-05-31+is%3Aanswer) in May

- [Efficiently defining numeric array literals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165257/36398)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of MATL-related challenges posted in May

- [Modular broadcasting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164056/modular-broadcasting) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- [Function clipboard: copy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/164712) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- [Function clipboard: paste](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165144/function-clipboard-paste) by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```