# Language of the Month for July 2018: Japt

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14645/16766) to have a Language of the Month, and since the [list of nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14737/16766) had a single highest-voted entry at the beginning of July, we have a new featured language! Throughout July 2018, our Language of the Month, nominated by myself, will be:

> ## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt)

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the meta posts linked above. In short, during July, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Japt, use it to solve challenges, and discuss it in the [Japt chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt). Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### [Information about Japt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/japt/info)

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**, created by [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) in early November 2015.

Japt is heavily based off of JavaScript; after transpiling Japt's syntax features to JavaScript, it is evaluated as vanilla JS. This allows easy building of an online interpreter. Some of the main features are:

- **One-letter functions:** each lowercase letter corresponds to a specific function, which is different on strings, arrays, and numbers.
- **String compression:** Japt uses the [shoco library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) for string compression. Wrapping a string in backticks tells the interpreter to automatically decompress it.
- **Anonymous functions:** `XY{X+Y}` is transpiled to `function(X,Y){return X+Y}`, as is `@X+Y}`, and in some cases, simply `+`. This allows for easy creation of functions on the fly.
- **Unicode shortcuts:** All 1-byte characters from `¡` to `Ì` transpile to longer sequences of chars.

### Documentation

Documentation is available in the sidebar of the [Japt interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/) and the [Japt v2.0a0 interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0)

### Other Links

- [Golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121253/58974)
- [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt)
- [Entry in the showcase of languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65191/58974)
- [Japt on TIO](https://tio.run/#japt)

For help, you can also visit the [Japt chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt). If no one's there, ping @ETHProductions, @Oliver or myself and we will get back to you.

(If you consider yourself knowledgeable in Japt and would like to help teach it to other users, feel free to add your name to that list!)

### Additional Efforts

In order to help promote Japt through the month and get more people to start using it, we - that being primarily ETH, Oliver & myself, but you may also see Bubbler and Nit contributing to - will be attempting to curtail/delay the posting of our own solutions

We will also be offering some bounties to those participating. For starters, ETHProductions will be awarding 50 rep to every member posting their first Japt solution during July and I will be setting up some open-ended bounties, the first of which is listed below.

#### Bounties

Unless otherwise noted, the following bounties are all for 100 rep each and will expire at the end of July. If you have any suggestions for additional bounties, please leave a comment.

- Best [Japt tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121253/58974) posted by someone who had not posted a tip prior to the 1st of July.
- All new contributors who add a number to [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124389/58974).
- Anyone who can manage to add Japt to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/167621/58974). (200 rep)
- <s>First person to beat 24 bytes on [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/167405/58974)</s> - Claimed by [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168105/58974)
- First person to score *below* 20 bytes on [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/167405/58974) (200 rep, including the 100 rep above - will be awarded to Kamil if unclaimed at the end of the month)

Answer (score 5):

## List of [all Japt solutions posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Japt%22+created%3A2018-06-31..2018-07-31+is%3Aanswer) in July

(First time posters highlighted in bold)

- [Implement Malbolge's “crazy” operator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167774/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Concatenating n with n + 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167840/58974) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410)
- **[Pleasanortmanteaus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167842/58974) by [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434)**
- **[First Last Last First](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167901/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)**
- [2D Array Middle Point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167906/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [2D Array Middle Point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167911/58974) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487)
- [Concatenating n with n + 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167920/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Find unique elements based on a given key](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167922/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [In for a bumpy ride](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167936/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Draw a descendant pyramid (addition)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167990/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- **[Shortest code in your language to persist a string across a reboot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168036/58974) by [LegionMammal978](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/33208)**
- [Find unique elements based on a given key](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168037/58974) by [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434)
- [Addition-Subtraction of Numbers Within String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168082/58974) by [LegionMammal978](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/33208)
- [Count sum of all digits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168087/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Alpha-Numerical Bowtie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168105/58974) by [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434)
- [Give me the Gray Code list of bit width n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168214/58974) by [Nit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16484)
- [Find the Smoothest Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168215/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Randomizing until 0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168255/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Last digit large number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168271/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Give me the Gray Code list of bit width n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168370/58974) by [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613)
- [Last digit large number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168374/58974) by [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613)
- [Make me a s'more!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168400/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Construct ASCII arches](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168401/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Draw a bowling formation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168481/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Count Consecutive Characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168482/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Scoring Briscola](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168498/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Perfect Squares below n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168523/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Scoring Briscola](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168527/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Take a stand against long lines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168567/58974) by [Nit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16484)
- [Search text for a prefix and list all its suffixes in the text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168655/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Is the matrix centrosymmetric… and so is the code?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168689/58974) by [Nit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16484)
- [Search text for a prefix and list all its suffixes in the text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168692/58974) by [Nit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16484)
- [Sort odd numbers first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168788/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Is the matrix centrosymmetric… and so is the code?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168860/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Generate ordered combinations with repetition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168891/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- **[Count the lucky tickets within the given range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168943/58974) by [Amphibological](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81420)**
- [Can I restack the buckets?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168967/58974) by [Nit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16484)
- [Get the century of a year](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169073/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Trim the array!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169084/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Sort of numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169133/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Is this a straight flush?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169390/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- **[Increment base-36 strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169452/58974) by [crashoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81225/crashoz)**
- [Implementing a stack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169457/58974) by [Amphibological](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81420)
- [The group of sequential positive numbers with the highest sum?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169636/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [determine longest group of consecutive numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169646/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Jolly Jumper Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169648/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Different Way Forward](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169655/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- [Display percent battery remaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169661/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Print a string with vertical words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169662/58974) by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974)
- [Code Golf: simple way to get min & max](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169672/58974) by [Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78039)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of [all Japt tips posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A121253+created%3A2018-06-31..2018-07-31+is%3Aanswer) in July

- [Know the flags](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167704/58974) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/)
- [Use multiple lines when necessary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167829/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Japt-related challenges posted in July

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

Comment: Hah, I came here to highlight the first-timers, only to find that you've already done it ;-)

Comment: Just a question, are we supposed to add our own answers to this, or will you do that for us?

Comment: @Amphibological, you can update it yourselves but I update it anyway once every day or two.

Comment: @Shaggy, ok, then, I'll leave it to you. :)