# List of bounties with no deadline

Tags: discussion, bounty

*This is a list of unofficial, deadline-less (hence not searchable) bounties offered by users on various challenges on the main site.*

**Disclaimer**: There is no guarantee that the user will award the bounty for you in case you fulfill its requirement. Especially if the user isn't an active member anymore. The only guarantee is their written word.

---

## Guidelines for updating

- To add a bounty, create an answer.
- Answers can be sorted to see which bounties are newest.
- Answers can be commented on, allowing someone to notify the bounty's creator that the bounty may have been earned.
- If a bounty is awarded, delete the answer.

## [Browse your current bounties](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A5243+user%3Ame)

Comment: How do you have a bounty without a deadline?

Comment: @BetaDecay They're unofficial bounties - if and when the feat is accomplished, a bounty will be created and the rep will be awarded.

Comment: There's a TNB feed for these bounties now. In order to pick your bounty up, you have to *add* an *answer* to this question. Question edits and answer edits won't be picked up by the feed.

Comment: Would it help to have a stack snippet in the question that just lists the first line of each answer as a link, rather than keep editing?

Comment: Since the problem of stuff being posted in the question wasn't fixing itself, I've taken extreme action. If people want to sort bounties by amount offered, there are plenty of stack snippets which produce a table based on the answers: one of those can be adapted. Similarly, checking whether users are "active" or "passive" can be done with the SE API.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It should be noted that not all the bounties in the question had corresponding answers, so you may have removed some completely.

Comment: @mbomb007, I checked the first dozen manually and then I counted and reasoned that since there were considerably more answers than lines in the question I was wasting my time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor As an example, randomra had some bounties, but [this search](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A5243+user%3A7311) shows he has no current answers. Maybe you could write a script? Or ping everyone who had a bounty in the question, and they can deal with their own bounties.

Comment: I wish a bounty on Windows Batch/VBScript answers

Comment: # 100 rep for first valid answer to [Clone GNU `cat` 8.32](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267392/clone-gnu-cat-8-32)

Answer (score 33):

## 50+ rep whenever you outgolf xnor

I've reached 100K and it's time to gift it back! I offer +50 rep to any new answer that outgolfs one of mine.

> **[Answers to outgolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a20260%20created%3a2016..%20%5bcode-golf%5d%20is%3aanswer%20-%5btips%5d%20wiki%3ano)**

Rules

- Submit an answer that's **shorter than mine** and **in the same language** to a code golf challenge.
- It's fair game to **shave bytes off my code** after you look at it. Post an answer with your improvement.
- Any code golf answer of mine is eligible if it's **at least one hour old** and from **2016 or later**.
- **Only your new answers count**, that is, those posted after this bounty.

I'm trying convey my intent with these rules, but it's up to my judgment what qualifies or not. Feel free to ask if unsure. Some further details:

- Even saving 1 byte counts. I may award a larger bounty for bigger golfs, or those that are particularly interesting or well-explained.
- "Cheap" golfs don't count. This means those mainly due to a different language version, looser I/O, or a changed or clarified spec. Remember that liberal I/O defaults weren't always a thing. Where I say I'm purposely avoiding some method or library, your answer needs to do so too.
- Non-code-golf challenges don't qualify.
- If you further golf someone else's answer that already outgolfed me, I'll decide case-by-case whether to award another bounty.
- Where I have answers in different languages to a question, these count separately.

---

Please edit in bounty claims here.

**Bounty claims**

- [isaacg's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196776/20080) to the challenge [Length-terminated sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194230/20080). Outgolfs xnor's Python solution, 62 bytes to 67 bytes.
- To [wilkben](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88089/wilkben) for [their Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199770/20260) on "[Egg, sausage, bacon and spam (lovely spam!)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199638/20260)", outgolfing [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199678/20260) by one byte to 31 bytes from 32.
- To [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)'s [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199857/20260) on "[Egg, sausage, bacon and spam (lovely spam!)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199638/20260)", further outgolfing [xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199678/20260) down to 28 bytes.
- To [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)'s [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199784/20260) on ["Repeat every other character in string starting with second character"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/198717/20260), outgolfing [xnor's 38-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198724/20260) to 36 bytes.
- To [Arnauld's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200429/20260) on "[How many petals around the rose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200386/how-many-petals-around-the-rose/200429#200429)" for outgolfing [xnor's 31-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200407/20260) by a byte.
- To [Bubbler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201493/20260) on [Random spanning tree of a rectangular grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197573/random-spanning-tree-of-a-rectangular-grid/201493#201493) for saving 2 bytes over [xnor's 136-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197624/20260) in Python
- To [Kevin Cruijssen's 33-bytes Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203149/52210) on [*Be the First 1 (leave only the first Truthy)*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119472/be-the-first-1-leave-only-the-first-truthy) for saving 2 bytes on [*@xnor*'s 35 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119503/52210).
- To [dingledooper's 53-byte Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203289/20260) on [Code Golf Christmas Edition: How to print out a Christmas tree of height N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/code-golf-christmas-edition-how-to-print-out-a-christmas-tree-of-height-n/203289#203289), saving 3 bytes over [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177755/202600).
- To [Surculose Sputum's 68-byte Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203855/20260) on [Perimeter of Conway Hexagon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203853/20260) for outgolfing [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203857/20260) 68 bytes to 76.
- To [Surculose Sputum's 93-byte Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205391/20260) on [Remove loops from a walk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205214/remove-loops-from-a-walk) for outgolfing [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205285/20260) by 5 bytes.
- To [dingledooper's 66-byte Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205420/20260) on [Judge a book by its cover](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205317/20260) for saving 2 bytes from [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205369/20260).
- To David's [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205606/20260) on [Determine the Sharpness of a Word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205533/20260) for saving one byte off [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205536/20260).
- To Sisyphus for [saving a byte off xnor's 46-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/20260) in Python 3 on [List of primes under a million](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5977/20260).
- To Arnauld for a [Python 2 solution using a new method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213947/20260) on [The Knight's Dialer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/213805/20260), saving 10 bytes from [xnor's 83](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213840/20260).
- To ovs for a [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217610/20260) on [Landau logarithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/217536/20260) saving 3 bytes off [xnor's 72-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217536/landau-logarithm/217578#217578), and to Wheat Wizard for [saving an additional 2 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248483/20260).
- To [Sisyphus's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217731/20260) on [Compute the Kolakoski sequence](http://Compute%20the%20Kolakoski%20sequence) for being 5 bytes shorter than [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157460/20260), and to [j4at's brute-forced answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259374/20260) for saving a further 3 bytes.
- To [dingledooper's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220367/20260) on [Semidivisibility](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/220281/20260) for cutting a byte of [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/20260) 24 bytes.
- To [kops' Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223427/20260) on [Negative Space Graphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107933/20260) for saving 2 bytes over [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107949/20260).
- To [dingledooper's 37-byte Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223612/20260) on [Output a Latin Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223590/output-a-latin-square) for outgolfing [xnor's 40 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223604/20260).
- To [att's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223902/20260) on [Is it better to walk or run in the rain?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223778/20260) for saving 2 bytes off [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223784/20260).
- To [ovs's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224533/20260) on [Plz Halp, Need Investors ASAP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224515/20260) for saving 1 byte over [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224524/20260).
- To [dingledooper's 47-byte Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235899/20260) on [Draw a hollow square of # with given width](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98866/20260) for being 3 bytes shorter than [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98919/20260).
- To [Wheat Wizard's 50-byte Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248031/) on [Eh, codegolf shmodegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247751/) for being 2 bytes shorter than [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247788/).
- To [Wheat Wizard's 48-byte Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249130/) on [Find the capacity of 2D printed objects](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69298/) for being 6 bytes shorter than [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69302/).
- To [Wheat Wizard's 46-byte Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249144/) on [Print the N-bonacci sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70476/) for being 1 byte shorter than [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70522/).
- To [loopy walt's 42-byte Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260349/20260) on [Is it a plausible chess move?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/260302/20260) for outgolfing [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260316/20260) by 7 bytes.
- To [Albert.Lang's 73-byte Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262076/20260) on [Vertices of a regular dodecahedron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/262032/20260) being 9 bytes shorter than [xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262078/20260).
- To [dingledooper's 124-byte Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262458/20260) on [Draw the initial positions of Mölkky pins in ASCII art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/262428/20260) for outgolfing [xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262457/20260) by 13 bytes.
- To [Albert.Lang's 55-byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266589/20260) and [Phan Trọng Nhân's 51-byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266576/20260) Python answers on [aaabbabbc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/266561/20260) for outgolfing [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266581/20260) by many bytes.

Comment: Idea: give rep in proportion to how much was golfed off. Scale so 1 byte off is 50 rep and all-but-one byte is 500 rep.

Comment: @Adám I had considered doing some sort of minimum byte save or scaling, but decided to just offer 50 rep for any golf and make it a judgment call what to give more for.

Comment: Does [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225684) count? It's shorter than many of your solutions (just not the shortest), and I think it's an interesting golfing trick

Comment: @pxeger Gonna say no for that one, since my shortest solution was 42 bytes. Nice trick though!

Comment: I scraped another two bytes off of ovs' solution to the Landau Logarithm.  I'm not sure what criteria you want to use for judging these cases, but [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248483/) it is.

Comment: @WheatWizard I'll count it, especially since the trick applies to my original answer as well,

Comment: Sorry for dumb question but, how to receive the bounty? I couldn't find it anywhere. TYSM.

Comment: @PhanTrọngNhân You'll get the rep in 4 days once the bounty period completes. For now, the bounty being up will probably keep attracting upvotes. Congratulations!

Answer (score 25):

## Fitting but Unsuitable Languages(no longer active)

There are some challenges for which we all want to see answers in a certain language, even if the solution is very difficult. I'll award 500 points for an answer in such a language to any.

#### <s>[Help! My Calculator Broke!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61751/help-my-calculator-broke-turn-integer-expression-into-calculator-keystrokes) in TI-BASIC, with all three bonuses</s> ([Claimed by Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180042/39328))

#### <s>[Gravity Simulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64359/39328) in Marbelous</s> ([Claimed by user197974](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223001/80214))

*Since it has been more than a year since lirtosaist has logged onto this site, Razetime has given the bounty for this on their behalf.*

Current shortest solution: [157 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68586/39328) in JavaScript ES6 using regex.

I don't know if this is even *possible* in Marbelous, a Turing-incomplete language, so I'd be very happy to see a solution.

#### <strike>[Hexagonal Maze Time!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65459/hexagonal-maze-time) in Hexagony</strike> (claimed by boboquack)

#### <strike>[Minify Brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16732/39328) in Brainfuck</strike> (Claimed by [Mitch Schwartz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97819/39328))

I'm willing to give thousands more rep away in bounties of this type, so comment below to suggest challenges!

Comment: Afaik, Sparr has some plans to make Marbelous TC. Is the third bounty still up if he does?

Comment: I'll need to know the details of the new features first, but probably.

Comment: I’m guessing the TI-BASIC program can’t just print out the answer? :P Also, is OS version 5.2 (84+CE only) allowed? There are some new string commands that would be helpful.

Comment: I noticed also that you were offering a bounty [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67289/convolve-integers-in-subquadratic-time/83259#comment166256_67289). I'm not sure if you are still offering it as a bounty, but if so, adding it here might help it get noticed.

Comment: someone did the [brainfuck one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97819/55896)

Comment: What about trying [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92404/60919) in Cubix? Probably impossible

Comment: Oh, never knew there was a [Help! My calculator broke!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61751/help-my-calculator-broke-turn-integer-expression-into-calculator-keystrokes) challenge. At first I thought this was my [Help! My calculator malfunctions!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/help-my-calculator-malfunctions) challenge that was linked..

Comment: Maybe [this] answer is interesting. Brainf*ck to Unary-digits answered in Brainf*ck and Unary-digits. [this]: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52712/brainfk-to-unary-and-back/185968#185968

Comment: I suggest [Mowing the grass](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204434/78123) in Grass

Comment: I suggest [Error 404: Character Not Found](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103097/error-404-character-not-found) in Intel 4004 machine code.

Comment: I have an [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218330/92901) to [Output Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218284/92901) in Buffalo. (Not sure this fits what you're looking for - it was pretty easy.)

Comment: Hi I would like to claim the final bounty: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223001/96393

Comment: Would this [><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233274) to [Obfuscate my ><>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233238/obfuscate-my) count?

Comment: It seems like the bounty-poster hasn't been active in around a year. Could someone with sufficient rep edit the post with a disclaimer? ( or perhaps someone with sufficient rep could adopt the bounty ;) )

Answer (score 23):

## 1000 – 2000 rep for figuring out how to program with both halves of a [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats) program

This bounty needs a bit of background, so bear with me.

Stack Cats is an esolang with fairly strong constraints on its program structure. Specifically, each valid program has to have mirror symmetry, and the commands are designed such that mirroring a character results in the inverse operation. That means that the second half of the program (disregarding the character in the centre) exactly undoes what the first half did. So in a way it's on that central character to change the program state in a meaningful way, such that the undoing part actually results in the program behaviour you want.

Of course, there's only a handful of possible commands that can even be used for that single central character. For the mathematically inclined, this means that programming in Stack Cats is all about finding a [conjugate relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) that transforms one of 12 built-ins into the program you want to write. Nevertheless, I believe that Stack Cats [is in fact Turing-complete](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Stack_Cats#Computational_Class).

While I've written non-trivial programs in Stack Cats (for example [this primality test](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83730/8478)), they all rely on a certain construction that essentially works around these limitations, by skipping the entire first half of the program. This lets us put arbitrary "unbalanced" code in the second half, so we don't really have to worry about the conjugation. The basic construction looks like this:

```
<(...)*(...)>
```

The `()` are conditionals, which are always false in the first half and always true in the second half, so the first `...` is skipped and the second `...` is executed. The problem is that this is clearly inefficient for golfing: we could be doing useful stuff with both halves of the program, but we're just throwing one half away to be able to make sense of the program in the first place.

For very trivial problems, Sp3000 and I have found some programs that don't use this construction, but even those were *usually* found by an automated search. [Here is an example of that for adding two numbers.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85048/8478) In particular, our brute force approaches are usually nowhere near fast enough to find solutions that actually require control flow/loops. As far as I know, the only program that was ever written which uses both halves and contains a loop is [this program by feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89484/8478) (and given that the task was to implement an arbitrary OEIS sequence, it's likely that they just tried some programs with loops until one of them produced a reasonable OEIS sequence).

**So,** Sp3000 and I will together award 1000 rep to a Stack Cats answer, which:

- Contains non-trivial control flow, i.e. `(...)` and/or `{...}` which don't always do the same regardless of program input (in particular, if there's a `(...)` it should be executed for some inputs and skipped for others, to make sure that it isn't used to skip unused parts of the code unconditionally).
- Contains an explanation for how one can find such an answer without resorting to automated search (of course, you're perfectly welcome to make use of automated searches to get a better understanding of the structure of Stack Cats programs).
- Can't be easily outgolfed by an answer which uses the `<(...)*(...)>` template or which uses no control flow operations at all (to ensure that the program isn't just a linear solution like the addition program, padded with some loops which don't end up doing anything; and also to ensure that this technique actually *makes use* of both halves in an efficient way).

To be clear, the explanation is the most important part: this bounty isn't for finding such a solution by serendipity but for understanding how to construct such a solution.

Don't try to find loopholes in these rules — we're in no obligation to actually hand out the bounty, so if we feel like your answer is clearly not in the spirit of this bounty, we won't award it. I'm pretty sure that any answer which actually deserves the bounty, will do so quite obviously. Also, if you can solve several challenges (which are sufficiently different) with your technique — which would be a great proof that it's actually a general technique and not just a way to solve one particular task — we will award another 1000 rep to a second answer.

Comment: "*we could be doing useful stuff with both halves of the program*", how so?

Comment: If it's always false, what's the use?

Answer (score 21):

***Disclaimer:** This bounty was posted by a person whose job is to promote APL.*

## 50 – 500 rep for an APL answer

I will reward 50 rep if all of the following conditions are met:

1. The answer is in [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/) Classic/Unicode/[Extended](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended)/[Prime](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-prime), [APL2](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/apl2/details), [APL+](http://apl2000.com/), [APLSE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gemesys.android.aplse), [GNU/APL](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/), [Sharp APL](http://www.sigapl.org/Archives/waterloo_archive/apl/sharp.apl/index.html), [sAPL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gemesys.android.sapl), [SAX](https://github.com/tobia/luit-sax), [NARS](http://www.nars2000.org/), [APLX](https://www.dyalog.com/aplx.htm), [A+](http://www.aplusdev.org/index.html), [dzaima/APL](https://github.com/dzaima/apl), [ngn/APL](https://gitlab.com/n9n/apl), [APL\iv](https://github.com/ktye/iv), [Watcom APL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gemesys.android.watapl), or [APL\360](http://wotho.ethz.ch/mvt4apl-2.00/). Feel free to suggest additional languages along this theme.
2. The challenge had no previous answer in any of the above languages.
3. The challenge was posted no later than on 31 Dec 2021.
4. The answer was posted after this bounty was set (Feb. 6 2019).
5. Awarding the bounty will not cause my rep to be under 10000.

**Hint:** Bubbler's (amended) [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1668391/questions-eligible-for-apl-bounty-by-adam) for eligible questions (has arbitrary filters and ordering — fork and edit if you want!)

The amount will be doubled once for each of the following conditions that are met (or 500 whichever is less):

6. The answer is well explained (as judged by me)
7. It is the poster's first APL answer, but the poster is not a "︎ New contributor".
8. The answer wins the challenge when posted.
9. The answer is the first answer to the challenge.

---

### Bounty list

Awarded bounties are <del>struck-through</del>.

Bounties in progress are **bold**.

Bounties on hold are *italic*.

If you have previously requested a bounty, add can add more requests after the struck-through ones, otherwise add add yourself to the below list to request a bounty.

The format is:

`- [username](url-to-profile): [rep](url-to-answer-post), [rep](url-to-answer-post)`

- [lirtosiast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39328/lirtosiast): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179605/39328), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179606/39328), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179603/39328),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179676/39328), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179673/39328), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179656/39328),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179755/39328), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179736/39328), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179720/39328),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179684/43319),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179686/43319)</s>
- [voidhawk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85183/voidhawk): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179587/43319), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180747/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179287/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179947/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180749/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181229/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181270/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181281/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181275/43319)</s>
- [TRITICIMAGVS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/triticimagvs): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179816/43319)</s>
- [Ven](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8328/ven): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180994/43319),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181532/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181792/43319),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181309/8328), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184668/8328)</s>
- ​[Sherlock9](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47581/sherlock9): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183058/47581),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180572/47581), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180621/47581),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180810/47581),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191345/47581), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191498/47581), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194446/47581), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194380/47581)</s>
- [J. Sallé](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74163/j-sall%c3%a9): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188622/74163),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191169/74163)</s>
- [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196175/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196373/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196433/78410),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196651/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196782/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197156/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197236/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197495/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197623/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198057/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198092/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198590/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199440/78410),
  [400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199608/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199992/78410), [400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200068/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200173/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200177/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200766/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203183/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203188/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203223/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203463/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204383/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204421/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204640/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205036/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205038/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205094/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205224/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205226/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205227/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205242/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205245/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205279/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205974/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206117/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206251/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206407/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206483/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206572/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206591/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206616/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206650/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206815/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207079/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207149/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207370/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207374/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207380/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207421/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209137/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209208/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210910/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211086/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211204/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211568/78410), [400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212043/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217579/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217580/78410), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231462/78410)</s>
- [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199379/571), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210619/571)</s>
- [mabel](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91097/mabel): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198900/91097)</s>
- [RGS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75323/rgs): <s>[400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199402/75323), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201756/75323), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204193/75323), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204209/75323), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204211/75323),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211219/75323),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213924/75323)</s>
- [JPeroutek](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41195/jperoutek): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140357/modular-multiplicative-inverse/199633#199633)</s>
- [Jeff Zeitlin](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/79081/jeff-zeitlin): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70847/this-challenge-makes-cents/200468#200468), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137572/approximate-the-dottie-number/200801#200801)</s>
- [petStorm](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92069/petstorm): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127750/take-that-frown-and-turn-it-around/204133#204133)</s>
- [Jarmex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26977/jarmex): <s>[400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204346/26977), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204411/26977),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204712/26977),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205000/26977),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205652/26977),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205192/26977)</s>
- [fireflame241](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206773/68261), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206998/68261), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207042/68261), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207340/68261),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207344/68261),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207377/68261),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207457/68261),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207598/68261)</s>
- [Silvio Mayolo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9486/silvio-mayolo): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207451/9486)</s>
- [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209779/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209973/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209974/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210038/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210199/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210258/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210264/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210389/80214), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210417/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210421/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210463/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210521/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210563/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210584/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210586/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210604/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210635/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210755/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210963/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210967/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210972/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211014/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211011/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211010/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211061/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211131/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211228/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211223/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211310/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211264/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211263/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211259/80214), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211313/80214), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211319/80214)</s>
- [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210871/76162), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210922/76162), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210928/76162), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210932/76162)</s>
- [rak1507](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95516/rak1507): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211599/95516),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211728/95516),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211676/95516),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212116/95516),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211731/95516),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212223/95516),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217468/95516),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220227/95516),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220432/95516),
  [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220818/95516)</s>
- [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215700/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215716/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216801/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216797/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216793/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216776/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216836/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216842/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216843/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216845/95792), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216987/95792), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230471/43319)</s>
- [Kamila Szewczyk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61379/kamila-szewczyk): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216304/61379), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216309/61379), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216313/61379), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216660/61379), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216657/61379), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216647/61379), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216713/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216648/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216649/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216652/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216659/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216661/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216662/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216666/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216787/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216784/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216780/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216790/61379),
  [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216840/61379)</s>
- [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215361/64121)</s>
- [Fmbalbuena](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106959/fmbalbuena): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240619/106959)</s>
- [Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253709/107299)</s>
- [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239999/group-elements-by-their-displacement/254519#254519)</s>
- [The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu): <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258268/114446), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258684/114446), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258691/114446)</s>
- [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267/mukundan314): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270056/91267), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270066/91267)</s>
- [username](profile url): [amount](answer url),  [amount](answer url)

---

### APL resources

#### On Code Golf Stack Exchange

- [APL Cultivation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/52405/the-apl-orchard?tab=conversations) — 50 chat lessons on most APL subjects
- [The APL
  Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard)
  — a very active APL chat room
- [Tips for golfing in
  APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl) — lots of sophisticated ideas

#### Other

- [APLcart](https://aplcart.info) — collection of APL phrases
- [APL Wiki](https://aplwiki.com) — lots of info, including learning resources

Comment: Do not leave a comment to request a bounty! Rather, edit the **Bounty requests** list in the post itself.

Comment: [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1156913/questions-eligible-for-apl-bounty-by-adam) for searching questions eligible for this bounty. I did impose several arbitrary filters and ordering, so feel free to fork and edit for your tastes.

Comment: @Bubbler Cool. Added.

Comment: I just checked and now you have more than 30 chat lessons, right? Might be worth editing that?

Comment: @RGS Updated and added a couple of new links. Thanks. Also, congrats on winning the first 400 bounty!

Comment: What's the reason for the "︎ New contributor" restriction?

Comment: @S.S.Anne Preventing people from creating new accounts to get the multiplier.

Comment: All of your challenges deserve an APL answer...

Comment: I believe Sherlock9's answer that you say is on hold due to invalidity has actually been fixed in revision 7 if you look at the history.

Comment: @pppery Well spotted.

Comment: WOW there is so much arrangement to make users learn APL, kudos to you @Adám, I am also interested in learning it now (was not interested before), where I can find starting tutorials for APL?

Comment: @Wasif I suggest you come hang out in the [APL Orchard](https://apl.chat), but learning resources are available at [apl.wiki/Learning_resources](https://apl.wiki/Learning_resources).

Comment: Is BQN a language you'd want to add to the list?

Comment: @AviFS No; definitely not [an APL](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/APL_Wiki:Content_guidelines#What_is_APL.3F).

Answer (score 18):

## 1000 Rep for a meta answer that solves the popularity problem

Popularity contests have been discussed many times, always with much conflict over what counts as a pop con, whether they should be on topic, whether the rules need to be consistent between different pop cons, and with a frustrating lack of consensus.

[Justin](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9498/justin) is offering 1000 rep in bounties for a solution to this.

***Note that trichoplax (who originally posted this answer) is no longer active here and unlikely to see any comments, so you'll need to include `@Justin` in your comment to give a notification.***

The bounties will be posted on a challenge of the answer author's choice if a meta answer presents a solution to this and meets the following conditions:

- 30 days after posting the meta answer, it has 10 or more upvotes and over 90% of its votes are upvotes.
- 3 popularity contests appear on main following the new meta answer, each of which after 30 days from posting has net 10 upvotes and is open.

The meta answer can be attached to a new meta question or an existing meta question.

The bounty target can be an existing challenge or a future one (the bounty can be deferred if the challenge is yet to be posted). It can be any challenge type.

The meta answer can make the rules on pop cons more restrictive, less restrictive, or any other combination of changes, provided it meets the voting criteria specified above.

There can be an arbitrary delay between posting the meta answer and the arrival of the 3 popularity contests on main.

Comment: I'd add another 1000 rep on top of this. My terms might be slightly different in determining if someone solves the problem, but overall it would be basically the same

Comment: @Justin I'd be interested to hear your terms. If they are similar enough, we can match our terms to each other and offer a combined bounty. If they are not, we can still offer two similarly themed bounties - either in separate answers here or in one answer with two descriptions. The advantage of a separate answer is that it makes it easy to ping the appropriate person to claim the bounty, but since you've commented here we should both be pingable on this answer now, so I don't mind either way.

Comment: I guess I want to reserve the right to delay the bounty until we see a few fixed popularity contests get reasonable reception. I really don't want to give out the bounty unless people can make good challenges from the new scheme (because otherwise it didn't work IMO)

Comment: That sounds like an excellent condition - it is indeed effectiveness rather than popularity that I wish to reward. I'd be happy to adjust my wording to include that. To make it precise I guess we could specify something like "N popularity contests posted after the date of the answer, each open with M net votes a month after posting each question".

Comment: So if someone suggests banning pop-cons with community support that is now ineligible?

Comment: @EinkornEnchanter Dang I didn't think about that. While that's not the solution I want, it could be a solution. It's possible that we should special case that. OTOH, there have been a lot of popcons, which shows that people like them. It might be reasonable to not allow banning them as a solution unless the person also comes up with a similar challenge style which captures the "general feeling" of popcons (by community consensus ofc)

Comment: @EinkornEnchanter I edited out the mention of banning popcons because it isn't compatible with the requirement for 3 new popcons, which I agree is a better way of measuring it. I could add back in that meta consensus banning popcons will still earn my original 500 rep bounty, but I didn't give it much thought because I thought it very unlikely that such an answer would be able to gain the 90% support specified.

Comment: @Justin just to let you know I've edited to reflect this, but I'm fairly sure this has no effect on your bounty. Feel free to edit if it does.

Comment: Posting this to make a record of my decision. While I'd prefer a solution that didn't ban popcons, I do have to accept that banning them is a possible solution. I don't want to promise that I'd award the bounty if banning is the solution, but it's very likely that I will

Comment: I believe this is impossible. :P

Comment: @Christopher I'm inclined to agree, but I'd love to see someone prove me wrong, and happy to give up the rep if they do

Comment: I don't think this is possible - not because the problem is unsolvable, but because I don't think it's reasonable to expect the voting restrictions. Why does it matter what the votes are on any popcons that follow our proposal?

Comment: @Challenger5 The voting requirements on main were added to ensure that the proposal is effective, rather than simply popular on meta.

Comment: @Challenger5 The meta answer can be posted on any meta question, possibly a new question. Obviously posting it on a relevant meta question will make it more likely to gather the required votes. From the answer: "The meta answer can be attached to a new meta question or an existing meta question."

Comment: @trichoplax I am seeing around 0-2 pop-cons posted every month for the past few months (including ones which were closed). Are you assuming that a good consensus would increase the rate at which pop-cons are created?

Comment: @Challenger5 No I'm not making any assumptions. I'm simply offering an incentive. Maybe a consensus on what counts as a valid pop con will lead to more suitable challenges that get more upvotes, or maybe it won't. If someone can find a way that works, they will get both bounties. If someone can argue for banning pop cons and get sufficient support on meta, they will get my bounty.

Comment: Hoping to try this again

Comment: @Justin As I no longer participate here, I've edited myself and my bounty offer out of this answer. Hopefully I've done this in a way that leaves your intention for your own bounty intact, but I've made it community wiki so you can easily amend anything I've got wrong.

Comment: @trichoplax Quick question, how does one even get the 1000 rep if it's on meta?

Comment: @DialFrost I'm not active here since switching to Codidact so I won't often see messages, but generally you would add a comment on the relevant Meta answer here, to let the bounty offerer know why you are eligible and which question on Main they should post the bounty on. For this particular bounty, the answer is in my name and I probably won't see a comment so you should contact Justin using @ in this comment thread. I'll edit the answer to make clear to anyone claiming that they won't be able to contact me.

Answer (score 18):

## 100-200 rep for good answers in interesting new languages

This is a bit subjective of course, but here are my criteria:

- The language is fairly new, and is interesting (in my opinion)
- The answer is clever, shows a lot of work put in, and shows off many features of the language (so no trivial posts in interesting languages)
- I have not awarded this bounty in a while (since I don't have much rep)

No requirements on what type of language (esoteric, golfing, practical, etc.). Doesn't have to be an answer by the language creator. I'm always interested in new languages, so if you think your post or someone else's deserves this bounty, leave a comment!

---

**Awarded:**

- [Generate Pascal's Triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216052/79857) (written in [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/)) by [xash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95594/xash)
- [Simple cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217909/79857) (written in [v³](https://esolangs.org/wiki/V%C2%B3)) by [Bo_Tie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100336/bo-tie)
- [Follow a linked list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218879/79857) (written in [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle)) by [Daniel H.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95671/daniel-h)
- [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223430/79857) (written in [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel)) by [LorenDB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92212/lorendb)
- [Division and remainder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223333/79857) (written in [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language)) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Hello, world!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/223559#223559) (written in [Sandwich](https://tildegit.org/karx/sandwich)) by [Y45HK4R4ND1K4R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103219/y45hk4r4nd1k4r)
- [Print this diamond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/print-this-diamond/230675#230675) (written in [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate)) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)

Comment: would be a good idea to include some examples of any recent languages you find interesting.

Comment: also, it's hard to find out when a person gave away a bounty, so instead set a reputation limit, like if your reputation goes below 5500, then bounties are closed.

Comment: @Razetime I'm going to be adding a list of awarded bounties so people know when the last ones have been awarded. I won't set a hard limit for minimum rep I have, since that increases pretty quickly. As for recent languages I find interesting, I'll look into finding an example.

Comment: I think `printLine("Hello, World!")` is quite boring, so I'm assuming I don't qualify for this bounty...

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I don't consider this an interesting answer; it doesn't show off much of the language's design.

Comment: Does an "interesting" variant of an existing language count?

Comment: @Seggan Yes, although the bar may be a bit higher for what's "interesting". If the modifications themselves are interesting, and the language isn't just piggybacking off of the original language's interestingness, sure.

Comment: I've done quite a few answers in my new language Trilangle, but I think if any of them deserve a bounty it's probably [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258119).

Comment: I recently come across an interesting new language made by alephalpha named Nekomata (it looks like a stack based language with backtracking), and I think alephalpha's answers in this language are certainly deserving of this bounty. For example, this answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257998/recognize-a-counting-tree/258071#258071

Comment: @AidenChow Ooh, I'll do the bounty for that tomorrow

Answer (score 18):

## 300 rep for [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) answers

*I'm basing this off the Japt bounty, so some of the wording is going to be the same*

Vyxal. It's one of the golfing languages ever made, and I think you'll like it. In fact, I think you'll like it so much, that if any of y'all post 5 Vyxal solutions in a 30 day period, Razetime, emanresu A and I (lyxal) will give you 300 reputation.

The 5 answers have to be posted after 20/04/2021 (UTC).

We'll be monitoring new solutions and keeping the list at the end of this answer updated but if we miss a solution of yours, please leave a comment with a link to it, or ping us in the [Vyxal chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal).

Bounties will be suspended if rewarding the bounty dips our reputation below 10k. If, on the off-chance, this bounty proves to be popular enough, we may adjust the rep we award to avoid completely tanking it.

---

### Useful links

- [CGCC chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal)
- [Official interpreter](http://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/)
- [Repository (GitHub)](https://github.com/vyxal/Vyxal)
- [Tutorial](https://vyxapedia.hyper-neutrino.xyz/beginners)
- [Tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223918/tips-for-golfing-in-vyxal/223923#223923)

Now go forth and dominate the competition and get this language onto the ELO list!

---

#### Bounty Claims

- **[Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223979/101522), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223985/101522), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223992/101522), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224018/101522), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224033/101522) (*awarded*)
- **[Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210497/write-a-hello-interpreter/224323#224323), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224365/implement-minceraft/224373#224373), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88653/print-a-10-by-10-grid-of-asterisks/224391#224391), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220211/which-th-second-now-in-this-year/225245#225245), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47005/different-way-forward/225281#225281) *(awarded)*
- **[A username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/a-username)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224768/generate-all-solvable-2xn-mazes/225285#225285), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183073/simulating-exploding-dice/225292#225292), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/184734/which-big-number-is-bigger/225289#225289), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185481/automatically-anti-predictably-assemble-an-alliterative-aria/225287#225287), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181078/the-easy-road-to-code/225306#225306) *(awarded)*
- **[StackMeter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100887/stackmeter)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225356/100887), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225357/100887), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225358/100887), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225360/100887), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225361/100887) *(awarded)*
- **[hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224897/68942) [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225299/68942) [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225396/68942) [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225397/68942) [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225398/68942) *(awarded)*
- **[xigoi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98955/xigoi)**:
  [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225412/98955)
  [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225413/98955)
  [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225423/98955)
  [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225685/98955)
  [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225687/98955) *(awarded)*
- **[a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80050/a-stone-arachnid)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225537/80050), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225668/80050), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225681/80050), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225683/80050), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225815/80050) *(awarded)*
- **[user](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95792)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224930), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226518), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226519), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226529), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226592) *(awarded)*
- **[Underslash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99035/underslash)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225394), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225544), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225653), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225855), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225862) *(awarded)*
- **[SjoerdPennings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45220/sjoerdpennings)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235140/45220), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233543/45220), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235155/45220), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235162/45220), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235164/45220) *(awarded)*
- **[Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/seggan)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243235/107299),
  [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243039/107299),
  [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243261/107299),
  [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243247/107299),
  [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243333/107299) *(awarded)*
- **[mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66127/catalan-numbers/242389#242389), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242666/is-given-number-a-concat-of-two-squares/242737#242737), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242726/triangle-tripler/242788#242788), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243100/convert-a-string-of-ascii-characters-to-base-3-equivalents/243115#243115), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243126/draw-an-ascii-pencil/243143#243143) *(awarded)*
- **[Bgil Midol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/105116/bgil-midol)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/169724/is-this-number-evil/243563#243563), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97713/print-the-digital-root/243564#243564), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241080/is-it-a-pure-word/243574#243574), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129596/am-i-divisible-by-double-the-sum-of-my-digits/243575#243575), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235964/implement-the-hyperfactorial/243578#243578) *(awarded)*
- **[Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246010/92689), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246081/92689), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246082/92689), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246084/92689), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246089/92689) *(awarded)*
- **[cjquines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103205/cjquines)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248501/103205), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248508/103205), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248526/103205), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248542/103205), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248622/103205) *(awarded)*
- **[Deadcode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17216/deadcode)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220281/semidivisibility/249423?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C0.0000#249423), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/count-of-as-and-bs-must-be-equal-did-you-get-it-computer/249679?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C0.0000#249679), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66197/is-it-a-pangram/249743?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000#249743), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126373/am-i-a-fibonacci-number/249748?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#249748), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79644/how-many-steps-does-it-take-from-n-to-1-by-subtracting-the-greatest-divisor/249890?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#249890) *(awarded)*
- **[tybocopperkettle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112514/tybocopperkettle)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107634/approximate-bruns-constant/250177#250177), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101961/the-squaring-sequence/250253#250253), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105861/can-this-number-be-written-in-3x-1-format/250224#250224), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66193/sums-of-consecutive-integers/250209#250209), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140748/get-the-best-of-two-arrays/250214#250214) *(awarded)*
- **[Pacmanboss256](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96266/pacmanboss256)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168221/randomizing-until-0/252501#252501), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73828/is-it-a-lipogram/252574#252574), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136713/find-the-first-duplicated-element/252735#252735), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/appending-string-lengths/252736#252736), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252302/find-the-real-solutions-of-a-cubic/252357#252357) *(awarded)*
- **[DialFrost](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/109916/dialfrost)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206158/what-calculator-is-this-datafile-for/252870#252870), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78410/watson-crick-palindromes/252899#252899), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132243/is-the-number-binary-heavy/252903#252903), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252619/its-just-rocket-science-part-2-centrifuge/252907#252907), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252264/its-just-rocket-science/252910#252910) *(awarded)*
- **[The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102219/binary-to-decimal-converter/256486#256486), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256166/is-it-true-ask-pip/256178#256178), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101638/shortest-code-to-produce-non-deterministic-output/256484#256484), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256003/calculate-my-income-tax/256142#256142), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256050/friend-or-foe/256069#256069) *(awarded)*
- **[97.100.97.109](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/113573/97-100-97-109)**: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204813/golf-me-a-world-clock/257144#257144), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252557/sample-from-the-discrete-triangular-distribution/257145#257145), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252927/make-a-court-transcriber/257148#257148), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257159/salacious-bacon-tripod/257179#257179), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/hello-world-with-no-repetition/257365#257365) *(awarded)*

Format:

```
- **[Username](code golf user profile)**: [1](link), [2](link), [3](link), [4](link), [5](link)
```

Comment: Can multiple bounties be awarded (to the same user)?

Comment: @BgilMidol no, one bounty per person

Comment: @TheThonnu razetime is still doing it - I'll ask why that never came through for you

Comment: @TheThonnu sorry about that - there was a bit of miscommunication about which post was being bountied. It's been placed now

Answer (score 15):

### 500 to 2000 rep for a quine in Hexagony

There are two ways to write a quine in [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony) (which will probably result in very different solutions). The former is clearly the golfier version but the other one would be a lot neater. I'll give a 500 rep bounty to the first person who manages to write either of those:

- <s>One program which is a quine when written most compactly, without whitespace and without unnecessary no-ops at the end (no-ops to pad the grid to the correct side-length are fine). ([I have written one in the meantime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74294/8478) but I'm happy to be beaten. You'll have to beat it at least by one side-length to qualify for the full bounty though.)</s> This one has been awarded to [Jo King's quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155431/8478).

  - <s>I, (Jo King), will pass the 500, as well as 500 of my own rep to an even shorter quine. Again, you'll have to beat it by at least one side length to qualify (though a quine of the same side length that employs a sufficiently different algorithm may also qualify).</s> The bounty has been claimed (in record time too!) by [user202729's size 11 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156271/76162).
  - Since the shortest Hexagony quine is now of [side length 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193220/76162), I (Jo King) will be awarding a bounty of 1000 for a shorter quine that beats it by at least 11 bytes (i.e. one row of the hexagon). If you can't quite get it that short, I will still award a 500 rep bounty for a side length 10 that uses a sufficiently novel algorithm. If you manage to golf another side length I will award 2000 rep (and my undying adoration)
- One program which is a quine when laid out nicely in a hexagon as usual, without a column of leading spaces and without any trailing spaces on the lines. There may be an optional trailing linefeed.

There should be some effort to golf the solution. And of course, the empty program is not a valid quine (I don't think there are any other possible cheats in Hexagony).

Answer (score 15):

## 100-500 rep for answers to good, old questions with few answers

#### Please note: I'm nearly out of rep and can't award anyone anymore. If someone else can continue the bounty, that'd be really great.

This bounty is for answers to questions that meet the following criteria:

- They have a score of 10 or more (and fewer than 4 downvotes)
- They haven't had an answer in 3 years
- There are between 1 and 9 answers (inclusive)

For questions not tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips), here are the bounty amounts, depending on how many answers there are and whether or not there is a good explanation:

- 1 to 3 answers (inclusive): 400 rep (500 with a good explanation)
- 4 to 6 answers: 200 rep (300 with a good explanation)
- 7 to 9 answers: 100 rep (200 with a good explanation)

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+score%3A10..+answers%3A..9+lastactive%3A..2018+closed%3A0+locked%3A0+-%5Btips%5D) search from caird coineringaahing/ChartZ Belatedly may help find eligible questions.

For questions tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips), if there are 5 or fewer answers already, new answers can get 50 rep.

Please edit in your requests in the form `username: [amount](answer link), [amount](answer link)`. Bolded requests are in progress, and those that are struck through have finished.

rak1507: <s>[250](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220432/95792), [300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220818/95516)</s>

ChartZ Belatedly: <s>[500](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119967/expand-kirkmans-schoolgirl-problem/220791#220791), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220827/66833)<sup><sup>[why not 300?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57372440#57372440)</sup></sup>, [400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220852/66833), [400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222525/66833)</s>

Wasif: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119253/make-an-interpreter-for-yes/221259#221259), [300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/compute-the-difference-between-two-days/221319#221319), [300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129243/printing-criss-cross-of-two-strings/221400#221400)</s>, <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12563/random-css-color-code/226631#226631)</s>

Jonah: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222512/15469)</s>

Deadcode: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17855/regex-golf-regions-of-italy-vs-states-of-usa/222571#222571)</s>

pxeger: <s>[300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222782)</s>, <s>[300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230725), [300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248285)</s>

Razetime: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222742/80214)</s>

Dion: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229376/92080)</s>

Aaroneous Miller: <s>[400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236077/101522)</s>

pajonk: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236466/55372)</s>

Grain Ghost: <s>[500](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237505/56656), [400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237588/56656), [100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237599/56656)</s>

ophact: <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246677/106710), [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71203/convert-the-time-to-a-string/247389#247389)</s>

alephalpha: <s>[400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75786/addition-on-elliptic-curves/248403#248403)</s>

mathcat: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248626/96037)</s>

Seggan: <s>[300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248742/107299)</s>

matteo_c: <s>[500](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250843/73593)</s>, [200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263744/73593)

bigyihsuan: <s>[300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252676/77309), [300](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253463/77309)</s> [500](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92877/phonemic-abugida/254944#254944)

Aurath: <s>[400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253362/113573)</s>

Comment: @Dingus I'm not sure your answer qualifies, as user has [specifically excluded previously unanswered questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57372415#57372415)

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Indeed - I missed the part about ' between 1 and 9 answers (inclusive)'.

Comment: @Dingus Sorry I can't award it - it certainly deserves +500 (I did upvote it though).

Comment: @AaroneousMiller, I think your answer should be eligible for the bounty here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17337/55372 (and as stated in comments above, user has [specifically excluded previously unanswered questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57372415#57372415))

Comment: @pajonk At the time of posting, the OP had answered the question as well, but it didn't turn out to be a valid answer. I mentioned it to user in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=59326501#59326501), and they said they would award the bounty when they got enough rep.

Comment: Having read through quite a few of these I think calling them "good" is perhaps a bit misleading ...

Comment: @GrainGhost Well, "good" is a bit subjective, and while subjective bounties are fine, I didn't feel like denying anyone their bounty just because I personally didn't like the challenge. Would "decent" be better? :P

Comment: You can call them what you want.  I'm just a little surprised by how low quality many of them are.

Comment: [i think this can claim the 400?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252156/101762)  (i can’t edit so i’ll put it here)

Comment: [Looking for 200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252313/106844), but if explanation is insufficient, the 100

Comment: [Looking for 100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252731)

Comment: [Looking for 200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110417/accessories-after-the-fact/252755#252755)

Comment: [Looking for 500](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253204/108218)

Comment: [400 I think](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253362/113573)

Comment: [Looking for 400](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253716/114446) (2 answers, no explanation)

Comment: [Looking for 200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253761/114446) (6 answers, no explanation)

Comment: [Looking for 500](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92877/phonemic-abugida/254944#254944)

Answer (score 14):

## 200 rep each for answering good unanswered questions

I don't like seeing good questions go unanswered, so I'm offering 200 rep each for valid answers to unanswered non-[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) non-[koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth) non-[cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) questions with a score of <s>20</s> 15 or above. As of now (April 26, 2022), there are 2 such questions:

- [Topologically distinct ways of dissecting a square into rectangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220053/topologically-distinct-ways-of-dissecting-a-square-into-rectangles)
- [Find a Glider Synthesis (Game of Life)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107788/find-a-glider-synthesis-game-of-life)

You can check for yourself what questions are available [via search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+score%3A15..+-%5Btips%5D+-%5Bking-of-the-hill%5D+-%5Bcops-and-robbers%5D), or vote for questions that are [close to the vote count](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+score%3A13..+-%5Btips%5D+-%5Bking-of-the-hill%5D+-%5Bcops-and-robbers%5D)

#### Previous winners:

- [Magic: the Gathering Combat Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179689/58563) By [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)
- [Optimize Compiler for simple Reverse Polish Notation Programming Language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190764/76162) by [Roman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87058/roman)
- [Auto BATCH golfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190995/76162) by [Kamila Szewczyk](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/61379/kamila-szewczyk)
- [Matrices Generated Using Rectangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195766/76162) by [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino)
- [Determine if a Graph is Toroidal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196011/76162) by [isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg)
- [Halting Problem for Simplified Hexagony](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199608/76162) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Maximal discrepancy-2 sequence with minimal entropy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200341/76162) by [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)
- [Gerrymander North Carolina](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203212/76162) by [my pronoun is monicareinstate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/my-pronoun-is-monicareinstate)
- [Hexasweep (part 1): The Solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211376/76162) by [Redwolf Programs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857/redwolf-programs)
- [How should I tile my kitchen?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212043/76162) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Complement a POSIX Extended Regular Expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233759/76162) by [tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87606/tjjfvi)
- [Totally Cubular](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235298/76162) by [tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87606/tjjfvi)
- [telgif: inverse figlet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235324/76162) by [tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87606/tjjfvi)

Comment: I offer 100 rep each for answering unanswered [tag:code-golf] non-[tag:tips] questions with any score, as long as there's a serious attempt at optimization.

Comment: Posted an answer to [Compare Dowker Notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237532/87606)

Comment: Posted an answer to [Acyclic orientations of an n-dimensional cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203756/76162). The challenge is not really hard if you know some Mathematica built-in.

Comment: I answered [Can you draw this in one stroke?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243741/can-you-draw-this-in-one-stroke/245334#245334)

Comment: Just posted an answer to [Golfing Expressions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223581/golfing-expressions/246348#246348)

Comment: I answered [Help me prove the Four Color Theorem!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229334/help-me-prove-the-four-color-theorem/246359#246359)

Comment: [Ajax1234](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74571/ajax1234)'s [Can I wall glitch to there? answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242581/can-i-wall-glitch-to-there/246965#246965) is eligible for this bounty.

Comment: About "unanswered" questions - does this mean that there's no accepted answer (like what I based my [SEDE query search](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1825362/code-golf-questions-that-are-eligible-for-200-rep-bounty-by-jo-king) off of) or does it mean that there are no answers?

Answer (score 12):

## Absurd thematic challenges

These can only be claimed once each, first come first serve. I will answer any clarifying questions for any challenge given below if needed.

#### 500 rep for answering [Non-discriminating Programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156967/non-discriminating-programming) in [Incident](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Incident)

No twist.

#### 500 rep for answering [Transform characters of your choice into "Hello, world!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250556/107310)... as a [self-validating](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-validating) challenge.

This challenge asks you to write a program or function which takes a printable ASCII character as input and outputs a printable ASCII character. It also asks you to choose a string of 13 *distinct* printable ASCII characters which, when input into your program/function, output the characters of `Hello, world!`. To claim this bounty, those two strings must be one in the same. To make this more feasible, character order does not matter. So for example: If your program is `abcdefghijklm` and inputting the characters in the order `mlkjihgfedcba` gives `Hello, world!`, you will be awarded this bounty.

#### 500 rep for answering [Is this hexagon symmetric?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241584/is-this-hexagon-symmetric) in [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony)... with symmetric source code

"Symmetric source code" here is defined roughly as follows: replace all the nops in your program with 0s, and all the non-nops in your programs with 1s. When this string of 0s and 1s is input into your program as a hexagon, it should accept it as symmetric. You don't have to use specifically 0s and 1s, just two different values, or however you take input to your program.

#### 500 rep for answering [Solve a Rubik's Cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153315/solve-a-rubiks-cube) in [Cubestack](https://github.com/tobyck/cubestack)... with the final state of the [cube](https://cubestack.surge.sh/) being solved

Instructions in this language correspond to moves on a Rubik's cube. Your program should correspond to movements on a cube which leave it solved. You can check the cube's halt state with the [official online interpreter](https://cubestack.surge.sh/).

#### 500 rep for solving [But is it a pretty place?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248047/107310) in [Positionally](https://github.com/chunkybanana/positionally/)

Again, no extra twist, this is hard enough as is :P [Here's the interpreter](https://dso.surge.sh/#positionally).

#### 500 rep from @CommandMaster for solving [Golf a LaTeΧ math expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265852/92727) in TeX

No twist. Feel free to use any common TeX variants or packages, but the computation has to be done in TeX - you can't use a package which lets you, for example, execute Python, and solve the problem in Python.

Comment: So for the Hello World one, the program _has_ to be 13 chars?

Comment: @Ginger yes :-)

Comment: Would having the part which solves the cube in an `if (false)` conditional count for the Cubestack one?

Comment: @CommandMaster ah, I hadn't realized that was an option. I think when I wrote that one up, I was partially under the impression that the cube state was altered during runtime lol. **I'll absolutely allow it**, and afterward I'll add a version of the challenge that should hopefully discourage that (without asking something unobservable)

Comment: I'd like to offer 500 rep for solving [Golf a LaTeX math expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265852/golf-a-late%ce%a7-math-expression) in TeX. Would you mind if I added "500 rep from @CommandMaster for ..." here, or should I make my own post?

Answer (score 11):

## 100-200 rep for your first 5 Pip answers

My language Pip has finally reached version 1.0! To celebrate, I will award 100 rep to anyone who:

- Is not a "︎ New contributor"
- Has posted fewer than 5 answers in Pip prior to 14 September 2021
- After 14 September 2021, posts valid Pip answers on 5 different [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges which:

  - Are not [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) or other challenge types like [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) or [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)
  - Have fewer than 30 answers at the time the Pip answer is posted

Once the 5 answers are posted, I will choose my favorite of them to bounty. **If the answer also comes with a good explanation** (in my subjective judgement), **the bounty may be increased up to 200 rep.** I may increase the amount further if I find the answer especially impressive. If other factors (for example, whether I've previously bountied the question) prevent me from bountying the answer I would like with the amount I would like, I will pick a different answer or work out another arrangement with you.

---

### Resources

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Pip)
- [Documentation site](https://dloscutoff.github.io/pipdoc)
- [Tutorial](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/wiki) (in progress)
- [Tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210380/16766)
- [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?L=pip) (supports a recent release of Pip, currently 1.1.0)
- [DSO](https://dso.surge.sh/#pip) (up to date with the latest commit; doesn't play well with stdin or infinite loops)
- [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) (up to date with the latest commit; command-line interface, defaulting to REPL mode)
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#pip) (only supports version 0.18, aka [Pip Classic](https://dloscutoff.github.io/pipdoc/pip-classic))

Feel free to ping me in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) if you have questions.

---

### Bounty Claims

Format:

- [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow): [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253309/triangular-polkadot-numbers/253467#253467), **[2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252927/make-a-court-transcriber/253470#253470)**, [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253568/alphabet-checksum/253605#253605), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252491/generate-parity-bits/253611#253611), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249868/every-possible-pairing/253614#253614) (awarded)
- [Baby_Boy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106844/baby-boy): **[1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253732/remove-the-last-n-occurences-of-a-substring-from-a-string/253756#253756)**, [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/equality-in-the-sum-of-digits/253790#253790), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135802/take-the-square-root-of-a-string/253816#253816), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103355/this-cat-has-bugs-really/254013#254013), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70277/implement-an-encoder-for-rfc-1924-ipv6-addresses/254196#254196) (awarded)
- [mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat): [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255650/sum-every-second-digit-in-a-number/255684#255684), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255765/replace-all-vowels-with-repeated-aeiou/255773#255773), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255804/create-n-sublists-with-the-powers-of-two-1-2-4-8-16/255819#255819), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255822/replace-0s-in-a-string-with-their-consecutive-counts/255826#255826), **[5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255902/keep-elements-in-sequence-that-have-a-letter-repeated-at-least-3-times/255919#255919)** (awarded)
- [The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu): [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141949/count-edits-accounting-for-grace-period/257776#257776), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257650/determine-the-octet-duplet-18-electron-rule/257774#257774), **[3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257752/print-all-pandigital-numbers/257756#257756)**, [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257649/arbitrary-apple-dilemma/257772#257772), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256050/friend-or-foe/256070#256070) (awarded)

```
- [Username](code golf user profile): [1](link), [2](link), [3](link), [4](link), [5](link)
```

Comment: Oh dear no one has claimed it :(

Comment: @DialFrost I believe a couple people have posted enough answers to be eligible... maybe I'll comment on one of their answers reminding them that a bounty is available.

Comment: yeah, for example I have [7 Pip answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A92689+pip), I just don't need random rep.

Comment: I'm the first one to claim it :P

Comment: @DLosc crap that is sad to hear

Comment: So should I just edit my list to put the new posts

Comment: Ok I got two other answers with <30 answers by the time I posted the answer: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252491/generate-parity-bits/253611#253611) (29th answer at the time of posting), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249868/every-possible-pairing/253614#253614) (24th answer at the time of posting)

Comment: @DLosc Thanks a lot! This is the first deadlineless bounty i'm claiming ever lol

Comment: I got my 5, [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253713/106844), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253756/106844), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253790/106844), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253816/106844), [5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253951/106844). Bonus [6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254013/106844) and [7](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254196/106844)

Answer (score 10):

## 500-1000 rep for further work on [(-a) × (-a) = a × a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/143822/39328) (no longer active?)

This now classic [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) question has 3 answers at score 18. Is 17 possible?

- 500 rep will be awarded for an answer with score 17 or lower.
- 500 rep will be awarded for strong evidence that a solution is optimal, with a possible additional bonus for a proof.

These bounties can be awarded either together or separately.

Answer (score 10):

## 50-500 rep for answers to Bubbler's challenges in any of previous LotM languages

LotM languages often go inactive again after the event ends, so here is an attempt to keep them alive (or revive?).

I (Bubbler) will award 50-500 rep for answering one of my [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), non-[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) challenges in previous LotM languages.

An answer is eligible for this bounty if:

- the challenge is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), non-[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips), and at least a week old ([search query](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a78410%20is%3aq%20%5bcode-golf%5d%20-%5btips%5d%20created%3a..7d)),
- the language used was on LotM before,
- there isn't another endless bounty that awards answers in that language (so [Whispers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21948/78410) and [Vyxal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22137/78410) are out), and
- the challenge didn't have any other answer in the same language before it.

Also, if you have **5,000** rep or higher, I won't award the bounty for solving Easy or Medium challenges.

The bounty value will be decided as follows:

- Base value (depends on the language used)

  - **+50**: Brachylog, MATL, Japt, R, Husk, Rust, Scala, Factor, Red
  - **+100**: QBasic, Forth, Vim
  - **+200**: Brain-Flak, SMBF
- Multiplier (depends on the difficulty of the challenge)

  - **×0.5**: Easy
  - **×1.0**: Medium
  - **×2.0**: Hard
  - **×4.0**: Insane
  - **+500** (fixed value, regardless of language): Higher than Insane
- Extra bonus (additive) if the answer is exceptionally good or interesting to me

#### Notes

- I won't award the bounty if the value goes below 50 (or the minimum value I can award on the challenge), and the bounty value is capped at 500.
- I don't have a fixed difficulty assigned to my challenges (yet). I'll try to be consistent though. You may generally assume a challenge is at least Hard if it has relatively high score and very few answers (and definitely Easy if it has very many short answers).

---

### Awarded Bounties

- (none yet)

### Bounty Requests

- Please edit in bounty requests here below the template, with relevant links.
- [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user): [Forth and Vim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231728/95792) to [This code errors on *this* and *that*, is it really written in them?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/159755/95792) (50 rep probably)
- Template: `[Username](link): [Answer](link) to [Challenge title](link)`

Comment: Is it alright if the challenge is a week old now, but the answer was posted on the same day as the challenge?

Comment: Does any past LOTM lang qualify, or only the ones listed in the Base Value part?

Answer (score 10):

## 250 or 500 rep for showing off some skillz on code.golf

[code.golf](https://code.golf/) is a competitive code golf site, where all solutions are hidden and users compete for a better solution for each task in each language supported. Many Code Golf SE users also compete there.

I found some of particularly insane solutions, and I hereby challenge all of you to find out (or even outgolf) those solutions. Golfing I/O is often considered boring, but there are some golfing techniques that can only be utilized in strict I/O setting.

Since the solutions cannot be shared, you need a code.golf account to be eligible for this bounty, so that any tie or outgolf is visible on the leaderboards. To claim the bounty, leave a comment on this answer with a link to your own Code Golf SE answer to receive the bounty.

Tie record (nullifying the "diamond" score) is worth 250 rep, and outgolf (setting a new diamond) is worth 500 rep.

### Records to aim for

- [Intersection in Python](https://code.golf/intersection#python), 110 bytes (this one was once a hot topic on TNB, and I got a 117 [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58465264#58465264), and shortly after that JayXon outgolfed me with a 116. Several months passed and I suddenly found a golf on my own answer that swooped away 7 bytes at once(!), and no one seems to have found the trick, even though the other top 5 solvers also got their scores improved a lot.)
- [Leap Years in J](https://code.golf/leap-years#j), 27 bytes
- [Seven Segment in J](https://code.golf/seven-segment#j), 61 bytes
- <s>[Musical Chords in J](https://code.golf/musical-chords#j), 95 bytes</s> *outgolfed by HPWiz by large margin*
- [Intersection in J](https://code.golf/intersection#j), 39 bytes (updated 2022-01-13; I found this by going back and forth between J and K, trying and backporting various possible algorithms. So the 39 is drastically different from my previous 40.)
- [Collatz in J](https://code.golf/collatz#j), 34 bytes & [K](https://code.golf/collatz#k), 33 bytes (added 2022-05-07)

Answer (score 9):

## 100-500 rep for APL answers to Bubbler's challenges

To celebrate me ([Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)) reaching 25k rep (with over 100 answers in APL, 50 challenges written, and several thousands of rep gained from [Adám's APL bounties](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/78410)), I will share some of my rep for even more APL answers!

Specifically, I offer 100 (or higher up to 500, depending on how impressive it is) rep for the following:

---

### A competitive APL answer to one of my [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges which doesn't yet have one

"Competitive" is a bit subjective, but it generally means the solution

- is at least shorter than comparable solutions in general-purpose languages (e.g. Python/JS; from my experience, APL usually gets 50~70% byte count of Python for moderately hard challenges, and much lower for easier ones),

  - The code length is just a rule-of-thumb guide, and can be dismissed depending on the task (e.g. if the task makes it hard to use the SBCS).
- utilizes core APL features as appropriate, and
- does not look like a line-by-line translation from C or Python code.

If you think your answer is good but too long, you may ask for help at [the APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) for golfing. I will decide on the bounties based on the golfed answer.

<s>In order to prevent rushing for the newest challenges, only challenges that are at least 2 months old are eligible for this bounty. This is also applied to the SEDE query below.</s> Due to lack of interest, I decided to simply remove this condition.

#### [List of challenges to answer (SEDE query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1242868/questions-eligible-for-apl-bounty-by-bubbler)

These challenges (despite having an APL answer already) are also available for the bounty:

- (none at the moment)

Note that some of the challenges are also eligible for Adám's bounties. Feel free to claim both.

---

### Awarded Bounties

- **150 rep**: [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210871/76162) to [20 cards with no Set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195685/76162)
- **150 rep**: [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210899/571) to [The Ultimate Inequality Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203583/the-ultimate-inequality-challenge/)
- **200 rep**: [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210913/76162) to [Bubbler numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205396/76162)
- **150 rep**: [rak1507](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95516/rak1507)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211748/95516) to [Cut resistance of a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205336/95516)
- **150 rep**: [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211068/76162) to [Is this a circular step sequence?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199994/76162)
- **150 rep**: [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212183/80214) to [Area of diagonal-folded regular polygon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195775/78410)
- **150 rep**: [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211821/80214) to [Circumference of an ellipse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211763/circumference-of-an-ellipse)
- **200 rep**: [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213830/80214) to [Counting valid Binary Sudoku rows](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/201094/80214)
- **250 rep**: [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215515/95792)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215515/95792) to [Evaluate Conway chained arrow notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204132/95792)
- **200 rep**: [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214649/80214) to [Perimeter of Conway Hexagon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203853/80214)
- **250 rep**: [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216263/80214) to [When is the closest Conway's Doomsday?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204002/80214)
- **150 rep**: [rak1507](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95516/rak1507)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217463/95516) to [Penney-Conway Odds](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203784/95516)
- **200 rep**: [Martin Janiczek](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69277/martin-janiczek)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217535/69277) to [Help me pair my left and right socks!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196837/help-me-pair-my-left-and-right-socks)
- **200 rep**: [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217477/95792) to [Read out the C variable declaration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/174677/95792)
- **200 rep**: [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218076/80214) to [Nightmare Puzzlang Translator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172586/nightmare-puzzlang-translator/218076#218076)

### Bounty Requests

- Please edit in bounty requests here below the template, with relevant links.
- [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime): [Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218072/80214) to [Circular Limited Sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/164364/80214)
- [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime): [Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218066/80214) to [Is This an L Shape?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218059/80214)
- Template: `[Username](link): [Answer](link) to [Challenge title](link)`

Comment: Is this bounty still going? I'm thinking about answering the C variable declaration question, but it since it looks a bit hard, I'd like some fake internet points too :)

Comment: @user Of course it is still going. (I just paused to give out LotM bounties, but forgot to resume this one after the LotM ended) It's great that you're tackling one of the harder problems, which is exactly what I was wishing for with this bounty.

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks. It’s really great that you and Adam are giving out these bounties to encourage people to learn APL.

Answer (score 8):

## 500-1000 rep for outscoring in [Multiply with restricted operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37188/multiply-with-restricted-operations)

The [current best score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41314/20260) is 22 operations.

```python
itx = 1/(1+a+b)     #4
nx = -1/(itx+itx)   #4
c = -( 1/(itx + itx + 1/(1+nx)) + 1/(1/(a+nx) + 1/(b+nx)) ) #14
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxCsAgDET3fkXAJUGKiHb0Y9SlLlaKg/16a5oeJNy949rTz6u6GYPbUjhm6QMCWINWR50IWMpvlem@8Or1OhKcmSIIBw3yv3UdRL83GDlKStIQKOtnu0vtmGm@)

I'll give 500 rep to the first better score, that is 21 operations or fewer.

Alternatively, you can get the bounty by proving that 22 is in fact optimal, say with exhaustive search. A weaker proof or lower bound can get a partial bounty.

The maximum you can get is 1000 rep, 500 for the optimal proof, and 500 for the solution less than 22 operations long.

Comment: What happens if someone posts something with less than 22 operations, **and** shows proof? 1000 bounty maybe? :3

Comment: @DialFrost Sure, I'd give 500 for both the improvement and the proof that it's optimal, 1000 total.

Answer (score 8):

## 50-300 rep for answers to unanswered questions

Similar to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17337/66833) offering, I will offer varying amounts of reputation for answers to questions that meet the following criteria:

- The question is unanswered<sup>*</sup>
- The question is at least one month old
- The question has a net score \$\ge3\$ and \$\lt 15\$
- The question is not tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)
- The question is open

<sub><sup>*</sup>: Unanswered means that no answers have been posted to the question which fully complete the task in the question</sub>

This list of questions, sorted by current score, can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20answers%3a0%20score%3a3...14%20closed%3a0%20-%5btips%5d%20created%3a...1m).

The amount of reputation I will offer depends on the following criteria:

- Age of the question (older questions will merit more rep)
- How impressive I personally find the answer (based on language, score etc.)
- How difficult I perceive the challenge to be

Obviously, these are subjective, but I will try to be as fair as I can.

Furthermore, if awarding a bounty will drop me below a [privilege level](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), causing me to lose it, I will postpone awarding the bounty until I have enough rep to avoid this. However, such bounties will only be *postponed*, so all valid answers will eventually receive their deserved bounties.

To claim a bounty, as normal, ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) or leave a comment below. If unable to do so due to reputation requirements, ask another user to do so for you, so I don't miss any answers.

Once you claim one of these bounties, please edit it in below

### Claimed bounties

- 150 rep to [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino) for answering [Generate Menu Access Keys](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93125/generate-menu-access-keys)
- 50 rep to [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino) for answering [Expand the variadic expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93651/expand-the-variadic-expression)
- 150 rep to [wastl](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78123/wastl) for answering [Recording xiangqi moves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165423/recording-xiangqi-moves)
- 200 rep to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) for answering [Score a 1 player game of Carcassonne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205861/66833)
- 50 rep to [EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94093/easyaspi) for answering [Test the endianness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193815/test-the-endianness)
- 300 rep to [m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104752/m90) for answering [Final tribute to John Conway: FRACTRAN self-interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204779/final-tribute-to-john-conway-fractran-self-interpreter)
- 100 rep to [tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87606/tjjfvi) for answering [Please parse this aLL1en language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67033/66833)
- 100 rep to [ryno](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104508/ryno) for answering [The knight's next tour](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73759/66833)
- 100 rep to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus) for answering [Simulate a Game of Quagmire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48386/66833)
- 50 rep to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus) for answering
  [Printing the Cracker Barrel Game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53436/66833)

Comment: @Wzl That's incorrect - there's nothing about views in the bounty, and you're missing `created:...1m`, which is in the query already in the answer. I did forget it should be `-[tips]` instead of `-tips` tho, thanks!

Comment: I think [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204779/final-tribute-to-john-conway-fractran-self-interpreter/231006#231006) qualifies? Also, the link for "This list of questions, sorted by current score" actually gives them sorted by "relevance" (at least for me); `tab=votes` would have to be added for it to be sorted by current score.

Comment: @m90 Indeed it does, and indeed it should. Started a +300 bounty and corrected the link

Comment: I think [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231771/87606) qualifies

Comment: @tjjfvi Started a +100 bounty, very nice!

Comment: I think [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53436/printing-the-cracker-barrel-game/233894#233894) qualifies.

Comment: [net puzzle generator rekt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237143/78410)

Answer (score 8):

## 100-500 rep for solving challenges using an ACE exploit in an esoteric language

I've reached 2300 rep, so here's a bounty for you RE/CTF enthusiasts for an answer I really want to see.

> CVE-2018-6849: Code execution results in code execution
> — *TheZZAZZGlitch, "A friendly reminder: Lua scripts are arbitrary code", [YouTube](https://youtu.be/LtGm7e9gd0Y)*

Esoteric language interpreters and compilers are often pretty shoddily written. It is usually shrugged off because "nobody is going to use it for anything serious".

Your goal:

1. Find an existing interpreter, translator, or compiler for an **esoteric** language published **before January 2021.** Preferably, this should have an entry on [esolangs.org](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page) or be under the "Recreational" category on TIO.
2. Find a bug **in the interpreter, compiler, or generated code** that allows you to **escape the language** and execute **arbitrary code**. This can be direct code execution, launching a shell, cross-site scripting, return oriented programming, making compilers emit arbitrary code, or something similar. If you can execute arbitrary code in the compiler itself, that counts as well.
3. Explain the bug (and, preferably, explain a way to fix it if it hasn't been patched)
4. Solve a code challenge **posted before January 2021** using code executed from that exploit **instead of** the tools provided by the language.
5. Also be sure to explain the payload itself.

**To be clear:** You are only allowed to use features provided by the language to set up the payload and exploit. The logic to solve the puzzle must be entirely in the payload.

However, you are allowed to execute some code from the interpreter/compiler itself in the payload, e.g. for input and output or ROP chaining.

The following do not count:

- Exploits that just run the interpreter on arbitrary code in the same language. You must demonstrate full control over the interpreter.
- Exploits caused by the code you wrote. The code you wrote must only exploit the bug.
- Tools in the language *intended* to execute code (e.g. `execve()/system()` in C or things like `eval()`).
- Bugs in third party code or the programming language that the interpreter/compiler uses. (e.g. exploiting a Node.js bug in an interpreter written in JavaScript)
- Code challenges that are simply "crash the program" or the like: It should be something interesting.

Older releases of an interpreter/compiler are fine.

Since these are very system specific, please either provide an online demo or a Docker image. You are required to provide the exact build instructions in the latter case.

Custom compiler flags for building interpreters follow the same loophole rules.

See some of my answers for [Shortest code that raises a SIGSEGV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-raises-a-sigsegv) which highlight some interpreter bugs I found for a starting point.

While I may not be able to award immediately, I will try to award anywhere from 100-500 rep, ***depending on how much you impress me.*** Finding new exploits is strongly encouraged instead of using the same one over and over.

**Take that Phooey freebie while you can!**

Add a comment here or ping me in chat if I (likely) don't notice your post.

#### Awarded bounties

- 200 rep to [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller) for [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231059/94093) for escaping a string to execute arbitrary Python in [Vyxal 2.4.0](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.4.0).

Comment: Good point. I will allow compilers/transpilers.

Comment: I have clarified that it should be an esoteric language, which wasn't obvious before.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231059/101522) should qualify for this bounty.

Comment: Yup, it does! Good one!

Comment: [lol I found another Vyxal ACE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237727/101522)

Answer (score 7):

## 50-500 rep for answering in [my languages](https://gist.github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/9cd9f4b5207593dc3bc8ef102eeb2cf3)

I've (currently) published 21 languages, all of which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/9cd9f4b5207593dc3bc8ef102eeb2cf3) and 16 of which are on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#)

I'm offering 50 rep to any answer that meets the following criteria:

- It is written in one of Add++, Adjust, Bitwise Fuckery, Deorst, NotQuiteThere, Orst, Rutger, Verbosity, Verbosity v2 or any version of Whispers
- It is the shortest answer in that language, at time of posting
- The challenge has fewer than 30 answers, not counting the to-be-bountied answer
- The challenge is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), and is not tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)
- The challenge is older than a week

I'm offering 100 rep to any answer that meets the following criteria:

- It is written in one of Commentator, Flipbit, Geo, Levels, No, Sample, Uno, Yggdrasil or `√ å ı ¥ ® Ï Ø ¿`
- It is the shortest answer in that language, at time of posting
- The challenge has fewer than 30 answers, not counting the to-be-bountied answer
- The challenge is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), and is not tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)
- The challenge is older than a week

Additionally, I will double the rep awarded for each of the following points met (to a maximum of 500 rep):

- It is the first valid answer to the challenge
- It is shorter than all other answers to the challenge (the challenge must have at least one existing answer)
- It uses a non-obvious\${}^*\$ method that helps it save bytes over the obvious method
- It is an answer to one of [my questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/chartz-belatedly?tab=questions)

<sup>\${}^*\$I'll be the judge of what's "non-obvious", but generally, it's a method that isn't the immediate, go-to method</sup>

Additionally, I will delay awarding bounties if they cause me to drop below 25000 reputation, until a point where I can award them.

**Don't comment to claim bounties. Instead, edit in claims below**

---

### Bounty list

<sub>Stolen shamelessly from [Adám's APL bounties](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/66833)</sub>

Awarded bounties are <s>struck-through</s>.

Bounties in progress are **bold**.

Bounties on hold are *italic*.

If you have previously requested a bounty, you add can add more requests after the struck-through ones, otherwise add yourself to the below list to request a bounty.

The format is:

`- [username](url-to-profile): [rep](url-to-answer-post), [rep](url-to-answer-post)`

---

- [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal): <s>[100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/232975/78850)</s>
- Razetime: <s>[200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233072/80214)</s>
- Fmbalbuena: [50](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240880/106959)

Comment: Just an FYI: if you have any questions about my languages (such as functionality, or just asking why on earth they exist, etc.), feel free to ping me in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), but be warned that the answer may not be all too helpful

Comment: "to a maximum of 500 rep" - the maximum possible is 400, since bonuses 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive

Comment: @pxeger I may add additional points that double it at some point, so I'll leave it as is

Comment: Where does Adapt fall in here?

Comment: @Razetime Adapt has been completely supplanted by Adjust, so I won't be offering bounties for using it. I did forget to include Adjust tho, so added that

Comment: Hello, bounty me :/

Answer (score 7):

## 50-100 rep for answers in TypeScript's type system

There aren't many answers here written in TypeScript's ([turing complete](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237776/87606)) type system; as of posting, there six, two of which are my own. I like seeing such answers, so I'll be awarding a 50 rep bounty to answers that meet *all* of the following criteria:

- Are posted later than 2021-11-27 (date of bounty posting)
- Consist of a valid TypeScript source file containing a type alias that, given valid input as type parameters, results in a type representing valid output for the challenge

  - Input and output types can be any types that reflect the challenge's I/O requirements

    - For example, string literals are allowed for a challenge requiring string input, and tuple types are valid where tuples would be
  - Type parameters that aren't part of the input but have defaults are valid, even for challenges with no input

    - For example, `type X<T="a">=T` would be valid for a challenge "Output the literal string `a` with no input"
- Beat all other existing TypeScript type system answers in the challenge, if applicable

  - Beat, for the purposes of this bounty, can be done either by the challenge's scoring criterion or by erroring due to the recursion limit on notably fewer inputs
- Produce no compile errors (`//@ts-ignore` is allowed)
- Make a reasonable attempt to avoid the recursion limit. TypeScript has a very strict recursion limit; 50 for regular types and 1000 for tail-recursive types. Reasonable attempts include:

  - Anything that supports most inputs without erroring
  - Use of tail recursion to get the 1000 limit
  - Anything where I either do not choose to or am not able to send you an altered version that errors on notably fewer inputs
- Use at least one conditional type (e.g. `A extends B ? C : D`), template literal type (e.g. `` `foo${T}baz` ``), or variadic tuple type (e.g. `[T, ...U]`), and cannot be beaten by a solution which uses none

  - Most answers will pass this criterion; this is to exclude things like `type A="Hello world!"`.
- Do not have any external dependencies (e.g. on type utility libraries).

If your answer does not meet any of these criteria, but you believe it is in the spirit of the bounty nonetheless, any of the criteria can be overridden by my judgement.

---

I'll award 100 rep (total) to answers that match all of the above criteria and **at least one** of the following criteria:

- Are the answerer's first answer in TypeScript's type system
- Include a decent explanation (this is, obviously, subjective)
- Demonstrate the turing completeness of TypeScript's type system by implementing an interpreter for a turing complete language
- Are notable in some other way (again, subjective)

---

If you're not familiar with programming in TypeScript's type system, the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html), [TypeScript Discord Server](https://discord.gg/typescript) (I'm @T6 there), and the [TypeScript Tips Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/237784/87606) are all great resources.

---

To claim a bounty, post a comment on this post with a link to your answer. If I don't respond promptly, feel free to ping me (@T6) in #random of the [TypeScript Discord Server](https://discord.gg/typescript), as I'm more active there.

---

### Awarded Bounties

- 100 rep for [user's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237788/95792) to [Convert Prefix to Infix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237574/convert-prefix-to-infix)
- 50 rep for [Jacob's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258114/87606) to [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58615/87606) (pending)

Comment: I hope my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237788/95792) to Convert Prefix to Infix qualifies.

Comment: I have a few here. [FizzBuzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz/258114#258114), [99 bottles of beer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64198/99-bottles-of-beer/256044#256044). Not expecting anything but a little more rep couldn't hurt :p

Comment: Is using [`hotscript`](https://github.com/gvergnaud/hotscript) (which makes the TS type system more like a traditional functional programming language) allowed?

Comment: @Jacob I'm going to say no external dependencies – I think it takes out a lot of the fun

Comment: @Jacob I'm glad to see someone else golfing in TS Types! FizzBuzz does indeed qualify per my original rules, but 99 bottles of beer has type errors. I've started a bounty on FizzBuzz. Let me know if you have any other qualifying answers :)

Comment: I think I've improved a lot since I posted those and other users have shown me some cool tips

Answer (score 6):

## 100 bounty: Minecraft redstone prime checker

What it says on the tin.

My version of a valid prime checker uses:

- levers as input (ON = 1, OFF = 0), representing a binary number
- redstone lamp as output (ON = prime, OFF = not prime)

I offer 100 reputation to make an expandable prime checker - that means that you can expand the prime checker in any direction infinitely, with minimal redstone wiring (connect the two "modules" together using redstone) and the prime checker still works.

You are allowed to use any block except for structure blocks and command blocks.

Do I need more clarification?

Comment: It is trivial to make a non-expanable that only takes one or two bits.  (or probably any non-expandable for that matter).  I don't want to tell you what to do with your rep but something tells me you might want to add a lower bound or remove the non-expanable category.

Comment: @WheatWizard That's a good point... fixing right now.

Comment: Can we use command blocks? structure blocks? If not could you include a specification for what blocks we can or cannot use.

Comment: where do I post?

Comment: @tuskiomi Post it on "Is this number a prime?" (link [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime)).

Comment: @tuskiomi Do you have a working prime checker?

Comment: @WheatWizard Fixed that.

Comment: Would a 32  bit prime checker be eligible for this bounty. Or is the expandable thing something you are set on.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala I would say you only get the rep if you make it "expandable". Making it non-expandable is much easier compared to the "expandable" thing.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp so would writing a prime checking program for the Universal turing machine be considered expandable if increased input could be realized with more blocks on the tape.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala No, because that's not really "expandable" - my definition of expandable is that two or more copies of the same prime checker, with minimal redstone wiring, should act as a bigger prime checker. I should probably clarify that.

Comment: IS this possible?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala That's why I'm offering a bounty for it. Besides, nothing's impossible on PPCG. I mean, look at Dennis's answers in Jelly.

Comment: I have partial progress. It's definitely possible, but the amount of time required is a barrier. I'm open to someone helping me. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34627269#34627269

Comment: can I use entity or mob_spawner?

Comment: @l4m2: I haven't used Minecraft properly in such a long time - are those commands?

Comment: I guess mob spawner was there for a long time, since command block wasn't there (from year 2010)

Comment: @l4m2 Oh you mean those mob spawners... I got tripped up with your underscore, I thought you meant commands or something. Yeah, sure you can use them.

Comment: I asked about that because if custom mob spawner(no command_block_minecart, assumed) is allowed, can make a turing machine in a finite space and no extra addin

Comment: `in any direction infinitely` any mean all or some?

Comment: Maybe you should make your restriction "theoretically rebuildable in Survival", that would exclude functions, cmd block minecarts, falling_block storing a cmd block, stuff in stored hotbars, etc.

Comment: @FabianRöling Yeah, sounds like a good restriction to make. Will fix.

Comment: I'm working on an idea that would take input in unary in the form of n items. This would also end up not being expandable by connecting multiple modules, but rather by trivially expanding the storage space for the machine's input and internal storage. Would these slight variations on the requirements be acceptable?

Comment: [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256083/92496)

Answer (score 6):

## 500 rep - Bubblegum Factorial

[Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum) is designed for constant output -  unless the code has a specific SHA-hash, you won't be able to write a program which takes input.

So, I will award 500 rep for a factorial program in Bubblegum. I don't really expect this to be fulfilled, as it requires major advances in cryptography to be possible.

If anyone ever completes this, post it as a submission to the [Factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial), where I will award the bounty.

Comment: So if someone solves decrypting SHA-256 this they could either decide to grab 25 bitcoins or get 500 reputation points on stackexchange.

Comment: @dylnan ... Why not both? ;)

Answer (score 6):

## 500 rep for a shorter payload capable V quine

Currently in V, there are two important quines:

```
2i2i
```

is the shortest known quine, but not modifiable. And

```
ñéÑ~"qpÿ
```

is the shortest known trivially modifiable quine. This is because

```
ñéÑ~"qp<CODE>ÿ
```

pretty much anything you want can go in the place of *CODE*, and it will still be a valid quine. You can see this on these answers:

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111209/31716
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107032/31716

Although these used a former version of the extensible quine, namely:

```
ñi<C-v>241<esc>"qpÿ
```

Either one could be easily modified to use this newer quine. Another good example is filling *CODE* with 'l's should always work. I will award this bounty to the first user to find a shorter extensible quine. For the purpose of this bounty, *extensible* means that any code you want to add to it will be recorded into some register and then pasted later, which is how the current solutions work (into register 'q' FWIW).

For completeness sake, I have found several 8-byte solutions:

```
ñéÑ~"qpÿ
ñéÑ~"qpx
ñéÑ~"qðÿ
ñéÑ~"qðx
ñ"qpÁÑ~x
ñ"qpÁÑ~ÿ
```

And many more trivial modifications that aren't worth posting. If you'd like more explanation on any of these, or want more examples, feel free to ping me in [TNB](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) or [Vim-Golf](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40448/vim-golf).

Answer (score 6):

## 100 rep for [Making a calculator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/568/basic-calculator) in GNU sed

Considering it is hard to even make addition in GNU sed, It is definitely worth a bounty.

Comment: I accept the challenge. What should be a minimum precision for division? This is not specified there. Also, do you have a time limit for a calculation? I ask because my submitted sed answer for the [1/x challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115528/59010) takes an incredible amount of time to finish, but is theoretically correct.

Comment: @seshoumara 4 under floating point/fractional output

Comment: @lol https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156290/34718

Comment: @mbomb007 Re "If you didn't cheat, it would fulfill a bounty. This needs to be deleted unless you fix it.": OP are not forced to award the bounty if they think that it doesn't deserve it anyway.

Comment: Exactly. So if the person fixed their program, it would win the bounty.

Comment: I know I'm late, but there's a sed calculator here: http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/dc.sed

Answer (score 6):

## 150 rep for a shorter C quine

Currently, the [shortest known C quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122856) (written by me) is <s>64</s> 60 bytes. I will give 150 rep to anyone who tops this.

Rules:

- Must be a full program (include the `main` function, or otherwise define main)
- Cannot use the filename to store data
- Cannot pull data from the internet
- Cannot read its source nor its executable ([thanks, Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122136/61563))
- Must be more than 1 byte (bytecount includes flags)
- Must be system-independent (you may assume POSIX and ASCII)

Comment: ... strictly more? Or at least? (anyway it's easily verifiable whether there is a 1-byte quine)

Comment: @user202729 do you have a proper 1-byte quine?

Comment: Does `X` count (must be compiled with `-DX=main()puts("X");`)?

Comment: @NieDzejkob No, that's a standard loophole.

Comment: @MDXF so if flags used, what to output?

Comment: @l4m2 If flags are used it's not just "C language", it's "C language with flags".

Comment: @user202729 `Must be more than 1 byte (bytecount includes flags)`

Answer (score 6):

## 900 rep for a shorter [Klein Topololyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/klein-topololyglots)

What it says on the tin, beat the current best and I'll give you 400 rep. (and 500 from me, Jo King)

Previous winners:

- August 15th 2017: [0                                                                                                              '](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139202/56656)
- August 29th 2018: [JoKing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171393/56656)

Comment: What if we prove yours is optimal?

Comment: @lirtosiast Personally I doubt it is, but a proof of optimality is also worthy of the bounty.

Answer (score 6):

## 500-2000 reputation for a golfy language

This bounty will be awarded to a new golfing language (more precisely, to an answer in that language by its author to [Showcase of Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-of-languages)) that

- Bests all pre-2019 languages by 10% or 2 bytes (whichever is greater) in 10 pure [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges.

  - The 10 challenges must be a subset of 100 consecutively posted challenges from before February 11, 2019.
  - No challenge of the 10 is written by the the language's author.
- Is on TIO.run.
- Has available documentation.
- Is otherwise sufficiently non-cheaty (at my discretion). Huffman coding is okay; builtins that don't generalize are not.
- All of the above remain true for 1 week.

The bounty amount doubles for every additional 10% improvement up to a 2000 rep, so a language that improves on all pre-2019 languages by 30% in each of the 10 challenges will be awarded the maximum 2000 rep; a 15% improvement nets 700 rep, and so on.

Comment: @A_ This is about language design, so to be eligible you must make significant contributions to the language.

Comment: @A_ Consecutively posted challenges are consecutive on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest. You must be the overall winner on each challenge by 10%, so if the shortest solution in a pre-2019 language is 22 bytes, your answer should be 19.8 bytes or shorter to count as one of the ten. Tying a pre-2019 language will mean that challenge doesn't count as one of the ten, but doesn't count against you.

Answer (score 6):

## 500 rep for the first engineered pattern in [Live a longer life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251510/live-a-longer-life/)

Currently, all the answers to [Live a longer life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251510/live-a-longer-life/), except the first few ones, are either found by soup search, or is a predecessor of other answers. They are discovered instead of constructed.

I offer 500 rep for the first answer with an engineered pattern. This mean that the pattern should be constructed from small parts and make use of the reactions between the parts. Some examples of engineered patterns can be found [here](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Engineered_diehard).

Answer (score 6):

## 50 reputation for first answers in FP languages

I find golfing in functional programming languages, and I'd like to get more people involved to make it more competitive.
Therefor I am offering 50 reputation for each user's first answer in:

- Haskell
- Curry
- Elm

You may claim all 3 bounties.

In order to be eligible the following criteria should be met:

- You don't have any answers in the language prior to this bounty. (The point is to encourage newcomers)
- You haven't claimed a bounty here in this language previously.
- The answer is sufficiently novel. If it is the first FP language submission to the challenge or if it out-golfs an existing answer in the same language that suffices.  If for example you simply port the existing Haskell answer to Curry by changing the pattern matching, that doesn't count.  Cases in between I will judge on a case-by-case basis.

Edit the list below to claim the bounty:

- `[username]: [challenge name](answer link) in Lang1, [challenge name](answer link) in Lang2`

Comment: [lesobrod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114511/lesobrod):  [Alternating factorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260120/alternating-factorial/260151#260151) in Curry

Answer (score 6):

## 200 reputation for golfing in [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal)

*Note that this is separate and distinct from the other Vyxal deadlineless bounty.*

Hi so Vyxal 3 exists and it's brand new and doesn't have very many answers at all. I think that needs to change, because it's a very cool language and y'all'll like it. In fact, I think you'll like it so much that you'll get free rep for using it! That's right free rep! Wonderful stuff!

And I don't mean the rep you get from upvotes. I mean I will give you 200 green points if you post five (5) Vyxal 3 answers. With 200 rep you can buy, well, uh, nothing because there's no rep-to-USD exchange, but still, that's like 20 upvotes. Much rep! Much wow!

Is this solicitation of golfers? Probably. Is it a form of bribery? Maybe. Will you end up wanting to stick around for more than 5 answers? I'm very confident you will!

Like last time:

Bounties will be suspended if rewarding the bounty dips my (lyxal's) reputation below 10k. If, on the off-chance, this bounty proves to be popular enough, I may adjust the rep I award to avoid completely tanking it.

A final note: If you've already claimed the Vyxal 2 bounty, cool. Those don't count towards this bounty, so you'll need to post 5 answers in Vyxal 3.

---

### Useful links

- [CGCC chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal)
- [Official interpreter](http://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/)
- [Repository (GitHub)](https://github.com/vyxal/Vyxal)
- [Tutorial](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/blob/version-3/documentation/Tour.md)
- [Tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267048/tips-for-golfing-in-vyxal-3)

### Claims

Format:

```
|**[$username](\$link)**| link1 | link2 | link3 | link4 | link5 | ❌ | ❌ |
```

*Make sure you put spaces before and after the links so that the markdown formatter converts them to question titles when rendering. Also, **leave the last two columns empty, those are for admin and keeping track of what's been bountied.**.*

| User | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3 | Answer 4 | Answer 5 | Posted (Which Post Number) | Awarded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **[Pacmanboss256](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96266/pacmanboss256)** | [Lolololololololololololol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/lolololololololololololol/267172#267172) | [Multiplicative persistence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181958/multiplicative-persistence/267151#267151) | [Count without 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98366/count-without-3/267150#267150) | [Determine your language's version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139243/determine-your-languages-version/267133#267133) | [Diagonal Alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125117/diagonal-alphabet/267132#267132) | ✅ (3) | ✅ |
| **[Fmbalbuena](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106959/fmbalbuena)** | [Find the Factorial!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial/267225#267225) | [Play the "bzzt" game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32267/play-the-bzzt-game/267228#267228) | [Count up forever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63834/count-up-forever/267229#267229) | [Even or odd: three player](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/even-or-odd-three-player/267230#267230) | [Drawing the Stack Overflow logo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224852/drawing-the-stack-overflow-logo/267265#267265) | ✅ (4) | ✅ |
| **[Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy)** | [Print the Christmas alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267039/42248) | [Limited letter renderer: BIOPD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267090/42248) | [How many paint tins do I need?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267138/42248) | [Finding the power sandwich](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267155/42248) | [80% of respondents agreed…](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267293/42248) | ✅ (2) | ❌ |
| **[math scat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/math-scatk)** | ["Perfect" an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269105) | [Output all the different counts of points](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268850) | [Can the chefs go?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267321) | [ASCII-art milk carton](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267306) | [Validate a CPF number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269172) | ✅ (5) | ❌ |

Comment: Cant edit the post but 
[1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/lolololololololololololol/267172#267172) 
[2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181958/multiplicative-persistence/267151#267151)
[3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98366/count-without-3/267150#267150)
[4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139243/determine-your-languages-version/267133#267133)
[5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125117/diagonal-alphabet/267132#267132)

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 oops forgot to make it community wiki

Answer (score 5):

## 100 rep for a neural network (or other new thing) that writes Moby Dick

This will be awarded in [Write Moby Dick,
approximately](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately) when one of the following conditions is met:

- an answer is posted based on neural networks and gets a reasonable score. (It doesn't need to compete with the top answers, just do reasonably well.)
- an answer is posted that takes a different method from the existing answers, in my subjective opinion. All the current top answers use variations on a Markov model (i.e. store substrings of length n and guess the most common next letter); I'm looking for an answer that does something significantly different from this. As above, this should score reasonably well but need not compete with the top answers.
- an answer is posted that (a) uses a sophisticated method (in my subjective opinion), and (b) has a good explanation of that method, where "good explanation" means I could implement it myself without reading the code. This bounty could be awarded to an existing answer, if one is updated with a good explanation.

Comment: Uh... -2. It seems that the community doesn't like it.

Comment: @user202729 that's... odd. But never mind, they don't need to - the bounty is between me and whoever would like to compete for it.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. No objective winning criterion.

Comment: @mbomb007 don't need one. It's a bounty. My rep, my discretion.

Comment: I'm saying that's why it's downvoted. It's a really unclear bounty. Poorly worded.

Comment: @mbomb007 your opinion is noted, but I don't share it, and I don't care about the downvotes in the slightest.

Comment: This looks like a job for [Andrej Karpathy's Magical LSTM](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/).

Answer (score 5):

## 50-500 rep for answering one of my challenges in one of my languages

**TL;DR:** I will bounty your answer if you answer one of my challenges using a language I made.

#### Eligibility

Eligible challenges are any of [my code-golf challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+user%3A16766+%5Bcode-golf%5D+-%5Btips%5D).

Eligible languages include any programming language that was primarily created and developed by me. As of April 5, 2024, that means [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), [Appleseed](https://github.com/dloscutoff/appleseed), [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), [Exceptionally](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Exceptionally), [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack), [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), [Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), [Sisi](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Sisi), [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), or [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr). If I make a new language in the future, feel free to ping me or update the list yourself.

**If there is already an answer to a challenge in a given language,** another answer in the same language is **not** eligible for a bounty **unless** it outgolfs the existing answer. If you further golf someone else's answer that already won this bounty, I'll decide case-by-case whether to award another bounty.

#### Amount

How big of a bounty I award depends on how difficult the challenge + language combination is. Here's a general difficulty ranking of the languages:

- Usable: Pip
- Reasonably usable: Appleseed, tinylisp, tinylisp 2
- Inconvenient: Exceptionally, FunStack, HBL, Ouroboros, Regenerate, Sisi, Zephyr
- Tarpit: *Acc!!*, BitCycle

But the difficulty also depends a lot on the challenge. Things that are trivial in Regenerate may be quite hard in tinylisp. And some challenges aren't easy in any language. Ultimately, the exact bounty amount comes down to my subjective judgment. You also get bonus points for a good explanation!

(A particularly jaw-dropping answer may get more than 500 rep. For example, if you solve [Tiny Lisp, tiny interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62886/16766) in *Acc!!*, you're getting at least 1000. =P)

If other factors (for example, whether I've previously bountied the question) prevent me from bountying the answer with the amount I would like, I will work out another arrangement with you. The ideal arrangement would be bountying an answer to a different challenge written in the same language.

Bounties will be paused if my rep drops below 20,000.

---

### Bounty Claims

- 

Format:

```
- [Challenge title](answer link) in language by [username](code golf user profile)
```

### Awarded

- [Ungolf my tinylisp code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247238) in tinylisp by [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a) (250)
- [Is it true? Ask Pip!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266192/92727) in *Acc!!* by [Command Master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master) (200)

Answer (score 4):

## 500 reputation bounty to the first Turing completeness proof or disproof for any answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111092/write-a-programming-language-of-unknown-completeness) based on proofs or disproofs of their respective conjectures

This is a long-term bounty which I am not making for the "lol"s.

I will create a 500 reputation bounty to the first answer to prove or disprove the Turing completeness of their program in this challenge. To celebrate the proving or disproving for any of the conjectures referenced in this challenge, I will *gladly* give a 500 rep bounty.

Comment: What if one of the conjectures is proved by an outside source?  Also just because a conjecture is no longer unproven does not mean that the answer is invalid.  I only require answers to be reliant on conjectures unproven at the time of posting.   If a proof arises later it is still a valid solution.

Comment: @WheatWizard This bounty relates to the TC proof, not the conjecture proof. They still have to prove stuff themselves.

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh! My apologies. This bounty is here for if any of those conjectures are proved, and if the answerer uses said proof to prove the TCness of their answer.

Comment: Hm, in that case, why favour proofs over disproofs? They will likely be equally impressive, no?

Comment: @MartinEnder Because they would then be unable to prove TCness. If they prove TCness without the conjecture, their answer is invalid anyway.

Comment: @VoteToClose I mean why is it more impressive to prove that the answer is TC (based on the conjecture) than proving that it *isn't* TC (because the conjecture turns out to be false)?

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh, I see your point. I still believe it to be more impressive as the answerer has to write a program to prove TC as well as apply what will likely be an incredibly difficult proof to their programming language. If you strongly suggest it, I wouldn't mind changing the scope of my bounty.

Comment: @VoteToClose honestly, I don't even *know* standard techniques for proving non-TC-ness of languages that have access to unlimited memory and non-trivial control flow.

Comment: @MartinEnder That's an excellent point I hadn't considered. Altering conditions.

Comment: @MartinEnder stimulate it with a non TC language (there are some very powerful non TC languages out there)

Answer (score 4):

## 400 reputation for an answer to [Paint Starry Night](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code) that takes top place without built-in compression

The bounty will be awarded to the first answer that takes first place (i.e. lowest score) without using an off-the-shelf compression routine. I'll award it even if it's immediately beaten by another answer. Currently the score to beat is 4159.06.

Answer (score 4):

## 200 rep for an Abstract Rewriting System under 100 points

This will be awarded to the first answer to [Abstract Rewriting Challenge (Cops)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157094/abstract-rewriting-challenge-cops) that scores less than 100 points and doesn't get cracked (or invalidated).

Answer (score 4):

## 100 rep for a Haskell answer to "[Make me some curry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162231/make-me-some-curry)"

I'll offer a 100 rep bounty for a Haskell answer to the above mentioned challenge. I might offer more than 100 rep for an interesting answer (for example not just copying the Idris answer or a clever TH answer).

Given that tuples are tricky with Haskell and that you can't use lists (can only contain one type), feel free to define your own data-type or use an appropriate one from an existing library on hackage.

**Note:** This bounty is tied to the one below, if someone gets the second bounty I will delete this one!

## 200 rep for a low-level answer (machine language, C or similar)

I'd love to see an answer that's really low-level, that's the main reason I allowed taking the number of arguments as input because otherwise it seems impossible.

Comment: For an answer in machine language, I need some way to know the type (or actually just the size) of the arguments. May I assume all arguments are of some constant size or may I get a list of argument sizes as extra argument?

Comment: Hi, is this bounty still going? I've posted a Haskell [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210999/95792) to that question.

Answer (score 4):

## 200 reputation for the true Alchemist

I don't know a lot about chemistry (nor alchemy), however - having written [Alchemist](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alchemist) - I'd be impressed if someone manages to use it as an actual chemistry tool:

If you manage to write a solution in [Alchemist](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alchemist) for the question [*Number of n-carbon alkanes*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178643/number-of-n-carbon-alkanes), I'll reward you with a bounty of 200 reputation.

---

<sub>Edit: Changed the language's specs slightly to make integer output easier, proper string literals & a forgotten feature printing whether a computation was deterministic (using `-d1`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XkHXTsHQoEJBWyG/tCS@ggtMggT9QYz////rphgCAA)</sub>

Comment: @PeterTaylor: That was a really annoying mis-feature of the language, I changed the specs as follows: `Out_"..."` will print the string `...` and `Out_xxx` will print the amount of `xxx` atoms. (I also changed the way string-literals get parsed, it now behaves as if it were a Haskell string-literal (eg. parsing `\n` instead of a real new-line or `\NUL` for null-bytes etc.)). (Couldn't fit the link into a message, editing it into the answer itself for the time being, until TIO pulls the latest commit)

Comment: @PeterTaylor: [TIO.run](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XkHXTsHQoEJBWyG/tCS@ggtMggT9QYz////rphgCAA) and [esolangs.org](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alchemist) are up-to-date now.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: What problems? If you have ghc installed an need help, let me know.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Oh wow, that's quite an old one. Instead of using `Data.Map.Strict` does `Data.Map` work? It shouldn't make a big difference. The other transformations you did seem sound.

Comment: That allows me to make progress; it also can't find `Data.Bifunctor` and suggests `Data.Functor`, which again allows me to make progress. Then there's a whole bunch of errors, a mixture of ambiguities between functions from `Data.List` and from `Data.Foldable`, and various methods not in scope (`sortOn`, `pure`, `first`, `second`, `<*>`). Meanwhile I've got my Python implementation finished and done some basic testing. I think I'm about ready to start the actual challenge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I'm terribly sorry about all this :( Pushed a change, that doesn't rely on `Data.Bifunctor`. I'm not sure about the ones with `List` and `Foldable`. I know where the issue with `pure` and `(<*>)` is, but tbh I'm not sure how to do a backwards compatible implementation just yet without rewriting lots just yet.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Sounds good, will do tmw. Created a new branch [here](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist/tree/old-ghc/) which could fix things (oldest version I should be able to test is ghc-7.8.4, but can't get it to work). Still not sure about the `List`/`Foldable` issues.

Comment: It is kind of interesting to see how Haskell is changing :) Btw. I can't see your changes to the esolangs entry.

Comment: Took me a while, but I [finally got it debugged and golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179641/194).

Answer (score 4):

## 500 rep for a ridiculously huge number

There are currently *no* valid answers to [Golf a number bigger than Loader's number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176966/golf-a-number-bigger-than-loaders-number). This bounty will be awarded to the valid first answer that either

- Is under 256 bytes, or
- Outputs a number significantly larger than Loader's number (i.e. larger than any simple modification to loader.c).

Comment: 256 bytes? Wow, that thing would probably win Bignum Bakeoff when it was made earlier.

Answer (score 4):

## 50-450 rep for answers in Scala

I'm giving out bounties for answers in Scala, an amazing language that is unfortunately rarely used here. Any Scala answers gets 50 rep from me, and if the following are met, you can get a bonus:

- Good explanation: +50-100
- Cleverly done: +50-200
- Wins challenge when posted: +100

The first two are subjective, but I'll try to be as fair as possible when awarding those. Also, I can only award the bounty if it won't cause my reputation to drop a privilege level. If I've already answered the same question or put a bounty on it, the bounty will have to be started on a different answer of yours.

Answer (score 4):

## 200 – 500 rep for outgolfing my [Fibonacci regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126373/am-i-a-fibonacci-number/178956#178956)

If you can write an ECMAScript (pre-2018, no lookbehind) regex that matches exactly the same set within the domain `^x*$` as my 161 byte regex, i.e. all nonnegative Fibonacci numbers in unary, I will award at minimum a 200 rep bounty. If it's a really significant reduction in size, or especially interesting mathematically, that bounty may increase (up to 500).

This was the first really large regex I ever wrote, and I think I've finally milked it dry golf-wise. But [I've been wrong before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110708/an-abundance-of-integers/178952#comment436018_178952).

Answer (score 4):

## 1000 rep for [\$\pi(n)\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94348/prime-counting-function/222468#222468) in unary ECMAScript regex

This is something I've been thinking about ever since 2014, and I haven't been able to get anywhere with it. See my answer to [Prime counting function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94348/prime-counting-function/222468#222468) for an explanation as to why I suspect it is impossible.

I will award 1000 rep (or 100-500 rep for **(4)**) for one of the following things regarding the implementation of \$\pi(n)\$ in a regex:

1. An implementation of \$\pi(n)\$ in one of the following regex flavors (see below), posted as an answer
2. A convincing explanation of an algorithm that could be used (which I could then set about implementing in a regex).
3. A proof that it is impossible in one of these flavors – the bounty will be awarded as soon as I can understand the proof, at least to some satisfying degree (which might involve some Q&A).
4. 100-500 rep for either **(1)** or **(2)** but using scratch space, where the amount of scratch space needed is less than \$O({n^2\over log(n)})\$, or equivalently less than \$O({n\pi(n)})\$, in its asymptotic growth. The scratch space will be provided as delimited unary, with your choice of delimiter character (i.e., the input to the regex will be \$n\$ in unary followed by a delimiter followed by the scratch space in unary). The amount of bounty will depend on how much less than \$O({n\pi(n)})\$ the required scratch space is, as well as the creativity/ingenuity of the solution. The regex should of course not be able to take its answer by measuring how much scratch space it's given – it should expect some random number will be added to the minimum required scratch for a given \$n\$, and for any amount of supplied scratch space of the minimum or higher, should always give the same answer.

The regex flavors (with scalar unary input and output):

- ECMAScript (pre-2018)
- ECMAScript with `(?*)` molecular lookahead / non-atomic lookahead, as supported by [RegexMathEngine](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)
- ECMAScript 2018, with `(?<=)` / `(?<!)` right-to-left evaluated variable-length lookbehind

Post it as an answer to [Prime counting function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94348/17216), even though for **(2)**, and **(4)** it's technically not one, since this is my only way of awarding the bounty. In the case of **(2)** or **(4).(2)**, once I've constructed the regex, I'll either post it as my own answer (giving credit to you for the algorithm), or as an edit to your post, whichever you prefer (if the latter, then please specify).

In the case of **(3)**, I guess the best way to do this is that you post the proof as an answer [to this CS.SE question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/137112/what-can-be-proven-regarding-the-differences-in-power-between-unary-ecmascript-r) or elsewhere, and tell me which post on CGCC you would like me to award the bounty to.

(Only 500 rep can be awarded at a time, so the 1000 will be awarded in two back-to-back bounties. Or in the case of **(3)**, to two different posts if you prefer.)

Comment: Since a proof wouldn't be a valid answer to that challenge, you might want to award the bounty to a different answer of whoever claims it.

Comment: Is the number of matches a valid output form, or must the output be the length of the first match?

Comment: @tjjfvi Thanks for the question. The output does indeed have to be the length of the first match and there needs to be only one match ("scalar unary output"). It would of course be trivial to output as the number of matches; just match all the primes not greater than *n*, `(?!(xx+)\1+$|x?$)`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that probably wasn't what you were looking for, but I thought I'd at least check.

Answer (score 4):

## 500-2500 reputation for a non-trivial answer to [Pristine Polyglots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/211839/66833)

The current - and only - answer is fairly trivial, exploiting the fact that multiple shell languages have almost identical behaviour for the `echo`.

I offer 500 reputation for an answer that uses 3 or more different languages such that each program in each language is non-trivial (i.e each program consists of different commands)<sup>*</sup>. Additionally, I will offer an additional 500 reputation if each answer provides a distinct, non-trivial output, and a further 500 reputation if this (that is, a program that qualifies for 1000 rep) can be extended to 7 or more languages.

<sup>*</sup>: Ultimately, "non-trivial" is a subjective quantifier. However, in this context, my judgement will qualify an answer, and a valid answer will consist of a program that is pristine in each language such that any given command in the program is likely to perform a different function in each language, but overall, the function should be the same for every language.

Furthermore, I'm willing to increase the bounty amount by either 500 or 1000 reputation, depending on how impressive I find the answer.

---

To claim the bounty, don't worry about notifying me - I should receive the notification when you answer. If the bounty hasn't been set within a week of your answer, leave a comment, or ping me in chat.

Answer (score 3):

## 50 reputation [for an Hello World version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/50239) that consist of a Google’s native client executable.

These are just elf files. but with special calling conventions.

- the file should be less than 1000 bytes.
- the file should contains runnable code without modifications. So it must be a .nexe or a shared object.
- a +10 bonus if the elf file targets the armelv7 architecture *(provided google chrome should load it on chrome os for arm).*

Comment: I don't believe you can offer a 60 rep bounty so I am not sure what you mean by the +10 bonus.

Comment: @WheatWizard : the upvote ?

Comment: @user2284570 Upvotes are not for doing something extra you wanted, they're for when you think a submission is clever/valid/good/golfy.

Answer (score 3):

### More unsuitable language bounties: 2 x 500

*Similar in spirit to [lirtosiast's bounties](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8219/42963)*

- 500 rep for an answer in [Mornington Crescent](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent) to [Somewhere On The Tube ...But On Which Lines?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/142331/42963)
- 500 rep for an answer in [Hexagony](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony) to [HexaRegex: A Tribute to Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87482/42963)

Comment: I'll add another 500 to the HexaRegex.

Answer (score 3):

## 500 rep for a Brain-Flak answer to [Balance the Brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114219/balance-the-brackets)

The challenge is clearly brain-flak related, and should have a brain-flak answer, though this is understandably difficult.

Comment: I was looking into this. First thought: *Oh surely it couldn't be **that** bad.* Then I realized that Damerau-Levenshtein includes swapping. Second thought: *Holy \*\*\*\*, I don't think anyone will ever be able to do this.*

Answer (score 3):

## 200-400 rep for discompassionate geometry

[Construct a pentagon avoiding compass use](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188333/39328) is about finding a compass-and-straightedge construction of a regular pentagon while minimizing the number of circles drawn.

The [Poncelet-Steiner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%E2%80%93Steiner_theorem) says that any construction possible with a compass and straightedge is possible with *one* circle, its center, and a straightedge. Finding such a construction is another matter.

Because the construction rules in this challenge are slightly different from the premises of the theorem (arbitrary points cannot be drawn in this challenge, which necessitates a second circle to construct anything nontrivial), it will not be valid for that challenge. Nevertheless, 200 rep goes to the first answer to that challenge that both:

- Contains a construction in 1 circle (which necessarily includes adding arbitrary points) and makes a reasonable effort to golf the number of points and lines drawn
- Also contains a valid solution or a proof of optimality of the [current best](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188337/39328) solution.

If the answer is an improvement on the current best or a proof of optimality, I will award an additional 200 rep.

Comment: I don't understand: in what situation would you only be giving 200 rep?

Answer (score 3):

## 50-250 rep for first answers in [ThumbGolf](https://github.com/easyaspi314/thumbgolf)

In celebration of ThumbGolf leaving pre-alpha, I will give the first [ThumbGolf](https://github.com/easyaspi314/thumbgolf) answer per user a bounty.

I will be following similar rules to Adám's APL challenge.

Specifically:

- The program must **not** be a normal Thumb-2 program. It must make use of the ThumbGolf runtime.

  - Specifically, if I remove all ThumbGolf instructions, the program should not solve the challenge.
- Only a user's first ThumbGolf answer will count.
- The user must not be a  New contributor to avoid giving the rep to alt accounts
- I will reward between **50-250 rep** depending on how much I like the solution **and its explanation.** Don't blow it on something lame.
- I will give this **a maximum of 5 times** (unlike my ACE challenge). If the bounty will make me lose a privilege level, I will queue it.

Answer (score 3):

## 50-200 rep for interesting [zsh](https://www.zsh.org) answers

I will award this if:

- the answer is interesting
- you have not been awarded this bounty before
- it will not cause me to go below a privilege level

Possible bonuses if:

- a particularly good explanation is provided
- it is the first answer to the question
- it out-golfs me

Comment: Hi, is this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220236/alphabet-printing-challenge/220311#220311) eligible for a +50 bounty?

Comment: @Wasif not as an answer to your own challenge I'm afraid (especially since it wasn't a particularly interesting question)

Comment: Does this apply to zsh answers that also work in bash, or do they have to use at least one uniquely zsh feature?

Comment: @AviFS yes a Bash polyglot is fine, but it mainly depends how interesting it is ;)

Answer (score 3):

## 500 rep for a Vim answer to [Sticky Polyhexes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222709/sticky-polyhexes)

What it says on the tin. An explanation would be appreciated.

Language must be Vim, not the V derivative. Good luck!

You may use bash commands in your script, but only commands which are in vanilla bash(no coreutils).

Comment: If this ever gets claimed, the answer's going to be a strong candidate for yearly Best Of.

Answer (score 3):

## 50-200 rep for good programming puzzles

We need more [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) questions! If you post a good one, I'll give you between 50 and 200 rep depending on how interesting it is to me.

I may decide to wait until someone posts a solution, and/or until your intended solution is revealed, before deciding to award a bounty.

I will decide to award one only if I see fit, not upon request, but if you think I might have missed your question (it's more likely I just wasn't interested in it (nothing personal)), you can message me in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240).

I will not award bounties if the rep decrease will cause me to lose SE privileges.

Since bounties can only be awarded on existing answers, not existing questions themselves, you need to have at least 1 answer to receive this.

Answer (score 3):

## 500 rep for another answer to [Print this text in Scala](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229970/print-this-text-in-scala)

hyper-neutrino's found an answer already, but it isn't the intended one. I'll award a 500 rep bounty to anyone who does it without using comments or multiple calls to `print`. Brownie points if it's the exact same as mine (not including spacing, of course).

Update:
pxeger's also found an answer, but that isn't the intended one either. I'll award another 500 rep bounty to anyone whose code goes inside a single call to print (no `def`s or commented lines outside it).

Note that I don't want an answer that's the same as mine, and would prefer for it to be different, I'd just like to see a more interesting approach than printing the text and then dealing with the `>)` part outside of the original call to `print`.

Comment: [Done!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229973)

Answer (score 3):

## 500 rep for a shorter Hello, World in Lost

The Hello, World record in lost [dropped to 36 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137699/56656).  Since then I have been trying to get it lower.  I'm willing to give 500 reputation to anyone who can come up with a Hello World in 35 bytes or less.

It must be a valid answer to [the hello world challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world).  It must deterministically print the exact string `Hello, World!`.

## 100 rep for an answer in Lost

As a more general incentive for programming in Lost I am offering 100 rep for any answer in Lost.

Broadly speaking any Lost answer to any challenge which does not already have a Lost answer is eligible.  However I reserve the right to deny the bounty to any "cheaty" answers.  This includes

- answers to questions which seem to have been asked just so that one can cash in on this bounty
- answers to questions which have extremely lax validity criteria. For example making a cop on a cops and robbers challenge will probably not get you this bounty.

As long as your answer is, in lost, works, and shows a baseline amount of effort I would be happy to award this bounty.

If you are looking for a place to start here are some questions that I think are answerable in Lost.

- [A Chiral Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172005/a-chiral-puzzle)
- [Happy Birthday Caird Coinheringahing Chartz Belatedly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231525/happy-birthday-caird-coinheringaahing-chartz-belatedly)
- [I'm a Lizard Cut Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231858/im-a-lizard-cut-here)

[source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) is a pretty good tag to browse to find more of these.

I may not be able to create a 100 rep bounty on the question you have answered.  If this is the case we can work something out.  If your answer is particularly impressive or inventive I will probably just award it more than 100.

Answer (score 2):

## 200 rep for n > 10 for my [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165504/delete-some-bits-and-count) challenge

This is a long-bounty. I will award 200 reputations  to the first answer which gets a score of `n=11` or better for my challenge.

Comment: I upped the challenge :)

Comment: I won't edit myself as I don't want to assume which is your intended amount, but the 200 in the title doesn't match the 100 in the body.

Answer (score 2):

## 200 rep for a low-entropy maximal discrepancy-2 sequence

[Compress a maximal discrepancy-2 sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122304/39328) is about compressing a particular discrepancy-2 sequence.

[Maximal discrepancy-2 sequence with minimal entropy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123228/39328) is about finding a maximal discrepancy-2 sequence that's easier to compress.

This bounty will be awarded to an answer meeting all the following conditions:

- It is the shortest answer to question 2
- It is at least 3 bytes shorter than the shortest answer to question 1
- Both of the above remain true for 1 week.

Comment: Does it have to be three bytes shorter than the shortest answer overall, or just 3 bytes shorter than the shortest corresponding answer in the same language?

Comment: @Dennis To the shortest overall.

Answer (score 2):

## 50 rep for each first sed answer

If these conditions are met:

- Giving away this bounty does not make me go below 400 rep.
- The question has at least 3 total upvotes
- The answer is the first answer for that question
- It's not [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling)
- The answer has at least 1 total upvote
- I approve (I probably will)
- The answer is in POSIX or Gnu sed, and I'm less likely to award the bounty if it uses `e` unnecessarily.

Comment: So currently, you can only give it once…

Comment: @Adám yes, but I'm working on that :)

Comment: Returned after a long time, I wonder if I qualify with an old answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113573/59010

Comment: [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256277/108218).

Comment: @Ginger sorry this is only for when the sed answer is the first answer to the question.

Comment: @Wezl' I thought it meant "first" as in "first sed answer by you"

Answer (score 2):

## 100 rep for interpreting a TC language in [Tarfish](https://github.com/chunkybanana/tarfish)

Answers should go to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111278/turing-complete-language-interpreter). Add a comment to this as well.

Some ideas:

- https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag
- Any [tag system](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Tag_system)
- Anything implemented in the linked question
- [FRACTRAN](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fractran)

Answer (score 2):

## 250 Reputation

I will give anyone who writes a working answer in **C** (not C++), for [Jam don't add like that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/81165/jam-dont-add-like-that).

### Condition

The input must be taken as integers, not as char pointers (or strings)

NOTE: Comment to receive your reputation

Comment: I assume that when you say "the input must be taken as integers," you mean a pointer to some data structure containing integers?

Comment: @DLosc yes ....

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263325/73593

Answer (score 2):

## 100-200 reputation for the first crack of my ["Find my other token" answer in Husk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242349/95126)

I will offer a 100 rep bounty for the first crack of this, or 200 rep if it's the cracker's first Husk post.

Answer (score 2):

## 200 rep for Chef answer to [Can the chefs go?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267313/can-the-chefs-go)

I will award a 200 reputation bounty to the first person to submit a working solution to "Can the chefs go?" in [Chef](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Chef).

Comment: This is extremely hard to do btw, I tried

Answer (score 1):

## 500 rep for a [SILOS](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S) submission of a [2048 clone](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24134/46918).

I'll even throw in a bonus 250 rep bounty (and of course give a week of bonus visibility). for one that has gui output (this is harder than it sounds). Feel free to use the [developer tools](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.D.E), which integrate into this language nicely.

## 50 rep for outgolfing me in the language (ping me in the nineteenth byte, and give me one week to attempt the challenge.)

So that you can police me, we both submit our submission concurrently.

Comment: Queues, GOTOs, definitely tryable. *goes and starts solving*

Comment: @SIGSEGV thanks, good luck.

Comment: In the GitHub page I see Keyboard Binding, and Graphics. Oh yes, this would be good.

Comment: @SIGSEGV, this would come out top notch, it would be so much better than the next best game written (Snake). You can use colored tiles and have a color key.

Comment: Yup. Thought of that too.

Answer (score 1):

## 150 rep for the winning submission on the winning team of [Team of The Hill!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117482/58826)

Rules:

- The winning submission is the bot on the winning team with *the most kills* at the end.

To claim the rep, comment below:

Comment: You cannot place two **+50** bounties on the same question. Every time you offer another bounty, you have to double the amount, up to the limit of **+500**. Also, since you posted an answer yourself, the first bounty must be **+100** or higher.

Comment: Finally, if these bounties are going to be awarded at a specific moment, they're not really bounties with no deadlines.

Answer (score 1):

## 100 rep for beating me in the Cardinal code challenge

What it says on the tin.  Beat my [Brain-Flak answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137599/56656) (in Brain-Flak of course) and I'll give you 100 rep.

Comment: I had a stab at this just now, and it is deceptively difficult.

Answer (score 1):

## 50 rep for the shortest "Hello, World!" in Pepe

If you can beat [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156764/72792), I will pass a 50 bounty for you.

I don't really believe a shorter solution exists - prove me wrong and you'll get it. My solution uses character constants which are probably the shortest way to push a number in Pepe. However, they are binary, so they span a lot of bytes - outgolfing it *might* be possible. Another problem is that most function pop the stack by default...

- If it will be really hard (it will), I'm might even pass a 100 rep bounty.

Answer (score 1):

## Up to 450 rep for answering [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness) in Whispers

I'm offering a 150 rep bounty to anyone who posts a competitive (in my view) answer to [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness) using [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers). In addition, I will award a further 300 reputation if the answer is proven to be optimal.

Rules:

- You may use any version of Whispers, but the bounty will only be awarded once total, not once per version
- A competitive answer means you can't just post an answer claiming a score of "number of Unicode characters", rather it has to be an actual attempt at competing. This is subjective, but ultimately, I won't award the bounty to a low-effort answer
- Whispers is currently not known to be TC (I only think it is), so if it's proven to be Turing-incomplete, let me know, I'll make the latest version TC and the bounty will be up for grabs.
- Using the eval command `⍎` is forbidden (to claim the bounty, not to post an answer to the challenge)
- Comment, or ping me in chat, to claim the bounty, as well as posting an answer to the challenge, so I can judge and award it.

Comment: Do you have any docs or tutorials for Whispers?

Comment: More specifically, is there any mechanism where calling a line repeatedly may give different results (i.e. mutable state)? Looks like the while loops are useless other than producing a trivial infinite loop, so I think it can only be TC by calling Python eval via `⍎`. (And I think I have a proof that Python eval (as opposed to arbitrary program) is TC without Python 3.8's inline assignment.)

Comment: [Posted an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210391/78410). Looks like eval will have the best score even if there are language-internal ways to achieve TC.

Answer (score 1):

## 200 rep for a 2D Language answer to [Rotation-safe quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121522/80214) - [Claimed by Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225545/80214)

What it says on the tin. You can use any language which uses two-dimensional syntax (Fish, Befunge, Klein, Labyrinth, etc) to create it. It must be a proper, valid quine and the language must have been made before this bounty offer had been posted.

The bounty value may increase based on the "impressiveness" of the answer. Explanations are appreciated!

Comment: I'll fork over another 500 if that 2D language is Lost.

Comment: @WheatWizard it's already been claimed, but I can add in a bounty for Lost if you want.

Answer (score 1):

## 50 repz for first answer to [99 bottles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64198/99-bottles-of-beer) in [jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage)

Comment: For a challenge like this one with many answers, it's easiest to pop `inquestion:64198 jelly` in the search bar. The bounty is open!

Comment: @Dingus i keep forgetting about inquestion oops. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

## 500+500 Rep for beating my infinitely busy beavers

Specifically for an answer that outperforms my 5 state or 4 state answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241864/longest-infinite-loop-in-5-states). I *refuse* to believe that they are optimal, however if they are, I'll give the respective bounties to whoever proves that they are optimal.

Answer (score 1):

## 100-600 rep for answering [Draw the Biohazard Symbol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191294/draw-the-biohazard-symbol?noredirect=1&lq=1) in Desmos (both [completed by fireflame241](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191294/draw-the-biohazard-symbol/246880#246880))

I'm offering 100 rep for the first answer to the linked question in desmos.

Additionally, I'm offering 500 rep for an answer that uses a single equation to express the symbol.

Comment: [Completed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246880/68261) including the one-liner

Answer (score 1):

## 100 rep for first valid answer to [Clone GNU `cat` 8.32](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267392/clone-gnu-cat-8-32)

Any serious contender qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

## 250 and 500 rep for the next two decent TIO [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) golfs

"Decent" here meaning in beating any solution on [this page](https://rosettio.github.io/Hello%20World) by at least 25%. Bounty may be awarded if under 25% if solution is especially impressive (subjective) - for example, if golfing in a language is particularly difficult.

Note: jimmy23013 appears to be on track to claim both bounties right now - they will probably be awarded after the current one ends unless a more impressive solution appears.

Comment: For your C# interactive program, `Write("Hello, World!")` is shorter than what you have right now, at 22 bytes

Comment: oh, true, will change soon

Comment: Can you add l33t?

Answer (score 0):

### 100 rep to the shortest [GNU sed 4.2.2 `-r`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) answer <70b to [Count up forever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63834) outputting in decimal

The program must output in decimal. You must use the `-r` flag, although with no penalty to the bytecount. The GNU sed version is 4.2.2, so you can use empty labels. The program must be less than 70 bytes.

[As is the standard for sed in no-input challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5477) like this one, you are only given a newline as input.

The program cannot use the `e` (shell execute) command, nor the `e` flag to `s`, nor anything else that I consider cheating that I may have missed here.

The way the bounty awarding works is that soon after I see a valid answer I will start the bounty. When the bounty is nearing its end (about a week hence), I will award it to the then shortest valid answer I see, which may not be to the first valid answer. So even if person A was the first to post a valid answer, and I start the bounty a day later, and then if person B posts a shorter valid answer 3 days into the bounty and noone matches it up, I will award the bounty to person B.

Comment: I wonder if this way of awarding bounties is good or if it stifles participation. Maybe I should just award to the first valid answer?

Comment: [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256277/108218). Complies with all listed rules.

Comment: Hey @Ginger, sorry I didn't specify but you can't take any input (for sed, the standard we have is the newline `echo | sed -f program`; see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5477).

Comment: Darn. It was worth a shot though!

Answer (score 0):

## 100 rep for finding a two byte* solution to [Is it a lipogram?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73828/is-it-a-lipogram)

Rules:

- Use a language created** before this bounty
- Solve [Is it a lipogram?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73828/is-it-a-lipogram) in two bytes *or less
- **If the language is still in development, you may use any version of the language published before this bounty. (EDIT: bugfixes after this post are fine lol just dont cheat pls)
- Two bounties will be awarded, first come first serve:
- <s>If you take the longer string input as an array of characters***, you get the 50 rep bounty</s> [claimed!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73828/is-it-a-lipogram/252956#252956)
- If you take both inputs as strings***, you get the 100 rep bounty
- ***I recognize that an array of characters *is* a string, but the distinction I intend to make here is as follows:
- If the user has to manually place spaces or commas (or some other delimiter) between each character of the string they intend to input, it is an "array of characters" for our purposes. If no delimiter between each character is required to be entered by the user, it is a "string" for our purposes
- Just bug me on this post to claim the bounty and ill add it soon as im online
- <s>Yes you can get both bounties at once lol</s> no longer relevant

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. I just think there should be a solution in two bytes or less. My idea would be something like `ToLowerCaseAll GetIndexOf` for some stack language, but this has not been shown to be possible yet. Sorry if you intend to include these operators in your upcoming language, I'm still looking forward to it, <s>and I'll take my check in the mail.</s>

Comment: I [claim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252956/107299) the 50 rep bounty using Fig, 1.646 bytes. Uses `EqualsIgnoreCase Any`

Answer (score 0):

## 200-400 Rep for Sub-Quadratic Trilangle Meta-Cat

I just submitted [a Trilangle answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267393/106545) for the meta-cat [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) question. I am offering a bounty to an answer that meets the following criteria:

- Baseline +200 for a program that

  - has an output that grows asymptotically slower than \$O(n^2)\$ on the size of the input,
  - gives a shorter output than my answer for at least one of the test programs, and
  - can handle spaces in the input and empty input, since those aren't covered in the tests.
- An additional +100 if the code is on a grid of size 15 or smaller (my code is on a grid of size 14).
- An additional +100 if the code does not rely on any "implementation-defined" or "undefined" behavior. You can check this with the "Errors" field of the online interpreter, and both the program itself and its output program matter.

If an answer takes the baseline +200 but not the additional +100 bonus(es), I will award an individual +100 to an answer that meets both the baseline criteria and the unclaimed bonus.

Answer (score 0):

## 100 rep for [golfing a PSK31 modulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268591/golf-a-psk31-modulator) and using it on the air

I will award 100 reputation to the first amateur radio operator to post an answer to "[Golf a PSK31 modulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268591/golf-a-psk31-modulator)," make a QSO on any amateur band using your submission to transmit, and show a screenshot to document the QSO. You may block out call signs for anonymity if desired.

Answer (score -9):

## 500 reputation bounty - for cracking [this whitespace cop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103475/46918)

As computers get faster and faster or other mathematical developements arise (sorry can't entirely give away the premise), this may become crackable. At any such time I will award the mathematical genius 500 reputation points.

Comment: The "premise" is factoring a large semiprime - this is roughly equivalent to the RSA problem.