# Why is the no deadline bounties post not featured?

Tags: discussion, bounty

[This post, "List of bounties with no deadline"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline) is a collection of, well, bounties without a deadline.

It's not featured, and I wonder why? It's a very useful and important community post. I personally think it should be permanently featured like sandbox. (however like the sandbox, it's sometimes edited and thus bumped). But still, shouldn't it be featured?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No it shouldn't be featured. There's only so much space in the sidebar. I think 4 or maybe 5 questions is the maximum. Occasionally one of them is a blog post and/or a feature post on Meta.SE. Then the sandbox is permanently featured. And we've occasionally got another important announcement that needs to be featured. That leaves one lot for regular "hot meta posts". As neat as the bounty post is, I don't think it's important enough to take up another slot. It's something that is only really relevant to PPCG "power users" who are looking for an extra challenge, and these users are likely active enough that they've found out about the bounty list on their own.

(As an aside [I *would* like software support for indefinite bounties](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8433/8478) which would likely also make them a lot more discoverable, but that's not something that's in our power.)

Comment: Space issues aside, I'm not sure if a collection of the most difficult tasks on PPCG is the first thing we'd want to shove in a new user's face.

Comment: I don't think it should be featured either, but I disagree with this _"It's something that is only really relevant to PPCG "power users" who are looking for an extra challenge"_. I'd say many of those are only relevant to very skilled programmers, and showcasing such questions might draw the attention of new "power users". Examples: [Shortest maze exit string](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53310), [Tetris in Conway's GoL](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11880), [Freecell solver](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/43150), and in general all the challenges that are not shortest code.

Comment: It's unfair how blog and hot meta posts count as taking sidebar space. It'd be better if it was 5 but only counting "featured on meta".

Comment: To prove [my point](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111932/31516)! [dim](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64412/dim) had only 5 answers prior to that one... Not exactly a power user :)

Comment: (Oops, it wasn't on the list,,, but it could very well have been, so I'd claim my point is still valid :P )

Comment: @Dennis "I'm not sure if a collection of the most difficult tasks on PPCG is the first thing we'd want to shove in a new user's face" --- I don't see why not, actually. If a new user comes here looking for the hardest challenges, they're probably someone you want to keep.