# Can I get my rep back?

Tags: support

This is my second PPCG account and I deleted my first due to how unpleasant I found the site. My first account had around 500 rep and I was wondering if I could get that rep and put it onto my current account. I can't find any questions like this but thought it would be an issue.

Obviously it isn't a life-or-death kind of problem but I just think it would be a nice ego boost to see the rep counter increase by 500 at once.

Does anyone know if I can do this? My old account posted [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107598/draw-an-asciirisk) question and the current username SE calls it is `user63571` if that helps in any way?

Comment: It appears [deleted accounts can only be restored (to a new account) if it was moderator error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283926/266052). So, since you deleted yours yourself, it cannot be restored.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107598/draw-an-asciirisk I remember this conversation! The bad jokes though... What was your old username again?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino "Me" IIRC

Answer (score 1):

The [help center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) goes over this:

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

Now, for what it's worth, you won't be taking rep from your other account, but rather taking that account and your current account, and merging them together. All of your old questions/answers on that account will now be associated with your current account.

If you want to get your rep back *without* merging the accounts, I'm afraid this is not possible. If you'd like to gain a lot of rep quickly, a great way is too look into earning [a bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243/31716), or making more challenges/answers.

Comment: Does that work if I've deleted one of those accounts?

Comment: @ThisGuy I'm not sure. Since that question isn't really specific to PPCG, you could consider posting it on [mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com).