# How should we edit questions which have non-expiring bounties attached to them?

Tags: discussion, editing, bounty, formatting

Just like we have a format for answering code golf, cracking cops and robbers, and posting most challenges, I am curious as to what (if any) format we should have for questions that have [bounties with no deadline](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline).

Some things to consider:
Where in the question should the notice be added?
What text information is important for the question reader?
Should it link to the meta question?
Should it always be posted on the question, or are answer applicable, too?
Should the title of the question be edited to indicate a bounty?
Should this even be standardized?

How should we edit questions which have non-expiring bounties attached to them to indicate that a bounty is being offered?

Comment: This should be two different meta posts IMO: "Do we want a standardized text block" and "Do we want them to be tagged?"

Comment: @NathanMerrill good Idea.

Comment: On the basis of the title I thought this question was about avoiding edits to the question which invalidate the bounty by making it impossible to fulfil the conditions.