# Conclusive opinion on having a Hello, World! feed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat, rss

[This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14636/66833) question asks about the possibility of adding a [feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?tab=feeds) to [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) that posts new answers to the [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) thread - a typical place for people to first introduce their new programming languages.

There are currently three answers to that [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), none of which are conclusive, advocating for ["In a different chatroom"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14638/66833), ["Yes, as a ticker feed"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22374/66833) and ["Yes, as a message feed"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22396/66833). The first one was posted 3 years ago, its current room suggestions are unfeasible (frozen for years due to inactivity) and is unlikely to be of any success - chat rooms outside of TNB are unlikely to succeed. However, the other two advocate for a system which may prove to be disruptive or irritating. This has lead to an inconclusive and somewhat partially outdated discussion, that could do with a definitive answer

Therefore, this is designed to be that *conclusive* opinion on this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Post your opinions below, with definitive answers and we can settle this discussion after 3 years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, as a regular chat feed.

It is important to consider what the purpose of this feed is in the first place. A lot of people use Hello, World! as an entry point to use a new language since it is a simple and well-known problem that also may not be trivial in many languages, especially the more esoteric and interesting ones.

Therefore, having a feed will allow us to see these new languages (and often new users) and welcome them to the site or learn more about this language. Essentially, it is to raise visibility to new positive contributions.

Thus, first of all, it would be nice to have a permanent display. Ticker feeds only show to people already in the room, and if you weren't there, too bad, you missed it. Additionally, the post may also prompt some discussion in the chat room if it's a particularly unique language, and a message feed offers context, whereas a ticker feed would make the transcript confusing as everyone would just suddenly start talking about something totally unrelated.

Finally, if problematic posts show up, we can remove the feed messages quite easily, whereas tickers can only be dismissed by the client, and so if someone is AFK in the chat room, they don't have to see said posts. If the feed posts a lot at once, which I believe is a largely unapplicable concern now anyway (it doesn't get answers *that* frequently), we can also trash all of those messages.

If it proves to be too disruptive, it takes a few clicks to completely undo it. So I say, let's go ahead with it. In the worst case scenario, we'll have a solid answer to this question.