# "Voidhawk's well-explained answer was the first one here in APL"?

Tags: discussion, bounty

The phrase "Voidhawk's well-explained answer was the first one here in APL" appears in 3 featured questions on PPCG with an active bounty.

It seems out of place and I'm not sure what it means.  Does it mean voidhawk was awarded a bounty on all of these featured questions?

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/42963

Comment: Maybe I should add a comment to posts that have a pending bounty, saying [+100 rep for an APL answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/42963)?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Sounds like an answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise I could use markdown in the reason for a bounty. I'll make sure to link to the meta post in the future.

Comment: Yes... something to indicate how to participate in the bounty would be great. As a guy with a rep of 13, I only notice bounties when they appear on the featured tab.  @Adam, could you post your link as an answer to this question, or alternatively a link to where users can find a list of all active bounties?

Comment: @Adám Sorry for the shortness, didn't have time to post an answer until now, but I wanted to provide some help and had the link handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### They are a result of an indefinite bounty

[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m) posted a [list of bounties](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/42963) for challenges to be answered in a flavor of APL, on our List of Bounties with No Deadline. [voidhawk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85183/voidhawk) subsequently answered those challenges, and Adám (is currently in process of) awarding those bounties.

Comment: Your reason for the bounty on [Lookalike Shapes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/56024/85383)  is very clear and well-worded