# Language of the Month for February 2021: Whispers

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others<sup>*</sup>, we have a new featured language! Throughout February 2021, our Language of the Month, nominated by myself (caird coinheraahing) will be:

> ## Whispers

<sub><sup>*:</sup> It was a close race between 4 different languages, but [it seems that](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56922085#56922085) at 00:00 UTC Feb 1st, Whispers was ahead.</sub>

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during February, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Whispers, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Whispers

Whispers is a rather unique programming language in how it executes a program. Rather than running line-by-line or command-by-command, Whispers only executes the last line in the program by default. All other lines are only run when referenced by either the last line, or by a line referenced by the last line (and so on).

Each line in the program is made up of a single builtin, meaning that most complex programs consist of a lot of linked lines and passed values. Most of the builtins are math-centric (especially in the latest version), so it is especially strong at [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) challenges.

The syntax rules that filter out invalid lines allow it to be very useable in polyglots and related challenges.

Especially with the latest version, Whispers is very powerful, including a built in calculus engine, along with the ability to run and evaluate arbitrary mathematical expressions. Furthermore, it now has support for common sequences, a massive builtin library of functions and a large collection of builtin operators and constants

Finally, the basic nature of the language/syntax could potentially lead to some interesting challenges themed around it.

#### Resources

- [Github repo](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers)
- TryItOnline! : [version 1](https://tio.run/#whispers) and [version 2](https://tio.run/#whispers2). [repl.it](https://repl.it/@caird/Whispers-1) for version 3 (requires a repl.it account to fork)
- [Tutorial](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/blob/v2/tutorial.md), up to date to v2
- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119194/whispers)
- [Wiki](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/wiki), including the list of commands and a more in depth tutorial

#### Bounty

Answers in Whispers will be eligible for a bounty of 50 rep if you have not posted an answer in Whispers before. Sorry, but if it's a question that I (caird coinheringaahing) have already answered, I'll only award the bounty to an exceptional answer, since it starts at 100 rep.

Furthermore, there is [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19267/66833) deadline-less bounty for proving the Turing-Completeness of the language.

Answer (score 4):

## List of all Whispers solutions posted in Febrary 2021

(First time posters highlighted in bold)

- [Sum of primes between given range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218571/80214) by **[Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)**
- [Fibonacci-orial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86944/fibonacci-orial/218597#218597) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Round towards zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/round-towards-zero/218598#218598) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Am I being run backwards?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195551/am-i-being-run-backwards/218601#218601) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Output Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218498) by **[Leo](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62393)**
- [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218542) by [Leo](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62393)
- [Calculate golden ratio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218617) by **[Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)**
- [Output a googol copies of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218651) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- ["DDoouubbllee ssppeeaakk!!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218656) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [Draw an ASCII-art rainbow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218721/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [“Factorise” a quadratic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218741/95126) by **[Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)**
- [Find the nth digit of Euler's number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204718/find-the-nth-digit-of-eulers-number/218747#218747) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Shortest method to implement the Pythagorean Theorem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20115/shortest-method-to-implement-the-pythagorean-theorem/218748#218748) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Draw an ASCII-art rainbow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218796/62393) by [Leo](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62393)
- [Do you make me up?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218863) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218877) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [Have you learned your fib-abc?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218973/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Output Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218380/78850) by **[Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)**
- [Denominator of harmonic series](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219288/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [N-dimensional pyramid numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219317/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Don't google “google”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219475) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219537) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [Output Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219624) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [Reverse stdin and place on stdout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219754) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [Your challenge is to make a script that reverses a word then replaces letters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219798) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- [Print a 10 by 10 grid of asterisks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219886) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of all Whispers tips posted in February 2021

- [Use Then to group values into an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218746/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Order is important](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219842/80214) by [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
   [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Whispers-related challenges posted in February 2021

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```