# Language of the Month for May 2021: Vyxal

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month, vyxal

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/78850), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout May 2021, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Vyxal

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/78850). In short, during May, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Vyxal, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Vyxal

<sup>Taken from the [nomination post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22138/78850) and from the [README.md](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal/blob/master/README.md) in the official GitHub repository</sup>

Vyxal is the latest addition to the plethora of stack-based languages used for code golfing. But unlike its competitors, Vyxal has a special focus upon readability and elegancy. Indeed, the codepage has been specially chosen to be as mnemonic as possible. Further, constructs from practical languages (such as functions, lambdas and easy list manipulation) are present.

- Vyxal has been known to repeatedly win against languages like 05ab1e, Jelly and Pyth... [it managed to beat Dennis in fizzbuzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210307/78850)
- It has features designed to make it feel analogous to practical languages while remaining concise
- It has reached version 2.0, so all heavy development has been completed
- Bugs are fixed relatively quickly: 10 of the most recent issues were all promptly addressed

### Bounty

Unlike previous LoTMs, in addition to a 50 rep bounty for first anwers, the [deadlineless 300 rep bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22137/78850) will also be awarded. Post 5 Vyxal answers and you'll get an easy 300 rep added to your account.

#### Resources

- [Github Repository](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal)
- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal)
- [Online Interpreter](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/)
- [Tutorial](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/blob/master/docs/Tutorial.md)
- [Command reference](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/blob/master/docs/elements.txt)
- [Esolangs article](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Vyxal)
- [Golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223918/95792)
- [Language bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline/22137#22137)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## List of all Vyxal solutions posted in May 2021

(First time posters highlighted in bold, and bounty claimers in italics)

- [Round away from zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224829/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Write a program with infinite expected output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224831/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Semi-Diagonal Alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224908/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Make an alphabet searchlight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224897/78850) by ***[hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)***
- [Coprimes up to N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224928/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Primes numbers with prime index](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224930) by [user](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95792)
- [Round toward zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224943/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [I reverse the source code, you negate the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224944/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [The Letter A without A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224948/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [I double the source, you double the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224980/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [I reverse the source code, you negate the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224981/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Exciting Mario Kart Grand Prix - Minimize the point difference!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225006/66833) by **[caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)**
- [Machine Epsilon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224989/78850) by **[Citty](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75429/citty)**
- [Exciting Mario Kart Grand Prix - Minimize the point difference!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225005/78850) by [Manish Kundu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77516/manish-kundu)
- [Reverse and Invert a String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225135/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Conway's Monster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225178/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [String to Binary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225185/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [The Luhn algorithm for verifying credit card numbers, etc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225186/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Numbers divisible by the sum and product of their digits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225211/80214) by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)
- [Which th second now in this year](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220211/which-th-second-now-in-this-year/225245#225245) by *[Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif)*
- [Different Way Forward](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47005/different-way-forward/225281#225281) by [Wasif](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116/wasif)
- [I reverse the source code, you negate the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-output/225283#225283) by Wasif
- [Generate all solvable 2xN mazes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225285/100664) by ***[A username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/a-username)***
- [Draw the Stack Overflow Logo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224852/100887) by ***[StackMeter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100887/stackmeter)***
- [Adding without using a + or - sign](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225376/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Count the number of vowels in each word of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225385/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Lolololololololololololol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/lolololololololololololol/225403#225403) by Wasif
- [Write an interpreter for *](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225442/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Write an interpreter for "interpreter"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225465/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Output a Latin Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225299/68942) by [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)
- [Animate finding the middle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225396/68942) by [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)
- [Adding up the digits and the digits reversed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225397/68942) by [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)
- [It was just a bug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225398/68942) by [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)
- [Find Abecedarian Words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225537/80050) by ***[a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)***
- [Compute the uncomputable … sort of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225610/92727) by **[Command Master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master)**
- [Old Spanish alphabetical order](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225668/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [Draw an hourglass](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225681/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [Invert a boolean array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225683/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [!I!n!s!e!r!t! !i!n!b!e!t!w!e!e!n!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225394/99035) by [Underslash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99035)
- [Stay away from zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225544/99035) by [Underslash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99035)
- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225653/99035) by [Underslash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99035)
- [Print the alphabet four times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/print-the-alphabet-four-times/225788#225788) by Wasif
- [Sing Happy Birthday to your favourite programming language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/sing-happy-birthday-to-your-favourite-programming-language/225790#225790) by Wasif
- [Compatible strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225815/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [Partial Sum of Harmonic Sequence!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225862/99035) by [Underslash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99035)
- [I give you ascii-art, you make it pseudo-3d](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225909/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [Parenthifiable Binary Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225426/85334) by [**Unrelated String**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)
- [Has My Pie Been Bisected?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225994/85334) by [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)
- [Shortest Konami Code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225913/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [What is the standard scratch?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225948/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [Generate ;# code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226033/80050) by [a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80050)
- [Write the shortest self-identifying program (a quine variant)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225989/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Make a polyglot generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226029/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [We're no strangers to code golf, you know the rules, and so do I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226132/99035) by [Underslash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99035)
- [Recover the power from the prime power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167199/recover-the-power-from-the-prime-power/226142#226142) by Wasif
- [Convert version string to pack_format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225916/convert-version-string-to-pack-format/226143#226143) by Wasif
- [Print "N NE E SE S SW W NW"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186582/print-n-ne-e-se-s-sw-w-nw/225979#225979) by Wasif
- [A very long Terza Rima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151023/a-very-long-terza-rima/226151#226151) by Wasif
- [Create a program that prints the number of characters it has, in words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226218/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Obfuscated Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226316/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [When I grow up I want to be ASCII](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200576/when-i-grow-up-i-want-to-be-ascii/226440#226440) by Wasif
- [Three other numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212240/three-other-numbers/226437#226437) by Wasif
- [Is string X a subsequence of string Y?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/is-string-x-a-subsequence-of-string-y/226425#226425) by Wasif
- [The alphabet in programming languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/the-alphabet-in-programming-languages/226423#226423) by Wasif
- [Longest run of a character in a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125377/longest-run-of-a-character-in-a-string/226422#226422) by Wasif
- [Print the alphabet without using each vowel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/print-the-alphabet-without-using-each-vowel/226415#226415) by Wasif
- [Find an Illegal String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226518/95792) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)
- [A rainbow of identity functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226519/95792) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)
- [Print the tetration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226529/95792) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)
- [Implement a zipwith function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226592/95792) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of all Vyxal tips posted in May 2021

- [Use `\` for single byte strings and `‛` for two byte strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225286/78850) by [Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- [Compress your strings and numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225288/78850) by [Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/Lyxal)
- [Use the register instead of a variable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225369/101522) by [Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaron-miller)
- [Custom base decompression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223918/tips-for-golfing-in-vyxal/226119#226119) by [A username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/a-username)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<tip title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

---

## List of Vyxal-related challenges posted in May 2021

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
    [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/<question-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```