# Language of the Month for November 2021: Zsh

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19271/16766), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout November 2021, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Zsh

What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). In short, during November, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Zsh, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Zsh

<sup>Taken from the [nomination post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229)</sup>

Zsh is a Bourne shell derivative which apparently specialises in having far too many ways to do some things, of which the shortest is always inconvenient, and no obvious way to do a lot of other things. Thanks to its liberal forgiveness of errors, it is very abusable, which is a great feature for code golf and makes competing in it particularly fun.

- It is easy to learn, but difficult to master
- By learning it, you will be able to write shell scripts much better and gain more experience with a practical interactive shell where you (should) spend a lot of your time
- It does surprisingly well in many text and pattern matching-based challenges, so you will be able to compete amongst even some golfing languages
- It's very good at restricted source, especially for a non-esoteric language
- I am the currently only active user, and I'd like to change that

**I already run [a bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20789) on Zsh answers; for the month of November only, all first time Zsh users' answers will be eligible for this bounty**

#### Resources

- [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZoFJQGAA)
- [Zsh Showcase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226010)
- [Tips for restricted source in Zsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/219490)
- [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15279), of which many are also applicable to Zsh
- [Zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html) (also `man zshall`)
- [Zsh user guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## List of all Zsh answers posted in November 2021

(first-time posters in **bold**)

- [Universal Spooky Meme Translator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236781) by [roblogic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15940/roblogic)
- [How long is the number in this base?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236877/92901) by [**Dingus**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901)
- [Rotate N Values in a List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236969) by [GammaFunction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86147/gammafunction)
- [yes is 91 lines long](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237136) by [roblogic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15940/roblogic)
- [Swap every two elements in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237102) by [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)
- [Digit small numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237394) by [**Seggan**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299)
- [Universal Spooky Meme Translator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237195) by [Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/994/gilles-so-stop-being-evil)
- [yes is 91 lines long](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237194) by [Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/994/gilles-so-stop-being-evil)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in November 2021

- [Use `.` for looping](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237161) by [nrgmsbki4spot1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100411/nrgmsbki4spot1)
- [Use `$_` (the underscore variable)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237192) by [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in November 2021

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```