# Proposal to mark Inactive posts in "List of bounties with no deadline" accordingly

Tags: feature-request, meta, bounty

I recently completed a bounty from List of bounties with no deadline, only to later realize it was inactive. This was a little disappointing and I believe this could easily be avoided by editing these posts to reflect them being inactive; either by adding <s>strikethrough</s> to their titles, or a little blurb in the body stating the post is inactive. If a user later returns to codegolf, they can always unedit the post to return it to active status.

Link: [List of bounties with no deadline](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline)

Comment: How do you determine if a bounty is inactive or not?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Another one is https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20846/106844, but for determining inactivity, if a user suspects someone is no longer awarding bounties, they can ask them in comments, or see if anyone in chat knows their status

Comment: @DialFrost, Baby_Boy I wasn't asking for examples of inactive bounties. My point is that there's no real way of determining if a bounty is inactive or not, aside from that user indicating so. I've seen fulfilled bounties that have gone unawarded by active users, and inactive users return to award fulfilled bounties. Potentially, we could mark bounties with some kind of warning that the offerer has been inactive recently, but I don't really think that necessary. Going for the deadlineless bounties has some inherent "risk" of not getting the bounty that you accept when you attempt them.