# Inactivity on bounties with no deadlines?

Tags: discussion, bounty

The [List of bounties with no deadline](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline) is a page where there are bounties that can be awarded anytime. However majority of these were created quite awhile ago and some comments don't receive feedback on saying "This answer deserves the bounty".

How can we bring this back? There's also the problem of users go inactive for years and not editing the post despite people spending time to try and earn the bounty only to realise the user is inactive and the posted is not updated to show it is.

[Example compliant](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25168/proposal-to-mark-inactive-posts-in-list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline-according) of the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an issue. The deadline-less bounties are not guaranteed. The second paragraph of the post is

> **Disclaimer**: There is no guarantee that the user will award the bounty for you in case you fulfill its requirement. Especially if the user isn't an active member anymore. The only guarantee is their written word.

When people advertise a bounty, it is expected, but not certain, that it will be rewarded when fulfilled. When you complete one of the bounties, you do so with the "risk" that you may not be awarded the bounty. If you aren't happy with that, then that's unfortunate, but there's no way to guarantee a deadline-less bounty, without SE making some changes for us.

At best, you can take a quick glance at the user offering the bounty and see if they've been active recently. If not, then consider not doing that bounty.