# Language of the Month for January 2023: Elm

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout January 2023, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Elm

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during January, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Elm, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Elm

Elm is a purely functional programming language for the browser.

It's very similar to Haskell but is designed to be easy for Javascript programmers to pick up. Elm is very beginner friendly.  Compared to Haskell it has useful error messages, simpler types, and no monads.  Compared to Javascript, it has useful types, fewer gotcha's, and is overall leaner.

You can certainly learn Elm enough to get started in an afternoon.  If you aren't already into Haskell it offers an easy way to experience a new way to program.  With it as the language of the month you can learn with the help of others new to the language and those more experienced.

If you are into Haskell and FP, it has a number of important distinctions from Haskell that I think make it interesting.  It has a rather different base library and a different approach to libraries all together.  Elm is a lot more minimalist than Haskell forcing you to use a few tools well.

Haskell golfers, and people who are interested in golfing in Haskell should find Elm as an excellent opportunity.

### Resources

- [Website](https://elm-lang.org/)
- [Introduction to Elm](https://guide.elm-lang.org/)
- [Try Elm!](https://elm-lang.org/try)
- [Package docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/)
- [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men)
- [Ellie (Online Interpreter)](https://ellie-app.com/new)

Feel free to ping @WheatWizard in chat if you have questions.

## Bounty

I @WheatWizard am offering 50 reputation to each user's first submission in Elm. [Indefinite bounty link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25453/)

Answer (score 3):

## List of all Elm answers posted in January 2023

- [Multiply a string by a number!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132002/multiply-a-string-by-a-number/256437#256437) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Separate a list into even-indexed and odd-indexed parts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64315/d/256439#256439) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [Non-Unique/Duplicate Elements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60610/d/256440#256440) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [Remove duplicates from my academic transcript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256441/d/256478#256478) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/)
- [Implement a cleave function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230145/d/256539#256539) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/)
- [Binary to decimal converter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102219/binary-to-decimal-converter/256541#256541) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Count the changes in an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146402/d/256571#256571) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/)
- [Division between two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256411/division-between-two-strings/256623#256623) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Apply at indices](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225085/apply-at-indices/256640#256640) by [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)
- [Equal numbers in sub-array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165954/equal-numbers-in-sub-array/256998#256998) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Trim the array!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128417/trim-the-array/257173#257173) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- [Reversed Iota's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199290/reversed-iotas/257203#257203) by [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in January 2023

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in January 2023

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```