# Untyped functions in static languages

Tags: discussion

I'll be using Java in this post, but the following also applies to C#, and likely other languages.

We require that submissions must be a first-class function, or a full program to be valid.  In Java, many users have started using *untyped* lambdas as their submission.  **The problem with untyped lambdas is that they have no meaning** without their types.

For example, given a theoretical challenge of `Add Two Numbers`, in Java, a submission would look like:

```
(a,b) -> a + b
```

which seems relatively reasonable.  However, the problem lies with the following solution:

```
(a,b) -> a.add(b)
```

The problem with the above statement **is that we have *absolutely no idea* which function is getting called**.  The only way the above statement could *ever* work in code is if we say in the description that `a` and `b` are `BigInteger`.

To extend this problem further, lets say I'm answering a sorting challenge.  You could submit:

```
list -> list.sortThis()
```

Now wait, `sortThis()` isn't a function on arrays, or on ArrayList, or anywhere in the JDK.  I'd have you tell you that `list` is a `MutableList` from Eclipse Collections for you to ever use the code.  Furthermore, if I *did* use that code, you don't need to import a MutableList.  Java is able to deduce the types, no import needed.

We require the submissions be self-contained, but right now, **these lambdas are not self-contained, because they require outside input to indicate the types**.

How do we solve this problem?

Comment: I'd like to point out VisualMelon's [past post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/c-lambdas-as-answers-to-questions-asking-for-a-function) about this issue that never really got a well-upvoted answer.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/java-function-literals)

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8779/51825). (I still think that question _is not a dupe_ of its dupe target but that's not really relevant here)

Answer (score 18):

**TL;DR**: Lambdas should not require their types.

---

I think that the lambdas shouldn't require types. A lambda does not need the type to be specified when you assign it to the function. For example, in C#:

```
Func<int, int, int> f = (a,b) => a + b;
```

Compiles just fine. In fact I didn't even know you could specify the type in the lambda before I saw this post.

Another reason to allow this is that these languages are never going to beat a golfing language and requiring types only increases the gap. As code compiles just fine without them, there is no need to add them in.

I don't buy the argument about not knowing what function is called. To solve it you can either a) Ask the author or b) Require people state what the anonymous function compiles to:

> ```
> s=>s.Length
> ```
>
> Compiles to a `Func<string, int>`.

Lastly, if we require types for the inputs it is only logical that we then have to require types for outputs. This makes no sense in the case of a lambda as there is no way to do this without showing what it compiles to. At that point it just becomes shorter to use a normal method and do away with lambdas on PPCG altogether.

Comment: Your argument isn't "lambdas should not require their types", but rather "lambdas should not require their types when those types can be automatically deduced", which is the same as Nathan's answer. In C#, dynamic types can be used, so the types can be deduced without them needing to be explicitly stated (I think - correct me if I'm wrong). Java is strongly-typed and statically-typed, so there's no way to define a lambda without include the types of the parameter(s).

Comment: So, I don't know C# very well, but how do you deal with my `l->l.sortThis()` problem?  Are you going to allow me to pick any type for `l`?  Then why don't I create a language with a gazillion types, and `a=>a.a` means something different for each type?

Comment: @Mego No it is lambdas should never require types, not sometimes they can, sometimes not. I can show you what it compiles to and `s=>l.Length` compiles fine so what's the point in adding it for a site about minimising byte count?

Comment: Sure, `s=>s.Length` compiles fine in C#, but `s->s.length` does not in Java.

Comment: @NathanMerrill No that's why you show what it compiles down to. Also part of a spec is requiring any reasonable input. I think it is reasonable to assume if I say it compiles to a `Func<int, string>` then assuming you pass an int is fine.

Comment: @Mego Yes it does... with the appropriate context.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire And that context is important, and thus required in the byte count.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Lets say I create 100 different libraries each with a different implementation of List.  Then I can pick whichever list gives me the shortest code, and the code will be identical `a=>a.a` sorts the list vs `a=>a.a` reverses the list.  The first one uses my `SortingList`, the second uses my `ReversingList`.  I'm getting functionality for 0 bytes.

Comment: @NathanMerrill That's a daft example because you'd have to add the code for both list classes into your byte count anyway and then it would be obvious which one you are using anyway... because you wouldn't use a class for it!

Comment: @Mego If it compiles without that context why is it important?

Comment: No I wouldn't. I'd simply have to publish the library before the problem is posted, and have it compile to `Func<MySortingList, MySortingList>`

Comment: @NathanMerrill So if I write such a library and I say instead of "Java", "Java with ...", I get all the freebies?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm not sure what you mean.  We allow other libraries, as long as they are imported.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Exactly but then you are telling us what it compiles to, a challenges spec usually states something like `Input in any reasonable format`, assuming the input is what you compile the lambda to is then a fine assumption surely? If the spec states input must be an int, I shouldn't have to do `(int n)=>...` we already know it is an int from the challenges specs.

Comment: I'm entirely able to write a library that does all the streaming methods, for very, very low amount of bytes. I'll call the main class `A` in the default package. so that I don't even need to type `import` because `A` is the FQN of the class. I can use all the functionality I created that took a lot of effort and I'd cheat everyone for that. All I have to do to make those entries valid is to call the entries "Java with A" instead of "Java". I'll outgolf every Java programmer, ever.

Comment: What I mean is that there are ways to bend the rules and here we haven't. We're still playing fair and contextual, as shown in my answer here is fair.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder What makes my custom List implementations not reasonable?   Regardless, would you allow me to use `long` instead of `int`, or even `float`?  I can get extra functionality by choosing my type with no change in code.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire yeah, but we consider `Java with A` a different language, and while it would absolutely be valid, we generally downvote them :)

Comment: Yep, downvoted, but still outgolfed.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Of course you can but then you are ignoring the spec `Any reasonable format` where the format is usually supplied in the answer. When I answer with a lambda I will either show what it compiles to or show the full code. If this `n=>n` is valid in language why ban it in a site where the goal is to reduce the number of bytes and require the more verbose `(int n)=>n` instead? it makes absoloutley(I can't spell) zero sense to me.

Comment: Because the language requires those types and we require submissions to be self-contained.

Comment: Also, following your rule, @NathanMerrill, we should write the following: `Arrays.asList("0","1","2").stream().map((String s)->s+"0"). ...` instead of `Arrays.asList("0","1","2").stream().map(s->s+"0"). ...`. This is absurd.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire no!  Java can deduce the types in that case.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Do we? What is the return type of `(int n)=>n.Something`? If it needs to be self-contained I need to know the return type in the code surely?

Comment: Oh, so Java can or cannot? Which is it? You said it can't, but then you say it can. So it depends on context. Exactly what I said from the start. Java is entirely able to contextualize stuff, which is enough to be accepted.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder that doesn't compile.  If `n` *did* have a `Something` property, then you could deduce the return type.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes but you'd have to look into the code itself, exactly the same as `n=>n.Something` to work out what `n` is.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire read my post again.  If Java can deduce the types from the code you post, then its totally fine.  We cannot depend on types *outside* of our submission.

Comment: In my submissions, I always contextualize the code. Check my last 10 submissions, I always say the type unless obvious. Still, it's not part of the code.

Comment: `Arrays.asList("0","1","2").stream().map(s->s+"0")` is valid, `s->s+"0"` is not.  The first Java can compile just fine.  The second, Java has no idea what it means.  That `+` literally has no meaning.

Comment: @NathanMerrill C# can deduce the types from `Func<int, int> f = n=>n;` so `n=>n` is fine then? It's the boilerplate code to tell C# what it compiles to with `(int n)=>n` I still have to compile it to `Func<int, int> f = (int n)=>n;`. Both work so why disallow the former?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Hummm... No. The first one can't be compiled just fine. I put that in a file and it doesn't compile. So you're handpicking what is omittable and what isn't.

Comment: I mean, yeah we need the surrounding code (to make it a function or a class), but Java can handle that statement :)

Comment: Java can handle the second one just fine too, given the surrounding code.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes and it can handle `n->n`. So I don't see your point.

Comment: Then I disagree that we can simply choose any type we want.

Comment: I can agree on that, @NathanMerrill. Let us open another topic where we say for Java, integers correspond to: "short", "int", "long", "BigInteger"; floats correspond to "float", "double", "BigDecimal" and discuss those lists. And then if one implied type is on the list, no need to explicitly name it. Okay?

Comment: 1. We require submission that are functions or full programs.  2. A valid Java function is typed.  3. If Java doesn't know those types then it isn't a valid Java function.  4. Providing those types in the surrounding code means that the function gains functionality based on the surrounding code.  5. If a function changes depending on the surrounding code, then it isn't self contained.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'd actually love it if we had a list of valid type mappings for each language.  That said, I don't think you'll get the community on board with that :)

Comment: @Mego, you're mainly wrong about C#. Yes, it has dynamic types, but they require using the `dynamic` keyword where you would otherwise expect the name of a type. There is also type inference in some contexts, but that's compile-time. Type inference is not incompatible with strong static typing.

Comment: @NathanMerrill And not showing the return type means it isn't self contained then?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for clearing that up. It's been a few years since I last used C#, and my memory is rusty.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder no, because you can't just change the return type to change how the function works.

Comment: @NathanMerrill where is that quote from?

Comment: 1. "*A lambda does not need the type to be specified when you assign it to the function*" is true, but the point of lambdas is that you can use them for things other than assigning them to a variable, so without explicit types they may be ambiguous. I'm on the fence about this point. 2. "*Another reason to allow this is that these languages are never going to beat a golfing language and requiring types only increases the gap*" on the other hand is just arguing for a handicap system, and discussions on meta have consistently rejected handicapping.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I wasn't arguing for handicap just another point to make the argument. The main argument is if `n=>n` compiles just as fine as `(int n)=>n` why should we force people to use a more verbose version in a code golf site. It makes no sense.

Comment: We already agreed long time ago that lambdas are accepted. And now when we write lambdas, they're not anymore... I don't know Python, but they have lambdas. If I give an number parameter to an array accepting lambda, it will fail, right? Then, where is it contextualized that the lambda accepts only arrays and not ints? "Oh, but it's in the question". Where in all there is the difference with Java? We use information from the question to contextualize and golf bytes. We can decide to be more strict on the lambda definition, but to force entirely the burden of complete definition on Java is bad.

Comment: What I mean is that we can say "hey, your submission isn' valid because you accept a string, but the question said number".

Comment: Another argument for it is being pragmatic that all Java golfers use and understand this. And get lots of reputation out of those lambda-based answers. This topic is 5 months old, yet there are everyday [lambda answers with 10+ rep in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124295/16236), that no one is policing. Java answers mostly compete between them and everybody's happy! Sometimes one is really good and forcing unnecessary burden only annoys everybody. That was the reason for "function or full program". Where is that spirit now?

Comment: Fun and slightly frustrating read.. First of all I don't get why `c=>...` in C# might be valid, but `c->...` in Java would not be, since they are exactly the same. Secondly, I understand the point of not knowing whether `n->...` is an int, long, byte, etc. without context. BUT, the same can be said about other languages that aren't strongly typed. I see answers ALL the time stating: "_input is ..._", like [input is a list of two Strings in CJam](https://tinyurl.com/y7vl8esz), [input is a cell array of strings in MATL](https://tinyurl.com/ya5qwyba). Why is Java/C# stating this any different?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I totally agree that it should be true for all languages (even the weakly typed).  That said, in strongly typed languages, I'm still of the opinion that `n->n+1` has absolutely no meaning without the types.  In Python, that is well defined:  take an object, and call the `__add__` function.  In Java it isn't defined at all.   So, I can see how we make a difference between the two.

Comment: (In context of C#, I'm not so familiar with Java) Just to reiterate what Nathan has said `n=>n` _has no meaning out of context_. "It is the identity!" I hear someone shout. Nope, it has no meaning: you can write the code `System.Func<int, float>f=n=>n` and you can _lose_ information calling that delegate. I am wholly and vehemently against this proposal. (Example where `int to float` induces misery is `int.MaxValue`: `Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue); Console.WriteLine((int)f(int.MaxValue));`, yes, I consider implicit `int to float` a failure in language design, but that is irrelevant).

Comment: I discuss in [my second proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11199/26981) to my prior question on the matter how we can define sensible rules that generally remove the need for explicit output types (short-answer: the compiler can infer for you, if you want anything else you do have to specify it). Again, I see no issue with long answers being long if it makes them _comparable_; you shouldn't require context be specified in the answer, and it shouldn't be allowable to depend on it. I won't comment on needing to know what a function is called, that is a different question.

Comment: And just to finish, who cares if lambdas in C# and Java are no use for code-golf? This is a non-issue: either way, they _would_ remain useful, but in places where context is given by the program, instead of being assumed by the answer.

Answer (score -1):

## Types should be included but not in the bytecount

The main argument is that a person wishing to use the lambda may not know the datatype just by looking at the function since it's implicitly set within the context of the lambda. This is a good argument for requiring that the datatype be specified in the answer... but this is code golf, people; if bytes aren't needed for a line of code to be valid, they're going to be omitted.

It seems like until recently people have been content with the untyped lambdas. This is likely because on PPCG there's almost always a rule where you can assume input is valid. Part of valid input includes the datatype in this example. The part that makes Java or C# different from Python or Javascript is that Java and C# are strongly typed. If you don't have the correct datatype, the code won't compile let alone run. In Python or Javascript you can call a function with any datatype you want... but it will likely error if you use one that's unintended.

Consider a javascript object `a = {key: 'value'}`. Suppose I expect this format for parameters to my function. In classic javascript fashion I'm able to invoke `console.log(a.key);` If my program relies on that functionality then it's going to error if you pass in `1`.

```
> 1.key
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I would need to specify in my answer that input is expected to be in a certain format or datatype but that wouldn't affect my bytecount.

Comment: *"This is a good argument for requiring that the datatype be specified in the answer"* -- I don't think requiring arbitrary additional information based on specific languages is good. But I do think answers should be *testable*. Sidebar: *"until recently"* -- doing the wrong thing in the past doesn't make it the right thing in the present. I think this detracts from you idea.

Answer (score -2):

## Java already allows contextual imports. So contextual information is allowed.

Take the two files:

**A.java**

```
import java.util.*;
class A {
  static List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo");
}
```

**B.java**

```
// NO IMPORTS!!
class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(A.list.get(0));
  }
}
```

Here, `B` *depends* on `java.util.List`, but `java.util.List` isn't declared in the imports.

[One of my previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93659/16236)'s one of my previous golfed answer showed that no imports are required in the context of a lambda. You can call it black magic, but it works. Types *can* be contextual in Java, and Lambda are no exception to this.

Here is the answer, retyped, for clarity of the example:

**`LookMaNoImports.java`**

```
class LookMaNoImports {
  static Main.F f = s -> // transform a Stream<Boolean>
    s.map(               // by applying its map method
      b ->               // which in turns transforms a boolean 
        !b               // by applying its negation.
    );
}
```

**`Main.java`**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    interface F {
        Stream<Boolean> f(Stream<Boolean> s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F f=LookMaNoImports.f;

        test(f, new Boolean[]{true}, new Boolean[]{false});
        test(f, new Boolean[]{false}, new Boolean[]{true});
        test(f, new Boolean[]{true, false}, new Boolean[]{false, true});
        test(f, new Boolean[]{true, true}, new Boolean[]{false, false});
    }

    static void test(F f, Boolean[] param, Boolean[] expected) {
        List<Boolean> result = f.f(Arrays.stream(param)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (result.equals(Arrays.asList(expected))) {
            System.out.printf("%s: OK%n", Arrays.toString(param));
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s: NOT OK, expected %s%n", Arrays.toString(param), Arrays.toString(expected));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, `LookMaNoImports` is valid *as long as you post both files* (and they both count towards your byte count).  However, Java needs types to compile, and you need to declare them for your submission to be self contained.

Comment: I don't really understand how this is an answer to lambdas needing types or not. Yes all required imports are required but that is a different thing to what this post is about.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder No, all imports aren't required. I just showed two examples where it's not the case, including one Lambda. The atom in Java is the class. Classes allow contextual information as shown. Twice.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I don't know Java well but as far as I can tell you have all the required imports, you've just hidden them in a different file. So as far as code golf is concerned you'd need to include the extra file as well into your byte count

Comment: @TheLethalCoder In Java, the unit is the class. The class contains methods. Codegolf says "hey, you can use Java methods or lambdas". So I'm showing Java methods and lambdas as they are written in their unit, the class. Taking rules, combining them.

Comment: I agree with @TheLethalCoder. When you have a class A and B, you'll have to include both in your answer. Yes, A lack's B's import, but including/excluding imports aren't the only thing that are mandatory when posting answers. One of the forbidden loopholes is to put everything in a file/executable/plugin/etc. and simply call that; or to create a language with a single byte-solution for the exact challenge posted. Hiding code inside another class without including it in your answer is a closely related forbidden loophole. (Also, this question is about function-types, not imports..:S)

Answer (score -3):

## Require types to be added if a method/function/operator cannot be deduced

This answer only applies to languages with [manifest typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_typing).

Java and C# both have the ability to define types in the definition:

```
(int a, int b) => a + b   // C#
(int a, int b) -> a + b   // Java
```

This gets immensely useful when dealing with objects:

```
(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) -> a.add(b)
(MutableList a) -> a.sortThis()
```

Furthermore, because the above two examples only involve a single function, you can shorten them to:

```
BigInteger::add    
MutableList::sortThis
```

Another acceptable format would be:

```
Function<MutableList, MutableList> f = a -> a.sortThis()
```

Even though the lambda itself does not contain the type, the method `sortThis()` can still be deduced.

In all of these examples, imports would still be required because the types `BigInteger` or `MutableList` are explicitly listed.  The key here is that **the submissions are *self-contained*; They contain all of the type information you need to run.**

Comment: Other languages have lambda expressions which fail if you provide the wrong types. Why is `lamda f:` allowed in python but `f->` is banned in Java? It's the same thing. If you write `lambda f:f.sort()` in python, it will fail if you pass it an int. If you write `f->java.util.Arrays.sort(f)`, it will also fail if you pass it an int.

Comment: The key difference here is that Java is `manifestly typed`.  Python doesn't require that the definition exists (you could simply implement `__attr__`).  However, for a Java program to be compilable, that type must declared somewhere.  We are simply requiring that the submission has that type.

Comment: Yeah, but the type doesn't have to be declared. For example, the function `castToDouble()` take an expression in the form of `n->n` as a parameter without the need for a type declaration.

Comment: The type is still required: it's just located wherever you declare the type of the variable being passed in.  I'm simply moving that type to the lambda

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the situation, but shouldn't I expect the types of the inputs to be declared in whatever hypothetical test framework is being used to test the function?

Comment: Yes, but the difference is that the lambda *depends* on those types being declared.  It isn't standalone, because it is obtaining functionality based on surrounding code

Comment: Is there an actual C# example where the type cannot be deduced since you can just use `dynamic` to cover almost everything? Off the top of my head, only pointer types that specifically use the pointer operators can't be `dynamic` in which case you can deduce it's a pointer type.

Comment: I don't know C# very well, but I imagine that a C# lambda would only compile if it knew the types of the variables *or* that the variables were declared dynamic.  Meaning that you *still* have the dependency to outside code.

Comment: @milk C# will never assume `dynamic` unless it's the natural consequence of the type inference, but you can indeed write almost anything in a lambda as long as you assign it to a lambda with the right number of (dynamic) parameters. C# also never guess pointer types (even if it could in theory know it's a pointer, it has no idea what type it points to).