# Should creating a new lambda class be allowed?

Tags: discussion

## Preface

This question is specifically targeting `Java` answers. I have little to no knowledge of any other program languages, though I expect that the questions I raise below will apply to other statically-typed languages as well. This question was "inspired" by [this PPCG answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127840/56085).

## Java Lambdas

(skip this if you know Java and how Java lambda's work)

So, in statically typed languages, everything has a type at compile-time - including lambdas. In Java lambdas are all instances of some `interface` which is considered a `FunctionalInterface`. An `interface` is functional iff it contains only 1 non-`default` method. Lambdas for that `interface` can then be created implementing that 1 method. For example, below is the (simplified) source code for Java's `Function` class:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {

    R apply(T t);

}
```

Lambdas of the type `Function<T, R>` can then be implemented like: `t -> r`, where `t` is the input and `r` is the return value. `Function` is just one of the many functional interfaces Java provides, others include `Predicate`, `Consumer`, `Supplier`, `BiFunction`, etc. In addition, interfaces which already existed but, as of Java 8, fit the definition of functional interfaces (such as `Runnable`) can also be implemented as lambdas.

## The Question

Every answer posted as a Java lambda that I've seen (up until the one that inspired this question) uses one of the default Java types. [I myself always specify what type the lambda is,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114014/56085)  to avoid any confusion. The question I have now is, can one just arbitrarily write a lambda, with as many parameters required, and submit it, as is done in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127839/swap-the-two-given-indices/127840#127840) (and claim it implements a custom functional interface)?

**Can lambdas be submitted as answers despite requiring an additional class declaration?**

---

## Notes

- I **do not** intend to specifically call out Okx's answer; it just so happens to be the one that spurred me to write this question. As far as I can tell, no community consensus was reached on this issue before they posted it, so don't go flooding their answer with down votes...
- Of course, you could also just use [a certain lambda library I may or may not have created](https://github.com/PlutoPowered/InverseY/tree/master/src/main/java/com/gmail/socraticphoenix/inversey/many) and side step this whole issue... and Java isn't going to win any [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges anyway... this kind of feels like a pointless question now... Anyway, thoughts?
- If this question is a duplicate, I apologize, I couldn't find any other similar questions with the search term: `lambda AND class is:question`

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

- All well-specified questions define their inputs and the outputs.  This is effectively defining your interface.  Requiring it is like requiring the code the runs your submission.
- All lambdas that require primitive types (unboxing doesn't work in their case) would need to declare their interface
- If you *really* want to get technical, [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/easybind/EasyBind.java) has functional interfaces for up to 6 inputs, and I would simply need to indicate in my submission that it implements that interface.  (I don't really like this, but it is the natural extension of [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12747/20198))

Comment: So the question is.the interface? That actually makes a lot of sense...

Comment: Formatting was messed up in my question! In the notes I tried to mention that [InverseY](https://github.com/PlutoPowered/InverseY/tree/master/src/main/java/com/gmail/socraticphoenix/inversey/many) provided functional interfaces for as many 0-255 parameters... but the link pointed to the wrong thing... anyway, this answer makes a lot of sense to me, so I'll accept it :)

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix don't accept it.  Let the community decide what it wants.

Comment: I appear to have forgotten to accept it anyway... but so be it :)

Answer (score -2):

## No.

Lambdas must be of a built-in type (such as `Function` in Java).

The key distinction, in my eyes, is boilerplate. With a built-in Java lambdas, one only needs the normal code required to get a full, compilable program:

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryOperator<Integer> add = (a, b) -> a + b;
    }

}
```

However, a custom lambda type requires a *full class declaration*, as well as boilerplate, to make it compilable:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TriFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer> addThree = (a, b, c) -> a + b + c;
    }
    
    public interface TriFunction<A, B, C, R> {
        
        R apply(A a, B b, C c);
        
    }

}
```

in my opinion, defining a whole new type that is than used in the program (as opposed to a class created only to house the `main` method) simply cannot be considered boilerplate.