# Proposed golfing showcase

Tags: discussion, new-genre

I'm looking for feedback on a showcase idea that's a bit like [Best of PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8007/20260), but on main. The goal is to showcase excellent golfs, so that a wider audience can understand and appreciate them. While inspired by [Showcase your language one vote at a time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44680/20260), it's not meant as a replacement.

Each answer would link to a golf (or fastest code, code challenge, etc) that the answerer considers worthy of admiration, whether their own and someone else's. The answer would explain in great detail how the golf works and why it's outstanding, far beyond the existing explanation in the answer.

- The explanation should make the code clear to someone who doesn't know the language. It could compare it to how other languages might approach the task.
- It should analyse the main tricks and optimizations. Moreover, it should explain *why* they were used, compare it to less optimized alternatives, and note any trade-offs.
- The author should explain what they consider special about the submission. Perhaps the core trick is hard to find, or the code was exceptionally well-optimized, or the language makes it very hard to solve the task at all. Or, perhaps it's more the sense of beauty the submission evokes.

I anticipate some potential issues. Answers might showcase already well-known, highly-voted submissions, so readers don't discover anything new. Voters might elevate answers that link to great golfs but have shallow explanations. Finally, the [FGITW effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) favors posting quickly, and quality answers posted months later might not get attention.

Beyond that, there's issues of scope. The site rules currently do not allow for such a showcase. Perhaps it could be called a popularity contest, with votes determining the "winner", but I find that a poor fit. Ideally, we would discuss and create a new category that allows for this type of thing.

Comment: I feel like the best place for this would be some sort of blog, since I can see it getting out of hand on the main site (especially the FGITW point). I do like the idea of giving recognition though, with more than just bounties.

Comment: I can't see this fitting into the scope as a separate question, but I can imagine tips answers that link to an example answer (or several) that have made good use of the particular tip. So a great answer may be linked to from several different tips.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A question whose answers explain existing answers on main is inherently a meta-question. Whether it's on topic for the meta site is debatable, but if it's on topic anywhere then it would be meta, not main.